# Let's Plan the Second Iteration of the Stack Exchange Quality Project!

Tags: discussion, se-quality-project

In case you missed the first one, check out the [se-quality-project](/questions/tagged/se-quality-project) tag. The quality project isn't one that we plan to ever finish, it's perennial and kicks in every 18 months or so after we've had ample opportunity to observe the efficacy of our previous efforts, changes in how people use our sites along with feedback regarding what they expected, and when new ideas seem promising enough to try.

It's time to talk about the areas that we're going to be focusing on. I'm going to give a high level overview of the *types* of things that we want to do, and touch briefly on things that we have in progress. I'll then turn it over to you.

It's then your turn to mention a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) that you think might be a great idea for us to evaluate for inclusion in this iteration, and we'll then take a look at all of it to see what we're going to be able to build.

We can't do all of it, but we're going to put the highest priority on small-ish things that could potentially make a big impact first, and then drill down into things that are going to take a bit of work, again with priority given to things that could help the largest number of users have a better experience on the site.

So, let's go over what we've got in mind:

#### Improving the new user experience

We want people to feel like they belong here. And in order to belong here you really need to be able to ask and answer questions competently, or contribute helpful things to documentation. It's that first part we're going to focus on first for the purposes of this project:

- We plan to test a new, 'guided' version of the ask question page soon. This page would essentially break down all of the elements that make a great question, and give the user plenty of guidance as to why it's to their advantage to understand what's needed in each of them, and provide it.
- We're launching an initiative with the University Of Melbourne in Australia. Some graduate studies have uncovered what (could) lead to much more precision in the detection of duplicate questions, as well as a huge improvement on what duplicates are suggested to the person asking. There will be a separate post about that this week. We need to help them validate a ton of data, they've come up with a system to make it easy for us to help. More to come on that soon.

#### Improving the experience of our existing users

We think the two things we've got planned in the new user experience category is going to have a pretty nice impact (most unhelpful questions don't need to be asked, if only we could let folks know we've already got their answers more effectively). But we want to do more.

- We're going to explore some ideas for better filtering of the questions that you see indicated by information that you give us. If you really only enjoy solving medium to difficult problems, that's what we need to prioritize showing you. We're going to have some discussions on ways this can be accomplished when we come to it.
- We're looking at some upgrades to the anti-spam and abuse mitigation systems. They've been good to us, but we need to keep them relevant. There are some awesome community-run projects that have been helping tremendously, and we're currently looking at ways that we might be able to integrate them more properly.

#### Improving the experience for our moderators

Because at the scale that we see on Stack Overflow, existing tools are really starting to show their age.

- We want to end the need to manually suss out voting rings. We're working on making the scheduled tasks that identify these things *much* smarter, by teaching them to think like Shog9 and myself do as we analyze all of the data that we have access to. We'll find a lot more rings where action is needed, and stop showing moderators patterns that are actually pretty benign (but the tools they have really don't indicate that it's benign). Mods will get a sort of 'minority report' in cases where the system couldn't make an automatic decision explaining why it couldn't decide, show all of the information that the mod needs to make the call, and let the moderator decide. This is actively being worked on for feasibility, once we're sure the model scales we'll kick off a discussion with more detail.
- We're going to do more to make certain that people understand what they're doing by flagging and help them choose the correct way to proceed (and in many cases that probably means not proceeding). We'll break out into a separate discussion when we get to this. Moderators are far too often called to look at things where they aren't actually needed, and this distracts them from looking at the stuff where they *are* actually needed. "Should I downvote, vote to close or flag? Should I do all of that?" - we need to make this much, much clearer. And we've got the inverse of that, folks downvoting spam when they really need to be flagging too :) It's not an easy problem.

None of these lists are exhaustive, there's more, but this is getting pretty long now. What's important is what you think we need to be prioritizing.

So what do *you* think we should include in this round? Try to link to the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), but don't fret too much if you can't find it (just explain what it wanted, and we can rely on Shog9's RAM-like memory for the location).

Comment: What makes a FR a good fit for this project? I've looked at the other six questions with this tag and I'm not quite sure what sets them apart.

Comment: How much of this will be Stack Overflow-centric? For example, a guided Ask page will probably be great on ---Programmers--- Software Engineering, especially given the confusion in scope and recent name change (meant to fix the confusion in scope).

Comment: @Catija Any FR where the end result is someone having a better experience learning how to use the site, or where existing users have a better experience of new users getting to know the site. But that's not iron-clad, if you think something belongs here, it probably does. We'll read every single one and sort them, and let folks know what we came up with / why.

Comment: @ThomasOwens The majority of this will apply to the whole network, _some_ of it will need merit for it to be turned on (similar to requiring registration to ask). We'll build it in a way that Software Engineering could take advantage of (or Ask Ubuntu, Math / Math Overflow / etc). (all provided it tests as well as we think it will).

Comment: +1 for better duplicate handling and for improvements with flagging.

Comment: From comment #3: *or where existing users have a better experience of new users getting to know the site*  ---> The ability to close questions quickly that are wildly not ready for prime time perhaps by some user vote weighting method

Comment: "Some graduate studies have uncovered what (could) lead to much more precision in the detection of duplicate questions, as well as a huge improvement on what duplicates are suggested to the person asking." - Are these papers listed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134495/academic-papers-using-stack-exchange-data)? I like reading new papers/studies that utilize SE data. If they are not, but are publicly available, can they be added?

Comment: Did anything come of the [post characteristics as images tests](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251679/quality-project-post-characteristics-as-images)?

Comment: Can I just take a second to say that the changes you guys have made to the mod screens over the past few months have been very minor but very welcome? Maybe I just noticed it over the past few months and it actually was there all along but it seems a lot easier to mod lately. So umm, yay.

Comment: "If you really only enjoy solving medium to difficult problems, that's what we need to prioritize showing you." I am curious as to **how** you are gonna accomplish that. Grading the difficulty of a problem often requires to understand it first. If an AI can do that, I am scared.

Comment: @Knu Think about it a little more. It'll come to you, and has very little to do with AI or NLP :)

Comment: Thanks to everyone for all of this work. It's really exciting! This is extremely minor, but in the bullet point about the new version of the ask question page, there appears to be either a typo or grammatical error in the second sentence. I think "...elements that make a great questions..."  was meant to be something else!

Comment: Are you going to make this community centric? What is good for some communities may not be good for others.

Comment: @sue - fixed :) Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @laptop2d Anything that substantially alters how folks interact with our sites will only be applied where we think it makes sense. What works for programmers doesn't necessarily work for cooks, even if most of those cooks are also programmers.

Comment: A TL;DR at the top of this post would be great. Not everyone has time to read such a long meta post, but they may still have something useful to add to the discussion.

Comment: @TimPost so you are planning to put the burden of grading on users? Now, in addition to downvoting and upvoting we will have (be able) to give a difficulty grade. Interesting. Gotta polish your UX for that one.

Comment: I notice that there is no statement of intent to implement things that are *a lot* of work. Do you think this is sustainable? Imho, there are a few things about the SE platform that need big changes. Do you plan to *ever* address such?

Comment: @TimPost - Is this the right place to raise current bugs to do with mod tools/mod pages or is it specifically more feature-request-y? Come to think of it should I be raising mod-bugs publicly at all, or with the SE team directly? (Either way what I've got is likely a quick-win)

Comment: @Robotnik If you can report the bug in a general way (that is, no revealing any user's identifying information including usernames, user ids, emails, etc etc), reporting on meta is fine. If that's not possible, please report via the "contact us" form.

Comment: @AdamLear - perfect thanks :)

Comment: @Andy I'll be making another post (why does it always sound like I'm planning another child when I say that?) shortly, with links to the papers. As they're published and in accordance with the university policy, they're unencumbered, or in essence a simple artifact of prior art. That was a very specific question that I asked, and the answer delighted me :) They very much plan for us to use what they've come up with if the data validates, along with anyone else that might benefit from it.

Comment: Waiting for this.

Comment: Tim, do I understand it correctly that this discussion you opened is not in the scope this year: [Empowering tag-badge holders part II - let's look at silver?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240700/165773) (guess it's going to be kept ignored for quite a while since over two years have passed already and nothing happened)

Comment: Guided question asking: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253305/thwart-publishing-duplicate-and-low-quality-questions/253317#253317

Comment: Can we send them to Jon's [perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) blogpost, and then give them 5 questions that they have to pass before we let new users write something?

Comment: "RAM-like memory"?  Does that mean that when he sleeps, it all goes away?

Comment: One thing that frustrates me is doing a search (here or on Google or Bing), and coming to a Q/A page, and the question is closed without an answer, and I have the same question. Sometimes the question is closed because it's a duplicate. In that case, more obvious links to the answer would be in order or perhaps a merge like Quora does. Other times moderators simply just don't like the question, and so I leave and look at another website that has the answer. In this case, the question probably should not have been closed. There needs to be a better way to handle questions moderators don't like.

Comment: "We plan to test a new, 'guided' version of the ask question page soon. This page would essentially break down all of the elements that make a great question, and give the user plenty of guidance as to why it's to their advantage to understand what's needed in each of them, and provide it." Will this be adjusted per site, like the current `help/on-topic`, or SE-wide the same?

Comment: When will we hear about the outcome of this initiative/?

Comment: @Raphael 6-8 months/years. (aka the team is busy with other things.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard As in, we all wasted our time (it may never happen, or things may be obsolete when it happens). Way to go! Next time, if you ask for several man weeks (?) of community feedback, please make plan *beforehand* on how you'll close the loop. Thanks.

Comment: Nobody wasted time here. More announcements coming this week as things move forward.

Comment: @ShadowWizard maybe it's just not yet time to take a stand on these matters

Comment: @Tim with all due respect (and there is respect, lots of it actually :)) the people who posted here wasted their time, and that's a fact. Proof? Let's take the top answer here, with 399 upvotes, posted almost year ago. You did post a [promising comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285889/lets-plan-the-second-iteration-of-the-stack-exchange-quality-project?noredirect=1#comment928820_285903), but those 3 weeks you mentioned turned into over 8 months now. So Robert has the full right to feel he wasted his time. I do not blame you. I do not blame anyone. Just stating the facts here.

Comment: And another full year went by. Do you by your comment "nobody wasted time", Tim?

Comment: And another full year went by after @Raphael's comment. Looks like there's some work done on the first post, related to the Ask Question Wizard.

Comment: Hehe, indeed. The next similar post from SE staff, i.e. one asking for "what can we change?" gets a duplicate vote for me. Not only is that now [meta] works (right?) but it's also true.

Comment: Any update on this @TimPost? And I actually mean ***any***.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Feedback post: Moderator review and reinstatement processes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336177/feedback-post-moderator-review-and-reinstatement-processes)

Answer (score 489):

#### New users need better awareness of what is expected of them when they ask their first question.

This is the single most important thing that needs to happen on the Stack Exchange network, in my opinion.  If the new Question Ask page will facilitate that, then I am enthusiastically supportive.  However, there are historical barriers, some of which SE itself has erected, and some which are due to conflicting goals.

Currently, we rely on a system of Help Center articles that **[new users never see](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279661/usability-issues-for-first-time-stack-exchange-users-a-micro-study)**, a patchwork quilt of Meta articles, and a Tour Page that focuses on site mechanics.  We carefully bury any information that might help new users shed their bad forum habits, allowing them instead to crash headlong into a "hostile" user community that expects new users to already know our rules, and we call that **being inclusive.**

Good software systems always follow the [**Principle of Least Surprise.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)  If your system's behavior regularly surprises, then it fails its purpose.

It is unfortunate that online behavior has been co-opted by the Facebooks, Twitters and YouTubes of the world, but if we are genuinely interested in making the world (or at least the internet) a better place, then we must also believe that we have (at least in some measure) a responsibility to educate people on how good communication really works.

This isn't about being negative.  It is about being proactive.  Nor is it about providing better flagging tools, although we should do that as well.  Rather, it is a mindset.  **The best off-topic question is the one that is never asked.**  Allowing sites to run off the rails by providing the lowest possible friction to ask off-topic questions and then saddling the community with cleaning up those questions... well, that's not what most of us signed up for, nor is it the best use of our time.  *It is probably the least-friendly way to welcome new users.*

Most of the professionals who are here come here to contribute and to help others, not to spend all of their time sweeping the floor.

Comment: Completely agreed: the best way to "improve the experience of our existing users" **and** moderators is not filtering the view _after_ the fact. It's catching (and ejecting) bad stuff before it even makes it through the pipeline. That said, it seems that the two bullets under "improving the new user experience" actually are aimed at this aspect, and I'm heartened to see that.

Comment: Do you have any proposals for how to make new users more aware of what is expected of them?

Comment: @TravisJ: I have lots.  You can browse my activity on Meta.Programmers.SE in the [new-site-name](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-site-name) tag if you want the sordid details.  **tl;dr:** http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/8254/new-logo-for-software-engineering-stack-exchange/8258#comment25901_8258

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Why people consider comments to be anything more than temporary confounds me at a very fundamental level. Of your 25 questions at programmers meta, I do not see any addressing the quality project. The how to ask rendition is maybe a slight shade, but still, again, what specific proposals do you have? Perhaps you could outline at least *one* here. Anyone can point out a problem, providing solutions is the hard part.

Comment: @TravisJ: I think I'll wait and see what the new Ask Question page looks like.  I don't view this as a technical problem; I view it as a philosophical one: *how can we tell people what they need to know without being negative?*  I am claiming that this assertion is a non-sequitur, and that it needs to be worked out before we even begin discussing a technical solution.

Comment: I have high hopes for the new Ask Question page as well. *fingers crossed*. Also, don't get me wrong, I agree with your answer here and did upvote it, I just would have liked to at least see one proposal included. With regards to your philosophical question, that topic is basically "negative feedback" and how to deliver it. There is a large field of study regarding this topic, and perhaps that could be integrated into the new user experience. I do not believe that is non-sequitur, which is to say I disagree that it is impossible to deliver negative feedback without being negative.

Comment: A possibility here - http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278444/193412 some GH repos have a similar thing for filing a bug report and I suggest that the average dev filing a bug report is a _lot_ more experienced than the average SO asker.

Comment: @TravisJ: I have seen some non-SE sites partially solve the problem like this: *"Before you ask your first question here, you should read the rules.  You don't have to read the rules, but you will be treated by the user community as if you have read them.  So read them."*

Comment: Important: these pipelines need to be site-specific. Because the rules are.

Comment: And related to this, can we stop caring how people who come here, don't read the rules, and drop off topic posts _feel_ about things? If a question is off topic, poor quality, etc, just get rid of it - I will downvote and vote to close. I'm not a mean person. I will just devote minimal time to someone who can't be bothered to help themselves. The reason we have this "SO is so mean!" is because people have this attitude but the guidance Robert is suggesting is poor - for fun, open an incognito tab and ask a question on SO, observing what you have to read in order to post.

Comment: @TravisJ: Since you did ask, [this is the proposal I floated specifically for Programmers](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/8061).  It didn't get much traction, so I narrowed it down to the single *"what we're not"*  paragraph.  Eventually, I got it down to a single phrase of 4 words in the tagline of the site: "but not code troubleshooting."  I thought I got agreement from SE that this phrase would be adopted, but it didn't make the final cut.

Comment: I've found I magically acquire powers normally reserved for 20k users if I politely point first time posters to the how-to-ask, on-topic pages as well as a breakdown of what's on topic on other sites.  If I can delete questions faster than we can close them by asking politely doesn't it suggest that many users are simply lost?  Yeah, we need to educate new users better. +1.

Comment: Why isn't there a direct link to the "what topics can I ask about?" and "what is considered off-topic?" help pages on the "Ask Question" page?

Comment: Speaking as someone who *did* read the Help Center before asking their first question...it's still useless.  I got plenty of information about how to interact with the SE software, but nothing about how to interact with the community, and very little about what sorts of things were on-topic.

Comment: +1 for help center articles **that new users never see**.  SOOOOooo true.

Comment: If someone has a '?' in an answer field, a big-ass warning should be 'do you realise you're asking a question in  response to a question?'.  The number of answers we have to delete because people post questions there is sad :(

Comment: Robert for president :) It boils down to whether we want quality over quantity. If you want quality questions, you need quality users, or you need to turn bad quality users into good quality users, which requires 'education', as you suggest.

Comment: My input on this subject: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253305/thwart-publishing-duplicate-and-low-quality-questions/253317#253317

Comment: @8protons:  New users never see the Help Center anyway.  You have to put this guidance somewhere else.

Comment: @MarkMayo Just don't make it a hard rule. There are valid reasons to include question marks or even questions in answers, not even limited to code blocks. A warning is probably a good idea, but an outright ban would be a *horrible* idea.

Comment: +1 for applying the Principal of Least Surprise to your argument.  I think if everybody -- not just software folks -- applied all the great software principals to their daily life, well, this world would be a better place.  Or at least a more-efficient-run, better-organized, more comprehensible place.

Comment: I'll be announcing some tests within the next 3 or so weeks, as well as a survey that's shown to brand new users after they ask their first question. tl;dr; - we *think* we know how to optimize the ask page to get good results, but we want to confirm that we're correct here - or a really good idea might get shelved due to a series of poorly constructed tests.

Comment: Did anything come of those tests, @TimPost?

Comment: @Josh well, according to [this new comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285889/lets-plan-the-second-iteration-of-the-stack-exchange-quality-project?noredirect=1#comment967192_285889), this week we'll know more. (but as 3 weeks are now more than 8 months, "this week" might also mean few months.)

Comment: Yeah, thanks, @ShadowWizard, I saw it. Like you, I am not holding my breath for anything. It's not the first "more coming sometime this week" comment I've seen.

Comment: looks very strongly related: ['How to ask questions' guidelines are not visible on android mobile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298059/165773): _"desktop page version of Stack Exchange sites has very clear 'how to ask' guidelines on the right of screen but the same are not seen when a user is ready to type in their question on the android mobile page version... a huge number of users are accessing the internet through android smartphones..."_

Answer (score 161):

## Implement a tool for editing tags without bumping

Mass tag edits are disruptive to both new and established users, especially on small- and medium-size sites.  There's no good way to edit all the questions of a nontrivial tag without thoroughly burying new posts on the front page.

Tag edits without any review are understandably problematic, but other options are available – one possible tool is described in [Tool for peer-reviewed no-bump mass retagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109510/300411).

Comment: I believe at 10k the tag-only edit privilege already does not bump the question... I could be wrong.

Comment: @TylerH Tag edits by 10k users, and even moderators, always bump the question.  See [Disabling bumping for retags by hi-rep users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93742/300411) (a declined feature request).

Comment: I'm not sure that covers the case of inline tag edits which could well be a newer privilege than that 5-year-old MSE request.

Comment: @TylerH, when I do inline tag edits as a moderator, the question is always bumped. As far as I know, the bump is only absent when tags are merged or when a tag is automatically deleted due to low popularity.

Comment: This should be a moderator- or community team-only feature, and it should be limited to mass retaggings that have been discussed and agreed upon on the site's meta. For regular users, and in all other cases, editing should bump the question for audit purposes.

Comment: @CodyGray What auditing purpose is achieved by bumping that isn't already achieved when a person edits it and leaves behind a new revision?

Comment: @CodyGray - +1 to this. I personally think that site mods should have a button they can press to **turn off bumping** for the duration of a mass tag edit. This button should have some kind of audit trail to show a) When it's been used and b) what it's been used for.

Comment: Please, can we have this feature. Recently on ELL there has been something like ninety, (maybe more?) tag edits which dominated over four active pages. And the majority of these *necessary* and *legitimate*  tag edits were performed by a mod. What's the big deal, when the newest page is not affected? A huge one on smaller sites which receives a new question hourly or every two/three hours, and when someone posts a new answer on an old question, it gets buried on the **active** page.

Comment: Change "editing tags" to "minor edits (including tag only edits)", and I'll give you a +1. Seriously, the bumping has been used as an argument for rejecting small improvements to questions.

Comment: I think that completely hiding tag edits is bad because of the whole principle of being transparent, etc. Perhaps there could be a "mass tag edits" heading in the sidebar where moderators can mass edit tags? Or the sidebar on meta?

Answer (score 141):

Two more minor requests:

[Allow unregistered accounts to delete their own posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273440/allow-unregistered-accounts-to-delete-their-own-posts): this one should be fairly obvious. This occurs a lot when some unregistered user finds out that they can't delete their own post, and decides to just vandalize it. This is a restriction for no good reason ("Cookie-based accounts don't support voting, therefore they don't support deletion" doesn't help an unregistered user remove their post), so I'd support removing it.

---

[What is the reputation required to edit one's own deleted question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281122/what-is-the-reputation-required-to-edit-ones-own-deleted-question): That's not a feature request, but it details the problem:

> One of my friends who is new to the SE recently posted a question on
>   SO and then quickly deleted it after I pointed out some issues.
>
> However, he finds that he cannot edit the question while it is
>   deleted.

Even [high rep, experienced Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336423/prompt-before-saving-question#comment405100_336423) believe that this is possible. However, it is quite obviously not. I understand not wanting hidden spam, but [bumping on undeletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/283013/237685) would solve this problem. Further, I doubt that many spammers would even think of such a complex way to spam Stack Exchange, but many legitimate users want to fix their post if it was accidentally posted or a huge flaw was found. Allowing (at least some) users to edit their self-deleted post would be helpful.

Comment: Both are good suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: *This occurs a lot when some unregistered user finds out that they can't delete their own post* and wastes *3 golden precious* 20k delete votes in turn. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39943048/4099593 Really need this feature, Please, Please.

Answer (score 129):

### Better automatic guidance when questions are closed

Thousands of questions get closed every day over the network, and newer users are more likely to get their questions closed. Yet little guidance is given to new users, so to be helpful, close voters often resort to canned comments! The information in these canned comments should really be provided automatically. There are several things that would improve user experience a lot and are technically easy to do.

#### [Notify askers when their question is closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93842/send-authors-an-inbox-message-if-their-question-gets-closed)

If somebody comments on a question, the asker is notified. If somebody answers, the asker is notified. If somebody edits, the asker is usually notified. But if the question is closed, the asker isn't notified…

Helpful close voters may leave a comment, solely to notify the asker. Moderators on beta sites even get a nagging flag for that (“question closed without comments”). That's either busy work for closers or leaving the asker in the dark.

#### Provide better guidance about closure in general

The notice under a closed question reads:

> closed as *reason summary* by *close voters* *date of closure*
>
> *detailed close reason*
>
> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions), please [edit your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/285889/edit).

That's not too bad, but it can be improved. The guidance suggests editing, but it doesn't explain what happens next. There are many small features around this which I haven't taken the time to collect, including:

- ["Marked as duplicate" box should include a link to the dupe target](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335738/marked-as-duplicate-box-should-include-a-link-to-the-dupe-target)

Oh, and get rid of the term “on hold”, which nobody understands. There is no need for a different word to mean “closed less than 5 days ago”.

#### Reason-specific closure guidance

“If this question can be reworded to fit the rules” is so generic that it isn't really helpful. The guidance would probably depend on the type of closure — closing as unclear usually requires filling in missing information, for instance.

There should be more community-edited close reason, including not just a reason but also close-reason-specific guidance. And of course those shouldn't be shoved under off-topic, which is an endless source of confusion (“it's a programming question, why are you saying it's off-topic” — “Because you haven't provided the full code.” “What does this have to do with being on-topic? Is Javascript off-topic?” …)

#### Better heuristics to enter reopen review

A question reenters reopen review if it is edited within 5 days of being closed, but only after the first edit.

I'm sure there's room for improvement, even though I don't have specifics to offer. It's very common that someone retags a question after closure, for example, and that doesn't make the question worthy of reopening; but when the asker comes back and adds missing information, the question has already accumulated “leave closed” votes and it's too late for the reopen queue to do its job. Edits by the asker should be more likely to trigger reopening, but edits made by someone who adds information that the asker provided in a comment should also count somehow.

#### Make migrations sensible

Instead of making migration a reason to close, [make migration what happens *if* a question gets closed *and* there is another suitable site](/q/251568/149076). [“It belongs on site Y” is not a reason to close a question](/q/260769/149076) posted on site X if it also belongs on site X. On the other hand, if site X has closed a question then denizens of site Y should be the ones deciding whether to accept the question on Y, not denizens of site X.

Comment: [Better guidance in duplicate-closed questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335738/1048572)

Comment: Very different items here, but I agree with all of them.

Comment: Sadly, the % of cases where the asker edits after closure are not high. And the % of these which are reopened tend to be far lower still. For this reason, I like [Wrzlprmft's idea](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285889/lets-plan-the-second-iteration-of-the-stack-exchange-quality-project/285951#285951): side-step the whole cycle if at all possible.

Comment: @Shog9 How often the asker edits after closure isn't really relevant. The reopening procedures aren't for the unsalvageable crap that gets closed, they're for the salvageable questions that needed a second iteration from the asker to get to a workable state. The important thing is how often those edits *should* lead to reopening, and how often the edits do lead to reopening if they should.

Comment: I disagree strongly about the use of "on hold".  It's vitally important not to discourage new users.  Too often I've seen a cycle like: New user asks question which is interesting, but technically violates a rule of the se in question --> Question closed without discussion --> new user leaves and is never seen again.  "On hold" conveys the need to edit and tidy up, without telling the new user they've been shut down.

Comment: @Tynam How on earth does “on hold” convey the need to edit? “Awaiting edits” or “closed pending edits” would convey the need to edit. But “on hold”? That just says “wait for someone to deal with it”... Besides, I've rarely if ever seen an *interesting* question that gets closed without any discussion. Crap questions, sure, but if the question is “do my homework kthxbye” then I don't mind if the user leaves.

Comment: @Gilles: I'm not saying "on hold" is the best possible terminology; I agree with you.  I'm just saying "Closed" is *terrible*.  And if you haven't seen an interesting question closed - maybe you're not on the same stack as I; I have.  I raised this precisely because I just spent time following up with a new user who asked something interesting and useful (but against the local stack rules in a non-obvious way) who'd had their question closed without comment.  They won't be back, and it's our loss.

Comment: @Tynam I've seen interesting questions get closed, sure. But rarely without any comments.

Answer (score 125):

**New users need better awareness of what is expected of them when they answer their first question, especially when it is old.**

### TL;DR We are speaking about the NAA (Not an Answer) Problem

Robert explained [about the issues created by uninformed users while asking their first question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285903/311398), so let us also extend that to answers.

### Background

The [New Answers to Old questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions) shows all the answers on questions that have been asked at least 30 days earlier. This is a hot bed of NAAs (Not-an-answer's), as well as VLQs (Very Low Quality posts). Most of the bad answers there follow a general pattern, and hence, we decided to write a [small application](https://stackapps.com/questions/7049/natty-bringing-10k-moderation-to-all) that tries to figure out those types of answers and reports it to us after filtering a lot of data. Some interesting revelations were

- **Almost all** the posts that were small and ended with a question mark were NAAs!
- **Almost all** the posts that had wordings like "I have the same problem", etc., were NAAs!
- **ALL** the posts that had a combination of more than one of these factors were NAAs!

There are more than 200 reports in a day on Stack Overflow, and about 100 are reviewed by us and nearly 90% of them are NAAs (or VLQs). We can see the results of the individual filters here: (tps are NAAs and fps are falsely detected posts)

[image: An image of the analyzed results - 1]

[image: An image of the analyzed results - 2]

The dataset of all the posts with feedback are [here](https://gist.github.com/Bhargav-Rao/786f42d0f4c9aab75648c367508c00f7).

### What makes people write a question in place of an answer?

Getting to the root of the issue, is what we need to do. While answering a question a new user sees this:

[image: Answer Pop Up]

The answer pop up links to [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), but, that page never mentions about not writing a bad answer. That's the main issue that we have at our hand.

### Requests to the SE Team

Pre Answering: Make the user know what a BAD ANSWER is!

- Split the trio, i.e., help, clarification and responding, into three different bullet points (and provide examples). Lists are [more helpful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17205/311398) than writing them in a single line.
- Prevent the users from stating that *I don't have rep, I answer* by adding a link to [*Why is the 50 rep limit present?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)
- Inform the users about link only answers and their ill effects and [*Why should I not add a link only answer?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)
- <sub>Scare them by speaking about answer bans</sub>

Post Answer Writing: Make the user know that they did not read the rulez.

- Detect the answers as NAAs by using simple techniques like, *Post ending with question mark*, etc. Add a warning label to those answers just like the pop up we get when a code is badly formatted and inform the user that their post might be a NAA
- Prevent the users from entering gibberish and non-English posts. Add an error label that mentions them that their post is not accurate for the site.

Post Answer Submitting: Sigh, can't help, but help the reviewers.

- Reduce the number of reviews needed to complete an LQP Queue review from 6.
- Have binding flags, like the close votes. 3 flags soft delete a post.
- Add a "move to comment" privilege, with 3 votes needed (similar to delete votes). Let the high rep users also decide.
- Educate the 3k+ to review.

Another personal request is to [Enhance the "New Answers to Old Questions" moderator tool](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319952/enhance-the-new-answers-to-old-questions-moderator-tool). It's really hard to use that at the state it is in, now.

We can be sure that the users will continue to post NAAs even after these are implemented, but these should help us reduce the number of NAAs by a bit at least.

Comment: "Detect the answers as NAAs by using simple techniques like, Post ending with question mark, etc." Actually this is [status-almost-completed](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-almost-completed). All we have to do is to integrate [NATOBot](http://stackapps.com/questions/7049/natobot-bringing-10k-moderation-to-all) to the system as well as SmokeDetector!

Comment: @dorukayhan While NAAs are being detected with a pretty good accuracy, The bot has a  lot of fps with VLQs. Hence I feel that it's still a bit premature. Smokey on the other hand, has been tested a lot.

Comment: This problem won't go away for good until comments cease to be treated as second-class and ephemeral, but one thing that would _really_ help is a way to explicitly ask the OP a complicated question, one that won't fit into the comment box.  "In order to answer this question I need you to run the following test program and report its output: [code...]" is the prototypical case, but there are others.

Comment: If we make someone rewrite their “not an answer” before they think it has been posted, it will become harder to find them.

Comment: Maybe make ever use that has had an answer deleted as "not an answer" complete and pass a test before they can post anther answer.

Comment: @Ian, For your first comment, The answers will still pass through the first post (and/or late answer) review queues. So, those posts might still be discovered. Another way might be to alter the Warning label in such a way that it informs the users that they are asking a question and not an answer. For your second comment, Yes, That's a better idea.

Comment: @zwol Yeah, I hate those types of NAAs. Those which are too long to fit into a comment. ([Like these](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40004633/4099593)). But, in my experience, They're usually good enough to be another question or bad enough to be deleted with no loss of useful material. There has been no in between. Thanks anyway, I'll be monitoring the late answers 10k tools and try to find out such posts.

Comment: @zwol we could mitigate a lot of that problem by allowing some basic formatting in comments and increasing the character limit (or not counting code blocks toward the character limit)

Comment: "What makes people write a question in place of an answer?" -- attempt to circumvent a question ban might be a popular reason for that. As far as I know system keeps an (internal) record of users bumping into the block - that makes it possible to, say, trigger a warning if it detects attempt to answer after a recent block. _"**Wait!** You've recently been blocked to ask questions. Consider that if you are posting question into the answer it will be deleted. Please select the check box 'I understand that and I am going to post an answer, not a question' in order to proceed answering"_

Comment: Interesting point @gnat, I remember one such user who had asked a question in place of an answer. They later confessed that they were question banned. After that answer, they were answer banned too. (Perhaps).  But I haven't seen that as a regular occurrence. Do you have any idea as to how to monitor those users? (as a non-mod). If so, we can certainly find out if it occurs more often and add that as a new request to Tim.

Comment: @BhargavRao non mods can't reliably monitor that and as far as I know even mods can't, bumps into blocks are only kept internally in the system and one needs dev access to see. Regular users can only guess by checking questions in the user profile and mods can only make a bit better informed guess because they can additionally see the history of user deleted questions. If you want to learn more then probably the only way is to request SE team for stats on how many NAAs are posted by recently blocked askers (FWIW there was similar request at Programmers meta and they gave stats on it)...

Comment: ...you can use that stats request as example if you want: [How many questions do we get from users recently blocked at SO, how many of these are closed / deleted?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6592/31260) (I am not sure if MSE would be the right place for it though, probably MSO is a better fit)

Comment: Mabe a first-class, voted and scored follow-on question, with full answer-box editing. Could look like a comment but be blown open as needed. Answers could be moderator-demoted to such a thing.

Comment: "move to comment" is quite an elegant idea to solve part of this problem. It allows moderation to prevent poor comments being posted as well as  educates the new user a bit. It has some potential for abuse, but no more the current system at first glance.

Comment: @DoritoStyle Yep. ATM moving to comments is one way only. So there needs to be some way to reverse this to prevent users from abusing this feature. But unfortunately, Jon doesn't like increased [comment moderation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252691/311398).

Answer (score 116):

I'm recommending [Categories other than "off-topic" should allow custom close reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210314/categories-other-than-off-topic-should-allow-custom-close-reasons) be considered for this project. See [Nathan Tuggy's excellent answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267216/284336) there to see how widely useful this would be to a variety of sites.

This is an issue for new users who have their questions closed and what they see first is "off topic" which is confusing to them because they can't understand how their question is off topic (which it's not). This often requires a knowing user to explain that the question isn't actually off topic, it's ______. If they think the question is off topic, they may be less inclined to fix it, while if the main close header says "unclear what you're asking" instead, they may be more interested in improving their question.

It's also an issue for new close voters/flaggers who may not be aware that these close reasons exist or have difficulty finding them because they don't fit the "off topic" category.

Comment: Yes, the custom reason should be at the top level, not buried under the Off-Topic reason, especially since you can modify the text to say whatever you want anyway.

Comment: Agree with Catija. Disagree with TylerH. I think giving a `groupby`able primary reason to which you can _add_ your custom text will keep whatever stat-keeping is available to the moderators.

Comment: [I've only been ranting about this for.. oh, years.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185102/responding-to-your-too-localized-concerns/185129#185129) +1

Comment: @Michael I'm fine with a custom reason in every category so long as there's also one at the root level, where it is most useful for the purpose of closing questions.

Comment: Using a custom reasons does increase the possible of a revenge down vote as it shows clearly who is "to blame".

Comment: @IanRingrose not sure what you mean. This is not about the "other" box that creates a comment, it is about the site-specific close reasons. They work just like all of the other close reasons.

Answer (score 85):

A minor suggestion, but we can [help make new askers more likely to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272104/307622) by pointing them to the "accept" button when they try to upvote and don't have sufficient reputation.

Comment: Care to explain the anonymous downvote?  What Tim Post said is *"we're going to put the highest priority on small-ish things that could potentially make a big impact first"* and he also emphasized improving the new user experience.  This would align perfectly with both of those.

Comment: @hichris123, not the same thing.  That only works if the asker *can* upvote, and it reminds them that they can *also* accept an answer.  It doesn't educate new users who *can* accept an answer but *cannot* upvote, which is even more important IMO.

Comment: Oh, oops. I didn't read enough I guess. Does this actually not happen? I'm surprised, seems fairly obvious.

Comment: @hichris123, I know it's surprising, but you can judge from the number of comment conversations that go along these lines: "Thanks, it worked!  But I can't click the 'up' arrow on your answer for some reason."  "You can only vote after you get enough reputation, but if my answer solved your question you can accept it by clicking the checkmark."  "What checkmark?  I only see voting buttons."  "It should be just to the left of the answer, below the voting buttons."  "Thanks, I see it now.  Accepted!"  :)

Comment: A big floating flashing arrow, scrolling text saying "award best answer"; +1

Comment: @axsvl77 Accepted answer is not necessarily the best. Also 'award' is not exactly accurate either (in common parlance, at least).

Comment: Ha! You're right; in this instance, I meant award = designate. Not regular usage.

Answer (score 80):

On some sites, there are simple heuristics to detect problematic questions.  By detecting a few problematic keywords, we can easily alert posters to potential problems before the question is even submitted.

For example, Code Review has been [requesting these automatic alerts](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6686/9357) for over half a year:

- No code in the question
- Title that says "wrong" or "incorrect"
- The presence of "this code" or "do this" in the title
- [Code that should be in a code block](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6777/9357)

The last two, in particular, would also benefit Stack Overflow.

As another example, [English.SE considers the use of `monospace` text for emphasis to be a *faux pas*](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/363/16310) that should be edited out.  We have the technology to detect backticks and advise the poster to use italics instead, right?  That would be preferable to [bastardizing Markdown](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3358/16310).

By giving automated instantaneous feedback, we should be able to improve question quality and increase user satisfaction.  That would be better than review queues, comments, waiting for the original poster to respond, downvotes, and close votes.

Comment: I'll say that some of this is most likely going to be covered in some of our /ask page redesign, etc.  We're looking at a variety of things that we can do to encourage users to include everything they should to make the question better.

Comment: @bluefeet that's great, but **#PeopleDontRead**. The idea is to pop a red in-your-face warning that you can't miss, e.g. when your question title says "Why isn't this code working?" it's 100% guaranteed your question is off-topic. Having yet another page to link to after we've closed their question isn't going to help, *if they can post such a question without the system telling them "WAIT! Your question is likely OFF-TOPIC!", then it's too late already*. 60% of CR's closures involve broken code, if pointing them to `[help/on-topic]` isn't enough, I don't see how `[ask]` is going to change it.

Comment: @bluefeet It'd be important for the triggers in this functionality to be configurable on a per-site basis, so that the different communities can define different standards for acceptable questions.

Comment: As you said @Meta'sMug People Don't Read, and it's entirely possible they would not read a giant red box yelling at them either, but as I mentioned we're looking at a variety of ways to offer better guidance to users when they ask their question.

Comment: @bluefeet they might not read it, but then at least their first clue for being off-topic wouldn't be a close vote, a downvote, and/or a friendly canned comment kindly explaining why their post is off-topic and linking them to the help center (or all of the above): their first clue would be a very short, obvious notification they'd have to actively ignore. Basically it boils down to [Robert Harvey's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285903/197901).

Comment: If people don't read then delete their question.

Comment: @MilesRout Wherever possible, the goal should be nudge the marginal questions into being respectable, or to help people post their question to the right site. "Then delete their question" is like saying "spam isn't that bad — is it really that hard to just press Delete?" And, to many new users, reading the Help Center pages is only slightly less onerous than reading the Terms of Service. We can make things better for everyone — we have the technology.

Comment: @Meta'sMug Not to go down a rabbit hole, but that topic title is not at all a guarantee that the question is off-topic.

Comment: @TylerH On CodeReview, I'd take 99:1 odds on any question with that title being Off-Topic.

Comment: For a while now I've been wanting to build a model for predicting self-study questions and off-topic programming questions on Cross Validated. It would greatly cut down on review load during midterms and finals season.

Answer (score 76):

### Improve communication between flaggers and moderators, or, "what's obsolete about that?"

Some sites are very chatty.  And that means flags on comments.  My biggest moderation time sink is comment flags, and, within that, obsolete flags.  I don't know *why* it's obsolete -- was the post edited?  Was the comment it replied to removed?  Or is it *not* obsolete, but the guy arguing with that other guy is trying to remove comments he doesn't like?

[Can we add more information to "obsolete" flags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281607/can-we-add-more-information-to-obsolete-flags) requests a little bit of tooling that would help flaggers tell moderators what the problem is, so we can handle the flags efficiently.  We all have better things to do than to read through 20 comments and 6 revisions to figure out what the history is.

On one of my sites we've [asked our users to mostly stop using the obsolete flag and use custom flags instead](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4166/472), but this only works for people who've seen the meta post and remember.  Also, it means we're giving the opposite advice for comments ("please use custom flags if you have any doubts") as for posts ("please don't use custom flags if the built-in ones apply").  That's confusing for users who aren't SE fanatics keeping up on every detail ("wait, am I supposed to use 'other' or avoid it here?").

Comment: Whenever I mark a comment as obsolete I always wonder if the moderator knows what I am talking about. It would be nice to leave a simple comment.

Comment: Alternatively, let 10k users handle obsolete/chatty comment flags to lighten the moderator load. I have read some discussions here and there, but have not taken the time yet to really dive into this and write a feature request.

Comment: Also let me mark many comments on the same post as obsolete along with    providing the additional information to the mods in one package, instead of lots of unrelated flags.

Comment: @IanRingrose if you really need to flag multiple comments on one post, the recommendation is to flag the post with a custom flag explaining why you think the comments need to be cleared.

Comment: @Catija that's the recommendation, but it's still a hassle for either the flagger (collecting links to specific comments to bundle together) or the mod (to dig through it).  Some sort of "these comments go together and should have the same disposition" affordance could be helpful.

Comment: I’ve drastically cut down using obsolete flags for precisely this reason. Most of the time, I flag for mod attention stating *obsolete -* followed by a reason.

Comment: @JanDoggen: Alternatively, [give the comment’s author a chance to decide about the flag first](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252883/255554).

Comment: @JanDoggen true.  I love it when users can sort out their own obsolete threads without involving mods.

Answer (score 65):

One of the minor-ish things that I would like, and have been meaning to check on the feasibility of would be to add custom filtering for certain sites in the "Hot Topics" bar down the side.

I don't really care at all about certain network sites, but often see a lot of their stuff show up. For example, I routinely have 3 or 4 from puzzling.stackexchange.com in my sidebar, no offense to those guys. However, every now and then I see stuff from other things like DIY, which I do find interesting, but I'm sure they're more often drowned in the noise from other sites.

Perhaps other people find this useful too. If not, no worries!

Comment: *ahem* Esperanto. *ahem* physics/math. *ahem* worldbuilding +1

Comment: @Jeutnarg physics/math is one of those that I occasionally do check out when the title sounds very interesting. Therefore, I made my request a little more clear that we should have the ability individually to say "I never want to see these 20 sites", or something like that.

Comment: I already read it that way, but I can see why they wouldn't have. FWIW, I just listed mine, not everybody else's. I'm sure that scifi and rpg exchange would be on some people's lists, but I like those.

Comment: @Jeutnarg Worldbuilding is actually one of the niche sites with better content out there... at least it started out that way. Now... puzzles, codegolf, lifehacks... I wouldn't mind seeing those sites del--er... ignorable.

Comment: I find Worldbuilding super interesting, but I tend to be on SO at work... it's more of a 'I like you, but I can't care right now' filter. If this was a thing, I'd probably make a script to change my preferences during work hours.

Comment: That feature is currently available in [SOX](http://stackapps.com/questions/6091/stack-overflow-extras-sox).

Comment: @fixer1234 Thanks for the heads up. However, it would get tedious installing that on every computer I would use to access the network. However, that could be used as a template for how to implement it making the SE Devs' jobs easier. I'll probably install it on a few as well.

Comment: it would be great if ignored tags were honored for hot network questions too (applicable when one is a member of the network site)

Comment: the only reliable way to achieve what you ask for is to [Increase the Hot Network Questions randomness](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247195/165773). This is because hot questions currently stick for too long and that annoys those who want more diverse list to pick the sites they prefer. But this is unlikely to happen, two or three months ago SE team folks told that they are perfectly happy with the way how hot questions work now

Comment: @gnat Then it sounds like SE could use a reminder that some users aren't.

Comment: they seem to ignore complaints about that. The only thing that worried them was meta noise when Stack Overflow questions stuck in hot list for too long (["croissants"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190106/165773)) but after they figured a trick to quickly drop them off the list they don't worry anymore

Comment: That would be an amazing feature, but was [declined in the past](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84389/filtering-hot-questions). I truly don't understand why the hell they refuse to turn a spam-like advertising of other sites into targeted advertising. It would be a win-win situation; we are served content we like, they promote content we are willing to consume.

Comment: Related request: [Don't show questions with ignored tags on Hot Network Questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271335/191265).

Comment: @gnat While I agree with your historical analysis, Q&As like this seem to point directly at the opposite conclusion.

Comment: How will this improve the quality of questions and answers?

Comment: @IanRingrose One of the things that they mentioned was that they want to "Improving the experience of our existing users" including "We're going to explore some ideas for better filtering of the questions that you see indicated by information that you give us.".

Answer (score 58):

## Give new users better advice on how to write question titles.

There are a *lot* of terrible question titles out there - and I'm not just talking about ones along the lines of "Plz send me teh codez for my C++ porgam". Many ignore the advice given in [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/274942), and are

- Not specific enough
- Grammatically incorrect to the extreme
- Not specific at all
- Not concise enough
- Not specific in the slightest
- Actually part of the body, rather than a succinct summary
- Not specific

This is a problem on a lot of Stack Exchange sites, from what I've seen, and I think that helping new users could solve it. I propose linking to the above [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) question somewhere near the input box for the question title in the first few questions from a new user, which can hopefully make titles, at the least, a bit better.

Comment: With the option of linking to a site-specific how-to, maybe!

Comment: (1) I’m bothered when I see a question where the author composes a multi-sentence interrogative, and then puts the first sentence into the title box and the rest into the body — rather than putting the entire text into the body, and then adding a *title* (summary).  I expect question bodies to be self-contained, so I find these hard to read.  Am I alone in this?  Would you add it to your list? (2) Do we have any automated tools for evaluating titles for these criteria?  Something like Microsoft Word’s grammar checker would be better than nothing.

Comment: @G-Man Honestly, the easiest way to address *that* issue--and something that I'd actually appreciate even as an experienced asker--would be to put the title field *below* the question-body field. It's fairly well known that the title is often the *last* thing you should write when writing an essay, journal paper, novel, etc; question-asking seems to work the same way, I think. (And if we had the machine-learning capabilities to do so, it would be awesome to auto-generate a proposed question title based on the content, the way we auto-suggest tags...)

Comment: @G-Man I like your point (1). A related pet peeve of mine is when the asker just copies the single-sentence body into the title, or vice versa.

Comment: @Kyle, I think the reason the title field is on top is so the "Questions that may already have your answer" box that pops up has something to work from. I agree with you though.

Comment: Some regulars could also use something like this. I have been known to downvote questions even from reasonably high-rep users simply because the question title is not a meaningful summary of the question, *particularly* if edits to try to improve are rejected or rolled back (as opposed to being used as a starting point for the OP to adjust further). Yep, guilty as charged!

Comment: Some veteran users could use a question-phrasing workshop too. +1.

Answer (score 57):

## Spam

We still get too much of it. The built-in filters do an awesome job keeping a lot of it out of our faces, but they're not catching everything.

[SmokeDetector](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) is reporting spam posts for people to flag, which is generating about [100 flags a day](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/admin/api_feedback). That's around 50-60 posts per day, across the network.

That's decreasing, but it's still 50-60 posts more than we need.

A couple of months ago, Pops came around and did a feasibility study on integration between the two systems. The results of that seemed pretty favourable - to quote Pops:

> [Seriously though, that's crazy impressive.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31634754#31634754)

As part of this quality project, I'd like to see us do something about spam - that may be working out an integration strategy, it may be something else on SE's end, or it may be something that doesn't need SE involvement - but let's see how low we can get those spam numbers.

Comment: Yup, the reason I was looking at Smokey then was ahead of this project. Be back with you soon!

Comment: That's precisely what we're going to look at. I designed the original system  and it has been holding, but we need to keep it modern. The problem with the system now is 100 spam posts come in, they're blocked within seconds, but there's still 100 spam posts to clean up which gives the perception of swiss cheese on the front end. Integration with Smokey at the _first_ instance could conceivably prevent 70 of them from being posted, we just need to figure out how we can make it happen.

Comment: @TimPost Yep, makes sense. We've got some ideas about how things can be interested - just yell when you want to get discussing :)

Comment: This was already discussed in the question... "We're looking at some upgrades to the anti-spam and abuse mitigation systems. They've been good to us, but we need to keep them relevant. There are some awesome community-run projects that have been helping tremendously, and we're currently looking at ways that we might be able to integrate them more properly."

Comment: @hichris123 Well, he added a bit more context to it (while enthusiastically agreeing that we need to do more) - I think he's just pretty happy that we're getting close to getting to it :)

Comment: @TimPost I'd much rather see other stuff prioritized rather than spam (like bullets 1 & 2). I say this even being one of those who works on SmokeDetector. :)

Comment: By "spam" do you mean "unsolicited commercial advertisements?"  Or do you subscribe to the looser form of the term which basically means "anything unwanted?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey I subscribe to the definition set out in the MSE FAQ on the subject

Comment: That definition appears to mean "anything unwanted."  I ask, because UCE seems to be well-controlled on the Stack Exchange sites, while question quality is still somewhat in "The Wild West" territory.  If we're going to talk about these things intelligently, I think it's important to make the distinction.

Comment: On Stack Exchange, the term "spam" has, historically anyway, been limited to unsolicited commercial advertisements. A good example of that is the spam flag. This is very different than other communities and forums on the Internet, which often use the term "spam" to refer to any undesirable or unwanted content. I agree with @RobertHarvey that we should be consistent. I think favoring the narrow definition is better, since it's a particular type of flag. I've rejected spam flags unwanted posts, but not unsolicited commercial advertisements because it doesn't meet the SE definition of spam.

Comment: @Robert I was going to start a thread on "spam". It seems some (younger?) people take the definition from the *verb* form "to spam" that apparently means "to pepper someone with a lot of junk" and use the flag to mark the posts as a thing used to *spam* the site. ie About ¾ of the "spam" flags I see are not spam, but just "annoying junk" with no "advertising" content (which I decline, usually with an explanatory custom message). Maybe there should be a custom "This is not spam! Just downvote or vote to delete" canned decline response

Comment: @TimPost Note that not all filters of SmokeDetector have a high true positive to false positive ratio. If we ever integrate SpamRam and SD we should only use the most successful filters (such as [links following arrows in body](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/reason/77) and [known-bad websites in title](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/reason/21)).

Comment: @dorukayhan That - but we've got ideas to solve that too.

Comment: @TimPost  Be careful, if you give feedback to the spammer to quickly about their post, they can learn how to bypass SmokeDetector, at present they don’t know they have been detected, as most spamming systems don’t check for results after getting conformation the post has been made.

Comment: @IanRingrose They can *already* figure out how to pass Smokey if they want to; the code is freely available on GitHub. They don't, though.

Comment: @ArtOfCode It's not about whether it's *possible* to circumvent, it's about whether they realize that they need to circumvent it, and how quickly they're able to figure out how. Rapid feedback (e.g. rejecting posts) does make both more likely. I do know a thing or two about SEO spam, and can tell you that feedback speed there is a very genuine concern. It may still not be an issue here, because those spammers are probably also spamming a ton of other places and may not notice/care too much about rejection here, but that's a different reason.

Comment: @Jefromi The built-in system already rejects posts immediately. The only thing that would change with integration would be that Smokey feeds the system to tell it *what* to reject.

Comment: Well, so it would reject *more* posts immediately, but yes, I get that. My point is that rapid feedback is a real issue in some cases, and that the reason it turns out okay in this case seems to be that the spammers apparently don't care enough to respond to the feedback. It's not about whether the logic is concealed (existing SE spam detection) or open-source (Smokey).

Comment: (An alternative theory is that they're trying to circumvent the blocking they have rapid feedback on, and when they periodically succeed, that's what you pick up with Smokey. But I haven't gotten the impression it's quite that organized.)

Comment: @Jefromi Given that we can positively identify 10 or more *distinct* groups of spammers, I think you're right it's not that organised :)

Comment: Since SE originates from programmers, so everyone tries to solve problems like programmers: make better filters, make bots, create intricate ban systems etc etc. Maybe think outside the programmer-box instead? The only effective counter-measure long-term is to take legal action against the spammers, or at the very least report them to their ISPs.

Comment: @Lundin Do you really think some spammer sitting in russia, china, india or some obscure small country or even using hacked boxes is going to care that you report them?

Comment: @Magisch Of course it might not always be feasible, it's on case-to-case basis.

Comment: What about not showing the detected spam to someone coming for anther IP address, and just waiting 5 minutes before the auto delete is done?

Comment: @IanRingrose Then how do we see it to flag it?

Comment: @ArtOfCode, maybe a review queue, but note I said "detected spam", e.g. the system already knows it is spam.

Comment: @IanRingrose If the system knows it's spam with that level of certainty, why not just delete it instead of hiding it for 5 minutes?

Comment: @ArtOfCode so that the software posting it does not know that it has failed an automatic spam detection test, otherwise the posing software can learn to defeat the test.

Comment: @IanRingrose Not *reject* the post - act as if the post has been accepted, but delete it immediately after posting. Most spam systems won't go back and check.

Answer (score 56):

## [Make close votes scale with reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266500/proposal-to-make-close-votes-scale-with-rep)

Right now, users with 10,000 or more reputation get to vote to delete 5 closed questions per day. This number increases as users get more rep, to a maximum of 30 daily delete votes.

Why on earth do we not apply the same logic to close votes that are a lot less <strike>destructive</strike> potent than delete votes?

Comment: This is planned. What we don't want to do is make our most avid users feel like they have even more responsibility (and feel bad if they don't have the time). Scaling with rep works a bit, but also scaling with the efficacy of their previous votes. [Related discussion here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281818/is-using-reputation-to-scale-the-number-of-close-votes-the-best-way)

Comment: @TimPost what happened to that dashboard thingy? [related message on the tavern](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=3560717#3560717)

Comment: Overzealous closing by high-reputation users of valid or arguably-valid questions is a problem IMHO. Super-high-reputation users are too far removed from the general population to be given that extra power. So, -1.

Answer (score 55):

## Help new users understand that answers aren't for comments.

This has been an issue for years and years and years. There have been loads of proposals to fix it - by [getting rid of the 50-rep comment threshold](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12119/274942), [having low-rep users' comments reviewed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186954/274942), and so on and so forth. These specific solutions have been [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), for reasons I agree with, but I still think we need to do something to explain to users that they can't use answers as comments.

A close [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) I found is [Low-rep users posting comments as answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183883/274942), which suggests adding a pop-up in certain cases when new users try to post answers. [A reasonable objection](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183884/274942) was that the Low Quality Posts queue often deals with these, but I think we can still do something to cut the issue off before answers reach the queue.

Perhaps the pop-up could

- Explain to these new users that they need 50 rep to comment, and link to the site's Privileges page.
- Explain why answers shouldn't be used for comments.
- Explain that comments posted as answers will likely be downvoted and deleted. It could contain examples (posts with the gist of "Me too!", "Nice question!", "I had the same problem", etc.).

The pop-up could be shown to users the first X times they answer a question and have less than Y rep (should Y=50?), with X hopefully fairly small. To be effective, it would have to be highly visible; putting it off to the side, as Blender suggested, might not be enough.

When I flag answers on Stack Overflow, a lot follow certain patterns, so it's easy to find them via queries after the fact. The ones I find are generally from people who have the same problem as the asker, so maybe a second pop-up could contain additional information explaining that comments should not be used for this purpose, triggered for newish users when the answer text contains phrases like

- "Please help me"
- "I had the same problem"
- "Did you solve this?"

and so on.

Comment: Yes, absolutely this.  Even if it leaves answers that request some kind of clarification (which they may insist on doing anyway), then so be it.  At least helps in *some* way.  But these three answers that you mention at the bottom just need to go away forever.

Comment: I always thought this was a very silly rule. We expect far higher standards from a posted answer than a posted comment. The solution is to get rid of the rule. I believe the main reason why the rule exists is some moderator tool implementation fiasco that makes it harder for mods to moderate comments than answers, and to protect against spam.

Comment: Since this is an issue which will impact new users it needs to be considered as part of that wider review. In particular, new users could usefully receive some guidance/reminder on positive strategies for gaining reputation so they can participate more fully in the site. Overpolicing of this rule can contribute to a less than optimal early experience for new users.

Comment: I don't see the point of this.  What is so awful about giving a comment in an answer or an answer in a comment?  Just because the software makes a formatting distinction, that doesn't mean there actually is a clear distinction.

Comment: @GregLee Comments are meant to be temporary; answers are not. Plus, giving them equality would induce more of a forum-like atmosphere, which isn't the point of Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Jamal, actually, I could easily imagine someone stumbling across an unanswered question page on their way to finding a solution, then *finding* a solution, then going back to the question page as an unregistered user and posting an answer that starts out, "I had the same problem, and what solved it for me was...."  And if that gets blocked, do you think they'll stick around to figure it out?  No, they'll be gone, and so will the knowledge they would have shared.

Answer (score 53):

Can't believe no one has posted this one yet...  **[Allow badge holders to have binding close and reopen votes for other close reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248312/swing-the-gold-hammer-even-more)**.

The duplicate "hammer" has been... Wildly successful. But perhaps most surprising is how popular instant *reopen* votes have been: over the past 90 days, just a hair under 60% of all reopened questions have involved a gold-badge holder *swinging that hammer of mercy*.

Turns out, folks who've answered a crapload of questions to great success are as likely to call out incorrectly closed questions as they are to close those that need it.

...So why are we still wasting all this time with *voting*? Let's at least extend it to "Unclear", the reason I'd wager folks who've done a lot of answering are more than adept at gauging. Maybe disable it for questions that've already been answered (our definition: +1 answer or accept) just as a safety check.

And just make reopening available across the board.

Comment: I think that a lot of that comes from gold badge holders not really disagreeing with the duplicate closure but wanting to provide their own answers, dupe or not. I don't think thats a measure of success personally, but one of an open avenue to abuse the Mjolnir privileges. There are even gold badge holders who disagree with closing duplicates as a concept, do you really want to give those people even more unchecked authority?

Comment: Or vote to reopen to close as another duplicate. Happens often too. I would like to see some more statistics.

Comment: I totally disagree with "disable it for questions that've already been answered", on SO the answers that gain upvotes the quickest are wild guesses to terrible questions. Why shouldn't we be able to close those?

Comment: maybe nobody posted this because this feature is strictly specific to Stack Overflow? how many other sites have gold tag badge holders. I think that even silver tag badges are rare outside of SO, otherwise somebody would probably already asked here about ideas discussed in [Empowering tag-badge holders part II - let's look at silver?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240700/165773)

Comment: Is there good number-crunch data that supports this? If this is indeed a good idea, I would expect correlations like 'dupehammer holders are unlikely to be countermanded on reopen votes on unclear-question closures' to be reasonably strong. This would be interesting data to see.

Comment: @gnat We have several gold-badge holders on [cs.SE] and it's by no means one of the largest sites.

Comment: @Magisch The reopen-answer pattern seems easy to detect. We could include it into the suspicious behaviour detection cronjob.

Comment: I have one fundemental problem with this idea. Having a gold badge means that you have contributed a lot and/or good posts. It does not say *anything at all* about whether the user is a worthwhile moderator. I'd rather see these privileges handed out based on constructive community moderation contributions. (Of course, the whole rep-driven privilege system has the same problem. Oh wait, let me make that an answer.)

Comment: @Raphael your last comment is also an explanation why having several gold-badge holders on Computer Science doesn't help in making this feature relevant for smaller site. This is strictly specific thing of SO that they have not "several" but _many_ such users (hundreds if not thousands I think). And that makes it so that even small fraction of these users who got interested in moderation can make substantial contribution. When (smaller) site has 10 holders and 1 of them is interested, this doesn't help. When SO has 10,000 holders and 100 of them are interested, they can make a difference

Comment: @gnat You have do account for the number of full-fledged moderators and traffic, as well. On a small site, having an additional moderator (effectively) on one of the few very active tags *does* help!

Comment: @gnat, Raphael... A good bit of this data is in SEDE: [overall stats for the last year](http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/425984/posts-that-get-hammered-closed-and-what-becomes-of-them), [reopen voters](http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/439580/reopen-stats-for-top-dup-hammer-users).

Comment: @Raphael that assumes that site indeed has them, "additional moderators". Of 10 holders, it statistically can happen that no one is interested, or that one interested is away etc etc. That's what makes a radical difference at SO, where they are guaranteed to always have large enough number of interested holders

Comment: @Shog9 I see, thanks. ~300 hammered at AU, ~450 at SU, ~1,450 at Math.SE and (drumroll) 73,479 at SO. Helps to feel the difference

Comment: @gnat You were proposing 1 effective semi-mod, not me. My point is, don't look only at the absolute numbers. It's the percentages that count. If we have 4 instead of 3 mods on a high-traffic tag (by our standards) and the gold-tag guy hammers 10% of the questions that need to be closed, *that is helping*.

Comment: Total closed questions on AU, last 30 days: 2098; SO: 27341. Total *asked* questions on AU, last 30 day: 6585; SO: 262548. % closed, AU: 31%, SO 10%. @gnat.

Comment: @Raphael SEDE query provided by Shog says 13 questions were dupe hammered last year at CS, that's hardly a substantial impact (though I am not quite sure because SEDE lies by hiding stats on deleted questions)

Comment: Yeah... The actual number is 25, @gnat.

Comment: @gnat My point is not that it's helping a lot right now on CS, my point is that your argument is invalid. a) Gold badges happen on small sites. b) *If* gold-badgers (XD) decide to engage in community moderation, their relative impact *can* be high on small sites. (That said, 25 seems to be about 10% of all closures as dupe -- I'd call that relevant impact. Nothing compared to the numbers on SO, that's for sure. But then, we probably *do* catch more dupes than SO does. Wild guess.)

Comment: @Raphael that's a theory. And I agree that in theory all what you say can be true. Practice shows though that none of this happens, notice how nobody suggested to utilize gold-bagders abilities until this answer was posted. I'd venture a guess that silver-badgers abilities would be more noticeable outside of SO but since system doesn't provide them with such abilities nobody thought about this either (me included)

Comment: I like this suggestion a lot more than scaling the *number* of votes we have.  Adding more votes just increases fatigue, if users even decide to use more of them.  Adding more *weight* to votes means we're more effective with the votes we're already using anyway.

Answer (score 53):

## [Allow site specific placeholder texts to be added to the question box](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7563/59258)

Many users evidently ignore the side bar which explains how to ask questions, and what we expect to be present in our questions. A placeholder text
 would be seen by almost everyone. (Would it work in mobile? I don't know.)

Here is a quick mockup I made for ELU: (If this was implemented sites like ELU would need to spend considerably more time deciding what a good placeholder text would be.)

[image: Image showing the new question page with a placeholder text in the question body]

This would pair very well with [Tag specific question requirements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/286035/256282)

Comment: This might be a good idea for the answer box, too.

Answer (score 52):

#### Make every closure, answer, and comment deletion work like closing as duplicate

I really like [the “new” UI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250981/255554) when somebody votes or flags to close a question as a duplicate for several reasons:

- The author is directly informed what people consider to be problematic about the post. (While they [may be totally oblivious](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93842/255554) if their question is closed for another reason.) Thus they can act before there is any effective action on the post (resulting in disappointment and the difficulty to undo this action).
- The author is presented a reasonable choice of options how to proceed – either to accept the verdict or edit the post to improve it. Should they accept the verdict, there is no pointless waste of reviewer or moderator time.
- Reviewers, moderators, and other users are informed as to what the original flagger/voter thinks is problematic about the post.
- All of the above is done with the UI, not with a custom comment or similar.

Note how I did not use the words *duplicate, question,* or *closure* to describe these advantages? I see no reason why a similar UI should not be applied to closing for another reason, impending deletion on an answer, and even comments.

More specifically, I suggest:

- Adapt the mechanism for other close reasons.
- Introduce answer-deletion reasons (and get rid of the confusing and pointless distinction between VLQ and NAA ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278794/255554), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214583/255554))); inform the author directly as to what is considered problematic with the answer; make it obvious to the author that they can edit or delete their answer. Give flaggers the option to choose a reason (instead of having only reviewers select canned comments). The UI of the low-quality queue badly needs an overhaul anyway ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242345/255554), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278916/255554)).
- Inform authors when a comment is flagged and why. [This particularly makes sense when the reason is *obsolete.*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252883/255554) It may also work if the discussion in the comments digresses or if answers are posted as comments. Authors of comments flagged for other reasons may not be so understanding, but at least they may take the hint after a series of their comments was flagged. Right now, persistent comment chatterers may not even notice tons of their comments getting deleted.

Of course, in most if not all cases, flagged posts should still be subject to review if the author does not agree with the flag/closure. Also note that there are some cases where this is probably not a good idea, e.g., spam flags.

Comment: Part of this proposal effectively suggests we get rid of the 250-rep [_view close votes on your posts_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) privilege, making it available to everyone.  In reviewing this proposal, it may be worth considering why this privilege was ever necessary.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom, or just hide the user names of the voters when below 250 reps.

Comment: Trivia: that privilege predates the "vote-to-close" system, and was once called "Close your questions", @Jeffrey. Prior to early 2009, you could (at 250 rep) close your own question, preventing further answers from being posted (given there was no automatic deletion, no delete votes, and no moderators, this was pretty much *all* it did unless Jeff caught you doing it). Once the vote-to-close system landed, that particular privilege pretty much lost any utility it might have had, hence the current focus on being able to *view* close votes.

Comment: To Wrzlprmft's point: the duplicate UI change had a fairly striking effect on asker editing: it doubled, pretty much instantly, and mostly stayed there. Granted, that took it from about 6% to about 12%, but that's still quite a few questions. I could see this being a HUGE win for stuff like "Unclear".

Comment: The longer I look at this, the more I like it.

Comment: @Shog9: *Granted, that took it from about 6% to about 12%, but that's still quite a few questions.* – Also, we can presume that a considerable portion of questions flagged as duplicate actually are duplicates, in which case it is fine for the asker to leave the question as it is. This does not apply to any other closure or deletion reason, where a correct flag means that the author should edit or delete the post.

Answer (score 51):

#### Implement a working FAQ system

It is a truly painful process to find a duplicate of a question you know has been asked many times before.

The current system with the "frequent tab" is not working well. It is based on close-as-duplicates and similar activities, rather than community consensus. A number of "canonical FAQs" eventually spawn from this system over time but they drown in the number of less canonical questions present on the "frequent tab". And we always end up with several "canonical duplicates" to the same question.

After speaking with many other users who do lots of user moderation in their favourite tags (gold badge/dupe hammer), it turns out that almost every such user uses the site's "favourite" feature as their own private "canonical duplicate" list for moderation purposes. Essentially every such user has created their own FAQ. There must be so many great links gathered in each such private FAQ, but they aren't shared with other user moderators.

On SO there exists one case where the C++ community has taken the matter in their own hands and created a tag [c++-faq](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq). The site has allowed this because their FAQ system is heavily user-moderated. As a result, this system works far better than the "featured tab".

Instead of having all these "private FAQs", shouldn't we gather all this knowledge into creating an official FAQ system that actually works? Which is tag-based and points at FAQs/canonical duplicates for each tag. Which is created explicitly by the community, rather than implicitly/by chance.

Comment: (The Documentation project will not solve this, since you can't close something as a duplicate while pointing at a Documentation page.)

Comment: The tag wiki could be used for this, or let gold tab badge holders mark (or vote for) questions as FAQ and have a new FAQ tag.

Comment: @IanRingrose It is often used for that too. But it isn't consistent across tags. Plus there tends to be a lot of clutter edits to the tag wikis. A system where gold badge tag holders can nominate a question for FAQ sounds like a very good solution. A special kind of votes "agree/disagree that this should be FAQ" could be introduced.

Comment: So instead of a system based on frequently-asked questions, you want a system based on what folks *think* are frequently-asked questions?

Comment: @Shog9 The main problem is that there often doesn't exist a canonical duplicate for a frequent question, or it is too hard to find for anyone to bother. So people just keep answering the same thing over and over. Now if you make an effort into creating a canonical duplicate, like making a community wiki together with others who read the same topic, it will take ages before that one makes it to the "frequent tab". Another problem is that there are hundreds of FAQs per topic, so even if the frequent tab is relevant, it can be very hard to find what you are looking for.

Comment: Veteran users often complain about lack of research from new users. But since the veteran users themselves can't easily find a topic, then what hope is there fore new users?

Comment: The problem with this is that most of the time the system already knows what is frequently asked, based on hard data, rather than individuals impressions. Example [rust tag faq generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust?filter=all&sort=linked) includes 5 out 6 rust-faq tagged questions, [r tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r?filter=all&sort=linked) the first page is filled with faq tagged questions, [2 out the most linked c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2B%2B?filter=all&sort=linked) questions doesn't have the faq variant.

Comment: @Braiam It would be interesting to know the algorithm that determines what shows on that tab. My impression is that the "frequent tab" also includes _frequently linked_ questions, and not just frequently-closed-as-duplicate. Looking at the C tag, most of the top ranked posts are purely _frequently linked_, such as a book recommendation list, which would never be used for close-as-duplicate. If this is true and the page lists "frequently linked", then that's one major design mistake. When looking for canonical duplicates, I'm not in the slightest interested in "generic good advise" questions.

Comment: @Shog9 I think you missed the point. The point is that the system fails at automatically identifying FAQs and users are doing a better (if imperfect) job of identifying them. I tend to agree with the sentiment here; the site is generally very bad at helping you find potential duplicates. In the situations where I'm confident there's a dupe, I always turn to Google before any site tools.

Comment: Well, that's a different issue, @jpmc26: it's hard to beat Google's search; they're kinda good at it. Tons of folks have their own personal lists of common duplicates, tons of tags maintain "frequently-asked" lists in their wikis, and all of that is useful... But that all takes a great deal of effort to maintain and use, and falls apart as soon as something changes; there's no magic bullet to be found in curation - if there was, Yahoo! would still be a big list of sites organized by category.

Answer (score 50):

[Let mods (and 10k?) know when questions go "hot"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245390/let-mods-and-10k-know-when-questions-go-hot)

Because on small(er) sites, influx from the Hot Questions list can mean a disproportionate amount of not-quite-productive posts. A heads-up for community moderators would be great.

Comment: We already have the [moderator tools privilege](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) for 10k+ users. It can be used to see most viewed, commented, edited, and voted posts, but you're right, it's quite *buried in the menus*. Some sort of easily visible menu or toolbar might really help bring experienced attention to the hot spots.

Comment: @Anko Yes. "Data is accessible somewhere" != "notification".

Comment: An option to remove the question from the HNQ list would be good, too.

Answer (score 49):

#### Meta Request: Get rid of "Jeff said so"

Over the years, I have encountered several instances of "Jeff said so" reasoning, that is design decisions were justified with the opinion of the founder of SO but little else. Well, he'll soon have been gone for longer than he was here.

Please keep an open mind regarding ideas that violate policies/principles that "have always been there". The network has come a long way since the days of Jeff. Once reasonable assumptions do not fit anymore.

(To be clear, I'm using "Jeff" as a shorthand for "any kind of dogma".)

Comment: "The network has come a long way since the days of Jeff." and thank god we followed those advise, imagine what would happen if everyone got whatever they wanted... madness.

Comment: @Braiam: This is not about giving everybody what they want; this is about avoiding unnecessary dogmatism. Consider, e.g., [the request to inform askers when their question is closed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93842/255554). The only arguments against it came from Jeff (now the answer is deleted but I mostly quote it in my answer). I am pretty confident that this would have long been implented if Jeff hadn’t said so.

Comment: Maybe get rid of 'Joel said so', given that Jeff's ideas were a lot better than Joel's.

Comment: @MilesRout and the 'Joel said yes' too...

Comment: As a fellow Jeff, I disapprove of this message...

Comment: Which specific assumptions do not fit anymore?

Comment: @TravisJ To name just one example: "Every question is ontopic on exactly one site." That said, this is more about the general mindset. I have seen many feature requests closed as duplicates of [tag:status-declined] posts that are a) old and b) declined without much discussion but a healthy dose of dogma instead. This has to stop.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft many of Jeff worries were more or less well founded except for a handful ones, but many more were critical for the correct grow of SE sites.

Comment: @Braiam: If you are doing something because it is well-founded, you are not doing things because Jeff said so and you are not dogmatic. Ideas should be judged by their usefulness and not by their source. That’s the entire point of this answer.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft remember that many things that Jeff said weren't meant for us... SE could say "Jeff said so" without elaborating, but Jeff may have good reasons, or no reasons at all.

Comment: @Braiam which seems to be the point of this answer; 'stop giving us "Jeff said so" as justification for certain things'. If Jeff said so because X, Y, Z, then use X, Y, Z as the justification. If he just said so to say so, then say "because we want to and don't have a better reason or alternative".

Comment: Jeff Atwood stopped being an influencing factor ages ago.  As to "any kind of dogma," we're never in short supply of that.  When you say "stop being dogmatic" to some people, you might as well say "stop being a dog" to your dog.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I distincly recall having (and seeing) seeing questions closed as duplicates of such that were answered (and "closed") by one Jeff saying "no, because" ages ago.

Comment: Well, the way you fix that is by writing a new meta post challenging the status quo.  No new post, no new consensus.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yea, except these get closed as duplicate as well.

Comment: Does StackExchange (as a company) have a set of mission statements? Is "what Jeff said" still relevant to those? I think being able to directly quote mission statements or even guidelines would be a fine way to combat this thinking.

Answer (score 46):

## Tag specific question requirements

As proposed in [Tag specific question requirements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286032/307988)

We currently have some handy tag-specific alerts when asking questions with certain tags. These are for certain problem questions that are only a good fit for the site if they follow certain requirements. The alerts list these guidelines and specific requirements.

> [image]

These alerts are great, but they don't go far enough and people simply ignore them a lot of the time. I propose we make these more prominent and permanent. They are currently (I believe) only implemented by devs on a case by case basis, let's give that power to the people who care about them (certainly mods and maybe high rep users).

A quick mockup:

> [image]

I'm not totally sold on my mockup, it's just a quick idea. Maybe the check boxes on each point are too much, I don't know—but there needs to be *some* interaction.

Comment: *people simply ignore them a lot of the time* – Which could be due to the fact that [people do not see them most of the time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278399/255554).

Comment: Ah yes, I do mention that in the feature-req, didn't realise it was already reported.

Comment: And soon you'll have walls of text like https://it.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=MediaWiki:Edittools&oldid=80540818 before the submit button-

Comment: But **#peopledontread** even the text they get already... :-(

Comment: @einpoklum sure, that’s the point. Interaction at least forces them to *look* and if they still haven’t read then we know they *intentionally* didn’t read.

Answer (score 43):

Some low-hanging fruit:

#### Give moderators one-click declines on auto flags

I mentioned this a few days ago in SO's mod room:

> On auto flags, we should have two one-click dismiss buttons - 'helpful' and 'not helpful'
>
> That'd let us get meaningful numbers on how useful auto flags are - right now I tend to dismiss them as helpful whether they are or not, just because it's two clicks vs. four clicks.

I don't know what, exactly, we'll find from this... but I know we'd find something. There are plenty of auto flags that aren't really necessary, and mod time wasted on those can't be used in other (more valuable) places.

This would let staff look for / verify patterns on a deeper, more objective level than we currently can.

Comment: In particular, the "Too Many Comments" flags.  Comments don't need to be scrutinized by a moderator at all unless someone raises their hand.

Comment: Side note: If you think an auto flag isn't necessary, then poke one of us in the mod room. I'm always looking at ways to adjust some of these auto-flags and will dig into any of them to see if they are beneficial.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Those flags actually age away after a period of time if there are no additional comments being added to the conversation.

Comment: @RobertHarvey for what it's worth, every time I see one of those on Workplace it almost _always_ includes some, ah, less than useful content.

Comment: @enderland Could definitely see that on the more soft-subject sites, but SO and others tend to raise cases like http://stackoverflow.com/a/40050748/1849664 (not worried about revealing the flag, you could SEDE it up anyway) where the comments might not need to stick around, but it'd be a prohibitively large amount of work to evaluate every one, in every case.

Comment: @Undo alternatively just make it so mods on any site can turn off any community flag...

Comment: Honestly, when I see the too many comments flag, I ignore it and leave it for a fellow mod (sorry guys). Part of me wants to do something to see if there's any useless or low value comments to delete, but it takes time that I often don't have when I jump on in a short 5 minute break at work. Sometimes, the comment thread can actually add value to a future reader and it's a lot more visible than a chat room, so I don't want to blindly delete, but I also can't immediately read and review.

Answer (score 43):

The biggest quality problem I see in the site where I spend most time ([PPCG](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)) is the Hot Network Questions sidebar. It's set up to promote cheap questions which anyone can answer without thinking, and because it channels in people with association rep allowing upvotes but not downvotes it self-reinforces the promotion of those questions and gives all newcomers (those who arrive via HNQ and those who simply find the site and look at highly voted questions) the impression that that is the best type of question to ask.

There are various feature requests relating to reducing the promotion of poor quality questions via the HNQ. The two I would particularly like to see are:

- [Remove question from HNQ if it has close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272230/164922)
- [Allow mods or gold tag badge holders to prevent question from being on hot network questions list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284929/164922)

Another one which would help to mitigate the anti-quality effect of HNQ is:

- [Prevent questions on Hot List from being upvoted by casual visitors (only rep is from association bonus)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238420/164922)

Comment: Here's one less-extreme way to cut that feedback loop: [allow 'outsiders' to vote, but stop counting those votes as a signal for the HNQ algorithm](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286020/breaking-the-hnq-feedback-loop-on-bad-questions).

Comment: That cuts the HNQ feedback loop, but it doesn't cut the feedback loop which drags the site's culture towards questions which are optimised for the HNQ rather than the site.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: If clickbait can't stay in HNQ for very long, it's relatively less rewarding, and therefore requires more work to get the same abnormal boost… work which could probably be put to make the post better in a less unnatural way to improve HNQ *and* organic voting response. The result is that there is less reason to optimize for HNQ, because HNQ-only optimization doesn't work as well.

Comment: It may be that questions are more likely to accumulate close votes after getting on the HNQ list. When you increase a question's exposure, it becomes more likely that _someone_ seeing that question is going to think it's close-worthy. Removing a question from HNQ if it has close votes would have to take that into account.

Comment: What if instead of “hot” questions it listed “well answered” questions (has a highly upvoted answer, many views, and if it gets many more answers that pushes it _off_ the list)? That would still highlight interesting content of general interest.

Comment: @KevinReid, there may be some subtle problem with that which escapes me, but my initial reaction is that it's an excellent idea.

Comment: I use [Stack Overflow Extras (SOX)](http://stackapps.com/q/6091/10143) to hide the Hot Network Questions sidebar.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, I don't see the relevance of that comment.

Comment: @PeterTaylor hiding the sidebar may be a solution for people who do not like its content.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, but the problem that this answer is about is the content shown to *other people* and the consequences of that.

Answer (score 41):

As a "meta" quality improvement, it would be great if the existing quality requests on Meta.SE and Meta.SO got an update from the SO team so we know where things stand.  I understand that, in general, responding to each feature request is not an efficient use of time, but since there are relative few requests related to the quality project it might be more reasonable.  For example:

- [What should the system be deleting automatically that it already isn't?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262077/what-should-the-system-be-deleting-automatically-that-it-already-isnt) which put forward a lot of good ideas, but apparently no conclusion was reached.
- [Time for roomba to ignore comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333477/time-for-roomba-to-ignore-comments), which generated a lot of discussion and seemed to be received generally positively. I personally liked the idea of at least ignoring comments that happen within the first week.

Answer (score 37):

### For those few of us who are heavy voters…

That's a very small target demographic, but the requested changes are pretty minor.

[Bring back the indicator of the number of votes cast in the current quota period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239601/reliable-count-of-votes-that-ive-cast-today).

[Relax the voting quotas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276989/amortize-voting-limits-over-a-rolling-week). I shouldn't have to care that it's almost midnight and I need to get my voting done or else I'll run out every day until next week-end.

Comment: [Another pertaining feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238680/255554)

Comment: Maybe have a "pot" of votes, that have a max value of N, with 1 vote added to the pot every 1440/N minutes. (N being the current daily limit)  That way voting at the start or end of a "day" will make no difference to the number of votes you can use.

Comment: Pretty sure that indicator was added to *encourage folks to vote more*. Which... Is still a good idea.

Comment: @IanRingrose That would be a good answer for my feature request. I don't care exactly how it's done, what I care is that it doesn't make a difference whether I do my daily trawl around 23:30 or around 0:30.

Comment: @Shog9 Any idea why there's a voting cap in the first place? (I'm not an active enough user to have ever come close to hitting the cap, I expect, but I'm still curious.)

Comment: Someone got the bright idea of writing a script to up-vote everything on the site back in the private beta, @Kyle. Kinda made the need obvious.

Comment: It would also be nice if the voting cap was just a little higher - it doesn't even have to be a lot more, but a cap that was even ten votes higher would help a lot.  Especially if there's a lot of activity on some sites on some days, and there are lots of posts worth voting on - which shouldn't be a bad thing, but it can be annoying when I will be playing catch-up for a week or more because most days I use most of the votes anyway.

Answer (score 36):

Make it easier for people to remove bad and incorrect answers. Some possibilities for discussion:

1. Allow delete votes on positively scoring answers - obviously we need to scale the delete votes along the same lines as question delete votes are scaled so that it's next to impossible to delete something that's highly upvoted. If a bad answer that's got a couple of upvotes starts to attract delete votes then it might prompt the OP to fix it up, others to fix it up or add a new answer themselves. Obviously delete votes should age away, perhaps more rapidly if the post has been edited since the vote was cast.
2. Educate users more to remind them that they'll get their precious 1 point of rep back when the offending answer is deleted.
3. Make downvotes on answers free to the caster - or perhaps at least after a certain reputation level/length of time on the site.

   I think that this will have a big impact on quality, as I am sure many people are reluctant to hit that down arrow because of the -1.

   "What!" I hear you say, "people are reluctant to lose one point of reputation when they see something bad?!?!. That's just crazy". It may be crazy but I fear it's true, especially for low rep users who are struggling to reach the next privilege threshold.

   This results in:

   1. Poor quality answers being left on the system with no indication to say that they are poor quality.
   2. Users flagging for moderators to delete stuff because they can't do it themselves as the post is not negatively scoring.

   All-in-all not useful. A word of warning though - if down-votes are free it becomes easier for people to down-vote all the competing answers on a question. We'd need to have a way of spotting that and either preventing it (the -1 remains if you've answered the question, or add an answer later), reversing it automatically or flagging it up to the moderators.

If the community. properly peer reviewed, can do the cleanup there's less work for the janitors to do.

Comment: You think that in order to improve the quality of Stack Exchange we need less answers? I just don't see that being the case. The largest problem is with low quality questions, especially from certain subsets of the community, as explained elaborately in this post.

Comment: @TravisJ we need fewer low quality, or down-right wrong answers. We need people to believe that when they come to a Stack Exchange site they're getting good answers that provide correct information.

Comment: Perhaps for small traffic sites, but for the larger SE sites, users are getting good answers that provide correct information. If you were to look at metas across the network, there are basically no posts stating "answers need to be of higher quality" anywhere. Question quality, on the other hand.. those complaints are everywhere.

Comment: I would say that every post on Meta.SO about NAA flags is a post about answer quality, @TravisJ. And there are plenty of those.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - I think there is some truth to that, although users are also constantly confused with the flagging mechanism. Many of those NAA flag questions are "why was my flag declined".

Comment: @TravisJ - probably because they used a NAA flag instead of a down-vote.

Comment: I think there's too much potential to abuse a completely free downvote -- especially among inexperienced users.

Comment: @Glen_b there was concern that free down-votes on questions would lead to chaos, but that didn't happen.

Comment: @ChrisF I'm not forecasting chaos, just an unwelcome degree of abuse among a subset of users; e.g.  the temptation to downvote some or all the other answers - regardless of merit - when you post an answer may be quite high for a new user. There's no corresponding moral hazard with questions.

Comment: @Glen_b - you'd still need 125 rep to be able to down-vote, so you wouldn't be that new a user. Also I did raise that concern myself.

Comment: @ChrisF Well, *relatively* new. Some people break 125 their first day on site. Even after I hit the downvote level of reputation (a long time after my first day), I don't know that *I'd* have had the sense to know better before I'd been on site a good while longer. It was fortunate that the cost of a downvote was there. By the time I had enough reputation not to care that it costs reputation, I understood enough not to misuse it. Some people won't need that, but some will, and it's the ones that will who break things.

Comment: Many people (on the sites I frequent) refuse to downvote because they don't want to be mean. I don't know how to address this, but removing the -1 rep will certainly not do so.

Comment: somewhat related: [When there are many answers already, help me check that mine won't repeat others](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2562/168) (there would be less of bad / repetitive answers if system would help answerers check that)

Answer (score 36):

### Cater for other screen sizes

If you use the full site, then a lot of things require horizontal scrolling if your screen is less than the prescribed width, and [some things are simply placed off-screen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226291/improve-discoverability-of-comment-undeletion-for-moderators). I'm not sure what the prescribed width for ordinary users actually is; I know that my preferred width (which, guess what, depends which computer I'm using) usually isn't enough. For moderators, there's an indication of the presence of handled flags or deleted comments on a post in the left margin¹. It's provides information which otherwise can only be seen behind a lot of clicks and manual URL modifications. To see all moderator tools, a minimum of 1400 pixels is required (more on a site that gets more than a double-digit number of deleted comments on a post, down to 1361px if you don't mind seeing how many deleted comments are on a post). That gives a handy empty ~150px bar on the right for… um… why would you want to have an empty margin in a window? I don't know but I'm sure that studies show that 93% of users prefer more than 100px of empty margins in their windows. Or whatever.

Instead of [making it worse to fit more ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites/272574#272574), make it better. Remember, your money may come from advertisers, but your content comes from users. Without content, you wouldn't get advertising revenue in the first place.

If you use the mobile interface then a lot of functionality is missing. The apps are even worse (at least the Android app is [so buggy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219840/drafts-for-edits-get-lost-on-leaving-the-android-app/261516#261516) it isn't ready for prime time if you want to do more than read and vote).

This isn't the 1980s. This is the era of browsers using hundreds of megabytes to display a web page on a wide variety of different hardware. There's no excuse for designing for a particular screen width.

¹  <sub>Unless you move that with [ArtOfCode's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188628/can-we-make-the-post-issue-indicator-more-tolerant-of-window-size/272620#272620) [userscript](https://gist.github.com/ArtOfCode-/3c8684f3df3f8d777af4).</sub>

Comment: +1 : The Android app leaves a *lot* to be desired

Comment: The android app can't do half of what the mobile site can do.   I wish it would just give me notifications about responses and take me to the website.   Get out of my way, cripple!

Comment: Preferred width is at least 1060px, which is how wide the site content is.

Comment: @TylerH Is that what it is today? On my main PC *my* preferred width is 800px.

Comment: If the Android app offers less than the mobile version of SE, why is it still around? Wouldn't dev time be better spent on other things?

Comment: @Gilles Yes, the `<div class="content">` that contains the site's content column (including the sidebar on the right) is 1060px wide. Since 2010 this means roughly 80% or more of web users use monitors wide enough to cover all the content. Since January 2016 that number is ~94%

Comment: Yeah, I stopped using the Android app within...days, probably. The mobile-web version is tolerable.

Comment: @Zaid: The Android app is great for reading (Hot Network Questions is great entertainment for when I'm on the go). For answerting or asking questions... not so much. Posting comments is fine though.

Comment: I've noticed this too. I actually have to zoom out of the site to see all the relevant content on at least one of the devices I frequent SE on, in order to see everything.

Comment: @TylerH For moderators, it actually takes a minimum of 1361px, otherwise some of the tools are off-page.

Comment: Art's userscript is linked in an answer to http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188628/162102.  (For your future discoverability, you placed a bounty on it, as did I.)

Comment: The only thing I use the Android app for is getting notifications of inbox events.  I've never figured out how to do basic site-by-site navigation like I can do on the web.  That's...pretty basic.

Comment: I actually like the Android app, I use it daily when I'm not in front of a PC. Typing long answers, especially when code is involved, is a bit tedious, but manageable. But the main thing I *don't* like about the app is a lack of access to my favorite Tags.  I have to type them by hand in the search box to see filtered questions.

Answer (score 35):

#### Give moderators tools to engage the community

Moderators can not always be sure about whether a question fits site policy, especially if they are not experts in the area the question is about. Also, they may want to defer certain decision to the community, i.e. promote a more democratic approach to community moderation. In particular, they may have to "train" their users to use the tools they have as the site grows.

Currently, there is *no tool* to do this, short of opening a second account for casting regular votes: every action a moderator takes is immediate and binding.

I think moderators need tools to prompt regular users into action.

Related proposals:

- [Let moderators move posts to review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263562/let-moderators-move-posts-to-review-queues)
- [How to train your growing community to self-moderate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217494/how-to-train-your-growing-community-to-self-moderate)
- [Add a way for moderators to cast a normal, non binding close/open vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41062/add-a-way-for-moderators-to-cast-a-normal-non-binding-close-open-vote)

Comment: Overall, I think this fits into how moderators behave. I can't speak for every site, but the theory is that moderators are really exception handlers and not community leaders. I think that if you look at the majority of the sites in the network, you'll find that moderators tend to be among the higher reputation users and also subject matter experts who can use their knowledge and influence to help do more than just handle exceptions. I'd like to see more at giving moderators community growth tools, since they are trusted. However, there would need to be some level of monitoring over this.

Comment: @ThomasOwens 1) I don't know about others, but I myself consider myself an expert in some areas of CS but certainly not in all or even most of them. 2) Why would softer feature than we already have need more monitoring? Or have you other features in mind besides those I link?

Comment: I think your suggestions are a good start, for sure. But I think the whole role of moderator in engaging and developing the community should be looked at in more detail over a longer time. I don't think a moderator can be an expert in all the subject matter of a site (can anyone really be an expert in all of computer science or all of software engineering or all of programming?), but they do tend to be people who are involved in the subject matter and may be in positions to help grow the site more. There are lots of different features to look at in this direction as a long-term vision.

Comment: Functionality exists to allow developers to move posts to review queues (that's how we test). My first reaction to making that bit of UI available to moderators is "why didn't we do that yet?" - I'm going to take a look at it and make sure there's nothing horrible that could happen if we exposed it (when something that useful isn't exposed, there's very often a very subtle but important reason why not) and see about getting it done.

Comment: @TimPost Cool, thanks!

Comment: Would be great if the mod could also add a comment that is only visible in the review queue.

Comment: @IanRingrose I don't think I've ever felt the need to post a comment that only reviewers would be able to read. Our moderation decisions should be as transparent as possible, so let the users read it!

Comment: @Raphael, it could also be a comment you **want** the reviewers to read, when there are 101 other comments on the item.

Comment: That's a different issue with different possible implementations (highlight comments by mods and flags; special message for this purpose; clean up comments before sending to queue). Still, I don't think the comment has to be hidden from everybody.

Comment: That's what the site's primary chat room is good for. Use it to develop a healthy community.

Comment: @200_success Are you proposing to use chat as general-purpose review-"queue"? I don't think that's a good approach.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use chat to solicit opinions on how to handle problematic questions? Especially if the chat room subscribes to the questions feed, it's perfectly natural to "reply" to posts there. ("I'm going to close this one as off-topic— [second opinions, anyone?](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=second+opinion&room=8595)" "Can anyone figure out what this guy is asking?") As long as it's done with a respectful tone (no brigading or shaming), it's fine.

Comment: @200_success I could do that but it's a lot less democratic than moving it into a queue. I don't know about other sites, but we have far more reviewers than chatters. Also, I want to get *more* people into the queues, not fewer. I would say chat is a decent workaround, but not a replacement for being able to move stuff to review.

Comment: @TimPost Any news?

Answer (score 34):

### Crossover questions!

My pet popular-but-ignored feature request is ["Crossover Questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199989/218334).

I realize that this would probably be very, very far from trivial to implement, but there really is enough overlap between many of the SE sites that I think this would be pretty useful.

While I do **not** think that crossover-questions would *replace* question-migration (since some questions really are off topic on the original SE to which they're posted but on topic at a different one), I do think that since the question-migration feature is currently the only feature that provides some sort of cross-site per-question "sharing", the *lack* of the proposed crossover-question feature is probably not entirely unrelated to the fact that [the way we think about the purpose and motivation of question-migration is currently a hot topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285467/218334).

---

**NOTE:** The [top-voted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/219824/218334) on the linked meta-question fleshes out the proposal and is very worth reading. In particular, it discusses how questions will be **nominated** and **accetped** as crossover questions. It also discusses how voting, moderation, and so on should work.

Comment: [Similar request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258233/fix-se-for-interdisciplinary-questions-inter-site-posting-instead-of-close-repo).

Comment: It's common to have the same question on different sites, such as *Why does Kylo Ren wear a mask?* on both [Science Fiction & Fantasy](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/111174/13217) and [Movies](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/49826/12783). Crossover questions would be a nice way to merge the information instead of having it fragmented between two sites.

Comment: Sometimes the same *question* fits multiple sites but the *answers* will be different, so this proposal needs to account for that.  We sometimes see the same question on more than one of the religion sites, but answers that are appropriated on one would be offensive on another.  So SFF/Movies is at one end of the spectrum, religion sites at the other, and I don't have a good sense of the space in between.  Would the same SQL Q&A work on both SO and DBA?  The same webserver Q&A on both Webmasters and Server Fault?  How many workable site pairs are there?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Are you thinking of particular religious questions? I'd be interested in an example. I would think that the implicit grounding for religion SE questions is an assumed "What do adherents of religion X believe about..." even if that's not explicitly stated in every question. If so, then the questions actually *aren't* the same. For non-faith-based sites  I'm not sure why there would be any question about whether the same question is "really" the same or not; in fact, database and webserver questions seem like excellent crossover question topics.

Comment: @KyleStrand "What does X in (some book in the prophets) mean?" "Oh, that's about Jesus". Even with explicit religious scope we get those kinds of answers on Mi Yodeya at times from drive-by Christians & Muslims. If the question were somehow marked as multi-site it would be even worse. We don't make people phrase those questions as "according to $religion what does X mean" because the "according to $religion" part is implicit based on the site you asked on. I asked about databases and web servers because I don't know if those sites also have implicit scoping not obvious from outside.

Comment: @MonicaCellio One of the important aspects of the proposal in the top-voted answer on the linked meta question is that making a cross-site question would require the users at the *receiving* site(s) to nominate *and vote for* potential cross-site questions. As long as both sites are involved in the decision, I don't think it would be too easy to abuse.

Comment: @KyleStrand if all sites involved agree then that's different.  It still has challenges (different editorial norms, voting, comments, moderation...), but that would address the one I brought up here.  (Err, with that clarification, if you were to edit this I could remove my DV.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Thanks for your feedback! I've gone ahead and added a couple sentences mentioning that the top-rated answer addresses some of the complications with the proposal.

Comment: Would totally support that, since to many sites partially or even completely overlaps with others. Questions on SharePoint are mostly on-topic on StackOverflow, but the people there will get almost no recognition of their efforts due to the low traffic. Sites like Science&Fiction, Movie, Anime and Arqade have questions that would probably benefit from being cross-posted on multiple sites (a question about the plot of a game based on a sci-fi anime is on topic on at least three sites), and those are only some examples.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how this would improve the quality of SE content. Isn't this the very reason why migrations exists?

Comment: @Braiam I don't think so. Migration is for questions that explicitly *don't belong* on the original site. This proposal is for questions that *do* belong on multiple sites. Examples are given on the proposal itself, but here's another one: http://askubuntu.com/q/694031/236343

Comment: That's why I fail to see it. For me migration is for questions were they are best answered, and have a swat of users able to curate the content as it ages.

Comment: @Braiam I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to say. It sounds like you're saying that for every question, there is *exactly one* site where it is "best answered", and it also sounds like you're assuming that cross-site questions would somehow be un-curated. Am I understanding you correctly on either of these points? If so, I disagree that all questions are necessarily best-answered on a single site (based on the examples shown) and am not sure why you would assume that this proposal somehow limits the curation capabilities of the communities involved.

Comment: It's because there is actually one person that is able to provide the best answer, and it usually only hangs out in a single site, the site where they can use their knowledge at its fullest.

Comment: @Braiam I think I'm going to have to respectfully disagree. I don't see anything to support your observation, and my experience has clearly been different.

Comment: @KyleStrand the problem with going with just your experience is that you have too little data to go with. [Check Jon's recent post about migrations, migrations do work, despite Jon owns surprise.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285467/213575)

Comment: @Braiam I included that link in my answer; did you not notice? And I also stated in my answer that this proposal would **not** replace migration, because they're different features.

Comment: This could actually be implemented fairly easily. Have trusted users and moderators be able to mark two questions as being related, even if they are on different sites. Then just include a panel/block that lists possibly related questions. And this would be useful throughout the site, since sometimes one question is one use case, and another is another use case, but they are both similar enough to be related. Helps people find what they are looking for.

Answer (score 34):

### Give new users better guidance on how to *answer*

The Help Center on each site has guidance about [what to ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [what not to ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), but no obvious guidance about *what makes a good answer*.  (There's some tucked away in places people won't think to look, like the help about flags.  That doesn't count.)

On many sites the biggest new-user problem isn't bad *questions* but bad *answers*.  People see a question, see a textbox, and type their personal opinion into it, or tell a related story, or ask another question.  Yes, people will probably flag them and they'll go to the review queue, but that's later.  It would be better if we could get out in front of it.

We should develop a template "how to answer" topic for the Help Center and [allow sites to edit it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/178537/162102) for their own particular rules.  A new user (first answer? rep below a certain threshold?) should see this information when he starts to answer a question, along with the other guidance that's given.

Let's help newcomers meet answer guidelines from the outset, rather than finding out only later when the downvotes and comments start rolling in.

(By the way, while we're talking about the Help Center, please fix this: [Why is "what can I ask about here" not the first entry in the help center?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263685/why-is-what-can-i-ask-about-here-not-the-first-entry-in-the-help-center))

Comment: Related request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178377/218334

Comment: I would welcome this. On Language Learning SE, we created a meta post about [resources for researching language learning questions](http://meta.languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/440/800). But that only helps when you can point people to it *after* they have submitted a low-quality answer. People need guidance *before* submitting an answer, and it would be nice if sites could edit this guidance.

Answer (score 29):

Related [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request): [Could: "Possible duplicate of.." be given prominence for answering users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/352450/839601)

Since you seem to be so much concerned about improvement on what duplicates are suggested to the person asking, it looks natural to additionally invest some effort into helping those who *answer* possible duplicates instead of aiding to properly handle these (by closing or by opposing the closure if duplicate suggestion is wrong).

This is especially so because it is so much simpler and it takes so much less engineering effort to help resolve matters after possible duplicate is discovered compared to searching for it, [as proposed eg here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316638/839601):

> **showing a modal popup to the answerer if the question is voted / flagged as duplicate**.

With the link (or better yet, full text) of possible duplicate and a message like: *There is possible duplicate here, please make sure that you don't repeat already existing answers*.

> 

This would serve several goals:

> 

- For *responsible* answerers, such an explicit warning would help to make better informed decision, whether to abstain of answering or even support a duplicate with their own flag / vote, or do the opposite, that is answer and challenge duplicate suggestion if they believe it's wrong.

> 

- It will prevent complaints like "why am I downvoted, I simply didn't notice *possible duplicate* comment when answering".

> 

- The last but not the least, it will throttle [FGITW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/fastest-gun/info) shooters who will have to go through an additional screen before dumping their garbage into the question...

> 

Implementing such a feature needn't be effort consuming, at least in its simplest form: warning message text, link(s) to duplicate(s) and two buttons for user to pick either to proceed or abstain of answering...

> 

And it can be tested say, at MSO / MSE prior to making decision on whether to give it a go at main site.

---

Really, folks, you are going to go to such great lengths to educate askers about possible duplicates. But keeping the answerers oblivious about already discovered (!) duplicates [kind of spoils all these efforts](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/28720223#28720223):

> **dupe close without answers teaches user: "next time, search and research". Close with answer teaches, "No need to research, just dump your question and it will be chewed up to you like it was to 10,000 guys like you before"...**

Comment: Fix duplicate search first.  Fix all the existing "canonical duplicates" with shitty canonical answers second.  Only then worry about this.

Comment: @zwol you got to be kidding. Fix everything including most difficult and trickiest issues that may take years (review and rewrite all canonical answers, yeah sure) and _only after_ that do the thing that takes just a day or two of developer time to implement. Just so you know, even with current insufficient system median time to discover and vote / flag duplicate at SO is [mere 7 minutes](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/28709226#28709226), good enough to help against getting useless FGITW answers in almost half cases. Sounds like you are simply scared by proposed feature

Comment: For users with enough rep, the dialog should offer to vote-to-close.

Comment: @gnat I don't see any of the things you seem to be worried about as significant problems, not compared to the problems I mentioned.  Put another way, I don't see why the SE corp should bother spending _even a day or two_ of developer time on the feature you want.

Comment: @zwol agree compared to mine your problems are more significant. But it doesn't make sense to put addressing these as a precondition to address mine, particularly because addressing your might take years while mine is a matter of days

Comment: @zwol the way you suggest will have the effect opposite to what you claim. There will be no improvement - instead there will be (heck there _are_) hundreds mediocre twin answers posted to hundreds useless duplicate questions. There is no room to improve when one can not see and compare how others already answered the similar duplicate. Now compare that to the way I mean, when duplicates are closed timely and answerers attention is refocused to dupe target...

Comment: ...answerers will try to post to that dupe target and they will have to try do better than prior ones. That will be real, direct competition, a clear road to improvement

Answer (score 28):

The guidance for the "requires editing" button in the Triage queue currently states:

> for questions where edits by the author or others would result in a question that is clear and answerable

However, if a question requires information from the asker, the question should be closed.  "Requires editing" puts the question in the H&I queue, where editors are powerless to read the asker's mind.

My feature request is that you should strike "by the author" from this text.  (There have been other proposals on Meta Stack Overflow about rewording these messages that may have better all-around text.)

Previous proposals/complaints:

- [Adopt a consistent policy on what “Requires Editing” means in the review queues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332546/adopt-a-consistent-policy-on-what-requires-editing-means-in-the-review-queues)
- [Triage Review Queue - Inconsistent guidelines for “Requires Editing”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319128/triage-review-queue-inconsistent-guidelines-for-requires-editing)
- [Suggestion for rewording of triage review guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289738/suggestion-for-rewording-of-triage-review-guidance)
- [Change triage guidelines for “requires editing”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321895/change-triage-guidelines-for-requires-editing)
- [Wrong review: Requires Editing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327197/wrong-review-requires-editing)

---

In general, it would be nice to see triage and H&I evaluated before moving on to new things.  I'm surprised it wasn't mentioned at all in this meta question.

Comment: I'd not only want "by the author" removed... I'd want emphasis on "by others".

Comment: This is just a symptom of a much, much larger problem: it's too hard for folks who actually know enough to know when a question is lacking information to close them as such. Expecting arbitrary reviewers in Triage to know what information is required for a question in a tag they've never seen is... Extremely optimistic; they're likely to miss cases where such information is needed as often as they incorrectly hammer questions that are already sufficient. In fact, we've seen exactly that *every single time we've tried.* This sort of content moderation requires folks who know the topic.

Comment: @Shog9 then adding the *filter for triage is a must*, maybe with a combination of this http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254145/213575

Comment: I think more guidance for what to do as a triage reviewer and what happends with the questions after triage (lots of low rep users who vote in triage have never seen the subsequent queues) is a great idea. I suspect that I have cast hundreds of "wrong" triage votes just out of confusion.

Answer (score 26):

## Add cross-site links to the right-hand sidebar

As proposed in [Display other SE site links in the linked questions sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59569/display-other-se-site-links-in-the-linked-questions-sidebar).

The `Linked` section of the sidebar is an excellent tool for discovery. Over time we have seen the development of many smaller sites that would vaguely fall under the umbrella of an older, bigger site (like e.g. astro, space, scicomp, hsm and earth science taking up a fair bit of question space that might otherwise have ended up in physics), and one of the worries in this process is the fragmentation of question collections and of communities.

An excellent way to help avoid that is to make explicit those inter-site links where they exist: both highlighting off-site resources that are mentioned somewhere in a given thread and, more valuably, making it easier to discover off-site threads that comment or build upon the thread you're reading (i.e. linkbacks).

This is admittedly a relatively small population of questions, particularly if you insist on comparing apples and oranges by bringing up the total amount of questions on SO (as Jon Ericson does [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/246767)). That's a dud argument - the measure is the high value that the feature brings to the threads where it does appear.

Ideally, this should also be coupled with a better cross-site question discoverability mechanism (how about a similar `Related` sidebar pulling from closely-related SE sites?), but first things first.

I'm also aware that there are nontrivial scaling issues in implementing this network-wide, but I find it hard to believe that they cannot be optimized with suitable indexing. If you're looking for places to put new code that will bring the network closer together, this is a good place to do it.

Comment: [related discussion (in Russian)](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/3013/23044)

Comment: (Scicomp a part of physics? You can't be serious! Computing is part of *every* science by now!)

Comment: @Raphael The claim is (exclusively) that there exist questions that would have been asked on physics that are now asked on scicomp. It says nothing about the relation of scicomp with other sciences and sites (and indeed identical arguments apply to all the other listed sites).

Comment: I would dearly love this feature. Last time we tried to get it implemented, devs decided it was too much work... I still burn a candle.

Answer (score 26):

## Easier tag handling

Currently, the most effective way to edit tag names or to create tag synonyms is to flag for moderator attention. They have the diamond power™. However, there is one issue that could, in my humble opinion, be made a lot easier a lot quicker; and a second issue that could be simplified but may require thought.

### Allow renaming of a tag if it is only applied to one question

This is basically a rehash of this [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request): [A pox upon small sites: the thing that prevents you from creating plural or hyphenated versions of tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234309)

Consider a site like Anime where tags are essentially series’ names. A user wants to ask a (the first!) question about [soul-eater](/questions/tagged/soul-eater), but for some reason misses the hyphen key and creates the tag [souleater](/questions/tagged/souleater). If they had created anything else, similar but distinct from [soul-eater](/questions/tagged/soul-eater) (except [soul-eaters](/questions/tagged/soul-eaters), which would have the same issue) one could simply retag to the correct one; the wrong one would then be orphaned and deleted at 03:00 UTC. Unfortunately though, the system forbids creating a tag that differs only in hyphenation or a trailing s from an existing one. So we flag for mod attention, waste a moderators time for something that could easily have been handled by any user with edit and retag priviledges.

I propose the solution (not in the present feature request) of allowing renaming of tags, if they are only applied to one question or have been created within the last *x* hours — whichever is easier to implement software-side. It would allow the first editor to fix the problem immediately and not take up any diamond mod’s time.

### Do something about tag synonyms

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [Improving Tag Synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204244)

We all know the system isn’t working unless again you waste a diamond moderator’s time (see linked post). There are a number of issues mentioned in the post and some sound difficult to implement. Here’s a biased selection, not meant to be exclusive:

- make synonym suggestions more visible
- if a synonym is approved, make that automatically retag all questions associated with the now-synonym (i.e. like moderator merges)
- [increase the number of people who can suggest synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103211) — I mean, what are [generalists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/15/generalist) for, if not for this?
- Allow users with a score of *x* to suggest a synonym for an existing tag without having to apply that synonym to a question first.
- … open to further suggestions.

Comment: In the current system, some synonyms simply can't be approved without a mod because there aren't enough users who can approve them.  [Even a site as large as Stack Overflow has to work these out on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305388/lets-handle-doomed-tag-synonym-suggestions)  It'd be great to improve the process, but I think users proposing these synonyms should at least be warned they'll need meta/mod help.

Answer (score 24):

As far as I can tell about *15 millions views* at Stack Overflow are on inappropriate ([historically locked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/historical-lock/info)) questions.

<sub>(285 locked questions have [views between 10K and 100K](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=locked%3Ayes+views%3A10000..100000) plus 158 questions with [views between 100K and 1M](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=locked%3Ayes+views%3A100000..1000000) plus 3 questions with [views over 1M](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=locked%3Ayes+views%3A1000000))</sub>

Visual difference between historically locked and legitimate questions looks quite subtle to me, even though I have few years experience on the site. It can be even harder for inexperienced readers to tell the difference. This seems to create wide open [broken windows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-windows/info).

Due to high views historical questions tend to rank highly in web searches. Inexperienced visitors coming from searches may think that these questions are legitimate and try to ask similar ones.

Suggest to invest some effort into making it easier for new users to see that historical questions differ from regular ones.

---

- Related: [Use pink background when rendering historically locked posts](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7828/31260). (similar analysis at Software Engineering shows about 5M views at historically locked questions over there - meaning this issue isn't specific only to Stack Overflow)
- Also related: [Automatic visual indication of old questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98589/165773) - this request shows an interesting mockup for how historic questions could be rendered:
   
  [image: Aged image]
- Yet another approach worth considering was [proposed in comments below](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285889/lets-plan-the-second-iteration-of-the-stack-exchange-quality-project/285985#comment928140_285985) - grayout with [un-fade on hover](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129593/165773) like it is currently done on low-score answers:

  > <sup>It already exists, it makes it very visually obvious that something is funky with the post, and it still allows for good reading conditions with minor effort. Moreover, it would bring the **locked** banner to greater prominence on the page.</sup>

Comment: This locked questions are a very important information source on the internet so should not be made harder to read.

Comment: That mockup goes too far in making them difficult to read; if we want them to be unreadable, we should just delete them.  But I agree some sort of visual marker would help.

Comment: @IanRingrose there would be no need in anything like that at all if visitors of historical questions were redirected to some kind of an "outcast" / "museum" site that would be physically different and in particular wouldn't show them that big prominent "Ask Question" button (which kinda tells, "hey here's an example question you can ask over here (and expect thousands upvotes and millions views)"). Quite a pity that all requests for such a redirect were declined by SE team so far ([example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73226/165773))...

Comment: ...we are essentially forced to decide whether "harm to the Internet" - obscured text of historic question - outweighs the harm of it hanging in here and making a broken window for inexperienced users (who sometimes simply can't see / understand what historical lock means)

Comment: One such alternative is the grayout that's currently in use for score<-3 posts (which re-blackens the text on hover). It already exists, it makes it very visually obvious that something is funky with the post, and it still allows for good reading conditions with minor effort. Moreover, it would bring the `locked` banner to greater prominence on the page.

Comment: I prefer my solution, the lock wasn't meant for being a permanent state either.

Comment: @Braiam per my reading of the [respective FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126587/165773) permanent state is intended: "Historically locking a post ends the debate over whether a question should be kept on the site or deleted, and is often the final state of a question..." Wrt your solution, I've seen it and while I didn't vote it down, nor did I vote it up because it assumes too much effort on questions that aren't worth it (I understand that these are kept to avoid link rot but besides that I have no interest in doing anything on them)

Comment: Read who wrote it... Then read this http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/36966/213575. I'm on mobile but there are more.

Comment: @Braiam "post temporarily locked away" in [a/36966/213575](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/36966/213575) talks about different kinds of locks, not historical ones (off-topic comments, edit wars, content dispute etc)

Comment: It would likely help if the locked banner were at the top of the post rather than below it.

Comment: @TylerH I recall a feature request for that. If memory serves some skeptics in discussion over there expressed doubt that this would be of much help. If, on the other hand, the banner would be the only non-greyed piece in the question...

Comment: Jeez, I didn't even know this was here.  Don't post anything late in October if it relates to me.  I'm busy having muh spoopy time. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v4IC7qaNr7I

Comment: but you know it @Won't be implemented anyway, so why worry

Answer (score 23):

Give more power to the votes to close, etc. of silver tag badge holders.

The duplicate "hammer" for gold badge holders has worked very well, however we have a lot more silver tag badge holders than we do gold.

This could be one or more of:

- A close vote by a silver tag badge holders takes longer to time out.
- Close review queue put questions with a vote from silver tag badge holder higher up the queue.
- A close vote by a silver tag badge holders result is an automatic vote from community, so doubling the power.
- Two votes from silver tag badge holders is enough to close a question as a duplicate.

Comment: [Empowering tag-badge holders part II - let's look at silver?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240700/165773) -- is this discussion related?

Answer (score 22):

Ability to leave a time-limited comment that also mark another comment as obsolete after a time delay.

- Often someone comments on one of my post, I edit the post in response and leave them a comment to say I have done so.
- Both of these comments are of no interest to anyone else in the long term.
- Having to remember to go back and delete may comment and flag their as obsolete is a pain.
- If the other person agrees that their comment is now obsolete, it should be deleted **without the moderators having to look at it**.

**Result, fewer obsolete comments, and fewer flags for the moderators.**

Comment: Why a time limit? "Delete after read by @notified user" should be perfectly possible.

Comment: @Raphael, maybe hard to define "read"

Comment: The canonical interpretation would be "viewed on their screen" or maybe "clicked the notification". Of course we can't know if they *read* it unless we implement some kind of acknowledgement mechanism.

Comment: @Raphael, "clicked the notification" would work, but I think there should also be a timeout, so even if they never come back, the comment does not live forever.

Comment: "Clicked the notification" as long as that doesn't mean just "opened the inbox menu", for those times when you have more than one waiting.

Comment: You may like [this proposal of mine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252883/255554) going in a similar direction.

Answer (score 19):

#### Flagging Improvements will Help Moderators' Experiences

I find as a moderator that many users get confused about when they should flag and when they should down vote.   I see it go both ways.   I see spam that gets down voted (but not flagged).   I see questions flagged when a down vote would have been sufficient.

Any improvements to flagging should also include changes to down voting.  When somebody down votes, a box could pop up asking for a reason.   Clicking on some of those reasons could escalate the down vote to a flag.  There could also be an "other" field that would be automatically left as a comment.

Some reasons for flagging could just turn into a down vote.   Something like "there are inaccuracies" or "I disagree with this".

I'd also like users to able to flag posts to enter queues.   It would be nice to be able to flag questions that need to be edited for grammar, spelling, or formatting.   There are plenty of times where you may not be able to do that edit right then, but putting it in a list of things to get taken care of would make the site better.

Comment: I agree with a more general shift from "what do you want to do" over to "why do you want to do it" and I'm not sure why you're seeing downvotes because the problem pretty much is people don't know when to vote or when to flag. I think the sequence would be more natural if they left the flagging box, realizing that they should just vote instead (if they have that ability) while we gather more anon feedback from folks that don't have the ability to vote, but indicated that they clicked on flag because "this just annoys me" :)

Comment: I'll ask the same thing I ask every time the downvotes-on-spam thing comes up: What real, practical harm does it do?

Comment: @Undo None if you flag it. But if you don't flag it and just vote, then it delays the luncheon meat slaughter :) This is going to be tricky to fix from a UX perspective.

Comment: @TimPost Of course... but is the few seconds we delay that really worth throwing time and work at? I'd like to see stats on how often it's actually a measurable issue.

Comment: @TimPost The downvotes are probably because people are reading too quickly, seeing "When somebody down votes, a box could pop up asking for a reason", and thinking "Oh no, not the discussion about justifying downvotes again!". I, for one, must confess that I had done exactly that before noticing your comment :)

Comment: I didn't "read too quickly". I don't understand what relevance changes to flagging guidance has to improving the quality of the material on Stack Exchange.

Comment: @TimPost: I downvoted because it seems like it focuses mostly on "flag mechanics," rather than education.  Proper flagging is not a software problem, really.

Comment: @JoshCaswell It surfaces stuff where mods are _really_ needed much better, which helps them drill down into things that make a bigger difference. I can't tell you the nerd rage I had as a mod on SO declining "pls I need answer" as an "other" flag on SO, and it happened nearly 10 times a day. It's worse now.

Comment: Okay, that's a very good reason for looking at this, @TimPost, which I had completely missed. Thanks for explaining!

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's a UX problem, and a hard one at that. You have all of these options and it gets quite complicated remembering which one is appropriate in any given context (not for me or for you, but for many). So we're shooting for more education, without getting in the way of useful flags too much. I could see a downvote on a post that has been flagged as spam bringing up "Mmm, maybe flag too?" and giving the user the option to do that right there (for instance).

Comment: @TimPost Alright, I'll buy that.

Comment: I've edited my question to explain this a bit better. I'm sorry @Stephen, this was a good direction in which to think and my vagueness there didn't fill in some gaps that most people don't ever see :)

Comment: No problem, Tim.   Thanks for weighing in.

Comment: To be clear, we're not going to ask for a reason for downvoting, we're more looking at _is that really what you meant to do?_ based on data (flags, spam system score, etc) and present the other option for them to pick conveniently. And this is all in theory at this point.

Comment: @TimPost Could we remove "close" and "flag" in favor of a popup dialog that appears after a downvote? Along the lines of "Why did you downvote? ..."; it would then cast close votes or raise flags (is the distinction really all that meaningful?) according to the answers.

Comment: Even if we didn't use it to replace flags and close votes, asking downvoters to select (the category of) their reason to downvote would be *very* useful. 'You received 5 downvotes: 3x "factual errors" and 2x "bad form"' is a lot more useful than 'You received 5 downvotes'. Yes, downvoters should comment, but we *know* they often don't.

Comment: Also let a down voter comment with their user ID hidden from anyone with less then 5000 rep.

Answer (score 19):

## Multiple Entry Boxes

Right now, everyone enters their questions and answers into a single box, and we rely on all users to use understand what a good question should look like. For the legions of users who come here from Yahoo answers and other question sites, there is no clear indication that SE requires a little more from its users.

I think for users with less than 200 points, instead of a single text entry are for the question, there should be two:

1. The actual question
2. How the asker has already attempted to solve their own problem.

So for Mathematica SE, a users would see two boxes - one for the question, and one to enter code and describe how they have already attempted to solve their problem.

For History SE, the second box would required what a preliminary search has revealed.

Having a simple form like this will start their walk through asking a good question.

Comment: And do you propose requiring the user to enter at least 30 characters in *each* box? 15 in each?  If the use of the second box is mandatory, it will contribute to the "SE is too complicated/unfriendly" mentality (and possibly discourage and annoy users).  If it's not mandatory, then it will be ignored by the people who currently ignore all the other guidance they are offered.

Comment: People to lazy to read the guidlines won't know about initial research. A separate box, clearly labeled, won't be missed.

Comment: It wouldn't be hard to label the two boxes: *Tell us what you'd like to know:* and *Tell us what you found or worked out so far:*. People then know exactly what they're expected to provide - a question along with some context and prior effort. It also places those two things in obviously traceable areas, so especially on sites that deal with a lot of HWQ, potential answerers can scan quickly for where the asker so far reached.

Answer (score 19):

Another pet popular-but-not-implemented proposal: [opt-in notifications for specific posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803/218334).

**EDIT:** The original question asks about notifications for particular *questions*. I'd actually like separate opt-in notifications for *questions* and *answers*; a new answer would generate a notification for a *question*, but edits to that answer would *not* generate further notification unless the user requests notifications for that *answer*. This would be an important distinction on questions with lots of answers (such as this "Plan the Second Iteration" question!).

### Proposal stats

- 96 upvotes, 1 downvote
- Three duplicate proposals/questions, none of which has *any* downvotes:

  - [Please allow me to follow questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13546/218334) (28 upvotes)
  - [Is there a way to get notification on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118899/218334) (10 upvotes)
  - [Can I get notified of changes to a selected question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/51254/218334) (6 upvotes)
- A request for notifications on favorite *tags*: [Can I get notifications from my favourite tags into the SE inbox?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279312/218334) (7 upvotes)

### Teach the controversy!

This request seems potentially more controversial than [my other request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285912/218334), so I'll try to address potential criticism in Q&A format:

#### Q: How is this different from marking questions as "favorites"?

Note that all of my "duplicate" questions asked above are actually marked as duplicates of [the official "favorite questions" FAQ question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53585/218334). This is not completely ridiculous, especially since one of the OPs mentions that they're specifically looking for something to replace in-browser bookmarking.

#### A: The proposal is for new *notifications*.

Marking a question as a "favorite" simply puts it in a list somewhere. In order to see if a "favorite" question has been updated, the user must remember to periodically check *each and every favorited question* for updates. I just checked, and I have over three pages' worth of favorited questions across the network. There is essentially no chance that I will go back and check each of those periodically for updates.

Additionally, there are reasons to "favorite" questions even when the user doesn't care about updates to the question. For instance, I "favorite" questions that I find merely interesting or amusing, or which explain how to solve particular problems that I encounter periodically.

#### Q: Don't you already get all the notifications you need?

For comment discussions, we already have `@`-notifications and the auto-notification feature that kicks in when the OP write a comment and only one other user has commented.

#### A: No, the existing features really are insufficient.

- There was a recent meta-question (I can't find it at the moment, unfortunately) asking about whether we could add a feature to promote use of `@`-notifications among new users.
- `@`-notifications are limited to notifying a single user. If someone has already written a comment asking a question to which you'd like to know the answer, you'd have to ask the OP to `@`-notify you in a *separate* comment if and when they get around to answering the user who originally asked.
- Similar to the above point, sometimes users may be interested in conversations to which they haven't yet actually contributed.

#### Q: Won't this generate too much noise?

#### A: That's why it's *opt-in*.

...and, once you've subscribed to updates, you should be able to *unsubscribe*, too.

This is a model that's already been deployed (and is in my opinion a success) on Bugzilla, GitHub (you can subscribe to and unsubscribe from updates for individual issues or for an entire repository), and Facebook. I believe it's even implemented on Discourse, another Jeff Atwood Project™.

#### Q: But wait, those example sites are social networks! We don't want *more* social networking features here!

#### A: This functionality is *not* specific to social networking.

It's unclear that the particular subscribe/unsubscribe feature is specifically related to social networking. This is a simple but extremely useful tool for customizing the notification features that *already exist* on SE sites.

Additionally, as pointed out by NathanTuggy below, Bugzilla (which previously wasn't mentioned in the list above) implements fine-grained control of per-issue notifications, and it is in no way a social networking site.

### Random trivia

According to Jeff Atwood's answer on the linked proposal, this was actually implemented, then pulled, then replaced with the "favorites" feature.

Comment: This would, to a degree, mitigate the problem of downvotes that are never removed because the downvoter didn't know the post was improved.

Comment: A better example than GitHub might be Bugzilla, which allows all kinds of coarse- and fine-grained notifications for bugs or categories of bugs, and is in no possible sense any sort of social networking software.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Thanks for pointing that out! I've added it as an example and modified the last "A" section.

Comment: [Related feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279312). There’s also a related [other suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/286064)

Comment: @Jan Thanks for pointing that out! I've added it to the list.

Comment: This is even more important, as "favourites" are also marked as modified if the "community" bumped them to the current list of active questions.

Comment: @KyleStrand Just to reduce any confusion that may or may not occur: My proposal is about new questions in favourite *tags*, not any edits to favourite questions. But of course, a favourite tag can be loaded with new questions, too ;)

Comment: @Jan Definitely definitely definitely missed that word. It does bother me a bit that we've overloaded the meaning of "favorite" -- oh well. Thanks for clarifying! I'll make another edit. (I also didn't notice that that was *your proposal*.)

Comment: @KyleStrand It’s just that we love this network so much, everything is favourite, right? ;)

Answer (score 18):

I can describe my big desire, as a power user and an expert in some cross-site areas: discoverability and manageability of communities and questions, preferably without needing to be actually on the network at all times.

---

It's not a feature request, at least in its present form, but:

[The cross-site Filtered Questions on Stack Exchange are a bit awkward to use, making site and question discovery extremely difficult](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285230/the-cross-site-filtered-questions-on-stack-exchange-are-a-bit-awkward-to-use-ma)

It would be nice to have better discovery tools. There are a lot of sites in the network. Just looking at my professional interests, I can answer questions across over half a dozen sites.

This fits in with your filtering stuff that was mentioned in the question, but being able to put the right communities and the right questions in front of the experts is only beneficial. Ideally, you'd see higher quality answers to questions.

---

Something tangentially related to filtering and discovery:

[Additional RSS feeds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242989/additional-rss-feeds)

As long as you aren't as aggressive in blocking feed readers as Reddit is (my Reddit feeds in Feedly rarely get updated because Feedly hits the Reddit rate limits and Reddit refuses to increase their allocation), RSS feeds can lead to some interesting discovery, data analysis in a closer-to-real-time situation, and integrations with third party tools (using something like IFTTT or custom software).

Comment: Going to dig up numbers on how often feeds are used. I know they plummeted when Google killed reader, but if it's steady and not tiny, it's definitely worth looking at this, even perhaps expanding it.

Comment: @TimPost I don't use feeds now, and there are two reasons. First, it's hard to find the feeds that do exist. Second, as far as I'm aware, the feeds I want don't exist. I would be hesitant to base a decision only on the usage numbers. If people don't know that the current feeds exist or the right feeds don't exist, of course the usage will be low.

Comment: Good point, re: usage. I'm going to look into it.

Comment: @TimPost Thanks. Admittedly, I don't know how easy it is to implement various feeds. I think that ease of implementation vs what people can do if they choose to use them would probably be better. I've got some ideas of what I would do with IFTTT (automatic posting of questions and answers on various site to Twitter/LinkedIn, for example) as well as building applications around discovery and RSS feeds across the network.

Comment: I just discovered that *some* searches have their own RSS feeds (queries with only tags work) but others don't. Giving every search query it's own feed (essentially, that would mean providing a search API) might be interesting. For instance, I may be interested in `[favorite-tag] answers:0 score:1 closed:no` for discovering questions I may want to answer.

Comment: @Raphael: That kind of query actually worries me. That's what I would call a drive-by. It's meant to sus out the questions that are most likely to give you rep, not necessarily the ones that need an answer. The ability to filter that way would make we worry that many users' questions may never get good exposure if enough potential answerers utilized it.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Actually, this is a search I would make when I have some time to kill to discover unanswered questions that may be worth answering. In particular in beta, there is some incentive to keeping the percentage of answered questions high. I agree that rep farming can be a motive, but it's certainly not the only one. (And rep farming is only bad if you get upvotes on crap.)

Answer (score 18):

#### Enable the Triage Review Queue Everywhere

**and possibly improve it**.

As a moderator, these criteria make me edit questions the most often:

- Has only one tag.
- Does not have a top 5% (?) tag.
- Has tags that don't usually occur together.
- Has [new or rare tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148300/add-a-review-queue-for-new-and-for-rarely-used-tags).
- Has a tag from the (implicit) black list.
- Has title that is very similar to many other titles.
- Has no or very little Markdown.
- Is only one paragraph.
- Has MathJax in the title.

If there was a review queue with questions that fulfill any of these or similar criteria, that would not only help me find them but also enable others to help with the task(s).

When a reviewer views the question, the reasons for it being in the queue should be highlighted.

Comment: I could honestly see replacing "First Posts" with Triage on most sites. Having both of them is a waste of folks' time though.

Comment: @Shog9 Any movement on this? Asking for a [user](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1419/warn-when-some-tags-are-used/1420?noredirect=1#comment4511_1420).

Answer (score 18):

## Leave closed but change the close reason

Sometimes questions have been closed with a close reason (unclear, too broad, off-topic) which was correct at the time. Then, the OP edits the question. This now makes the former close reason obsolete but lets a different one kick in: for example, a question which used to be *unclear* is now *off-topic* because site-specific off-topic reason 2. Currently, the only thing possible is to either leave it as is, ask (/flag for) a mod nicely or attempt to reopen followed by reclose.

Instead, a functionality could be added to the reopen review queue along the lines of *leave closed; apply different close reason*. With a sensible majority of e.g. three people (which would kick the post from the queue anyway as is) the new reason would be applied.

If a closed question acquires both *leave closed* and *change reason* votes, let it go up to three identical votes. If the users cannot agree on a new close reason (e.g. two go for *too broad*, one for *off-topic reason 2*), wait for five close-type votes in total. If a majority of three hasn’t been reached, leave the reason as is.

I’ll admit that this is a not-so-often encountered feature, but in my opinion SE would benefit. It would be much clearer than commenting on a user’s comment ‘Why is my question still unclear?’

Answer (score 18):

[Give an incentive for finding duplicate questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37466/give-an-incentive-for-finding-duplicate-questions) and at the same time can we have a platinum badge for questions that get more than 500 upvotes:-)

> At present if you see a question that may be a duplicate and has an
>   easy answer you can post the answers or post a link to the duplicate
>   question. (Or the few hi-rep users can vote to close it as duplicate,
>   think of normal users here, not the people that read Meta)
>
> It is better for Stack Overflow if a link to the duplicate is posted
>   as a comment, or the user votes to close the question as a duplicate.
>   However, the user gets more rep if he/she posts the easy answer
>   quickly.

Comment: If we're going to reward rep for linking to SO Documentation, we should reward rep for closing as duplicate.

Answer (score 17):

### Improve searching operators by adding options to `sort`

Searching plays an important role in find posts, matching duplicates for closure votes, and possibly many more.

I enjoy the search operators that can be used to limit the scope of one's search. Perhaps one can add more of these:

- Be able to sort your search as part of the search query using (say) `sort:votes` (for a descending list of posts by their score).

  At the moment, this is a click away with any query. When trying to find duplicates that I know are highly voted, I have to search and then click the sort. A `sort:` operator would help here.
- Be able to reverse the sort order using (say) `sort:oldest` or `sort:-newest` to have a look at the oldest posts matching your query.

  At the moment, there is only one suggested order each of the tabs (newest, votes and active).

Comment: Can't you just navigate to the last page of a sorted search?

Comment: @NathanTuggy: There's an additional click (or two + scroll) to reach this sorted search (and then the last page).

Comment: Well, I mean, that's sad, but is saving two clicks and a keystroke on a somewhat unusual search option really worth implementing a new feature (set)?

Comment: @NathanTuggy: This is just a suggestion. Perhaps it's simple and saves a bunch of clicks. Perhaps it's not and won't be implemented because it's super difficult. I don't know, but my gut suggests the former.

Comment: It's a feature. So figure a couple hours to spec, a couple hours to implement, a few hours to test, a few hours to document, another few hours to handle regressions… and when all's said and done, it's just another search keyword that helps the few thousand users that even know about it to save a few seconds a few dozen times a year.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: Like *most* (if not *all*) feature requests here.

Answer (score 17):

#### Improve Searching

I know this is a can of worms, but let's face it: the search results usually ... disappoint. When I *really* need to find something, I use Google with `site:x.stackexchange.com`.

Part of this may be the "Relevance" sorting criterion. How does that work? Searching Meta I just got five-years-old posts that have [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) right at the top.

Comment: What about inline search by Google?

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek I don't know what you mean by that. Should SE use Google to drive their search? I don't know. The SE-specific parts of the query language *are* useful.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Maybe it would be good to let users choose the search method before searching, SE search would be the default.

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek Could work. I wonder if the two could be combined, or Google result presented through the SE stack.

Comment: Imagine the situation: Daily news: "Stackexchange combined forces with Google to make a new inline search engine!"

Comment: I just search `site:stackexchangedomain.com stuff I want to find`. Works way better.

Comment: The various SE sites are well positioned on google. Of course it doesn't feel right that the best way to find SE content is via an external resource, but personally I don't really know whether I consider this to be a priority issue. -- Semi serious note: if people can depend on finding stuff via google, they just have 1 to-go spot, also for things that are not properly covered on SE. Not sure if this is the best for SE, but it could be the best for the programmers of this world!

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Honestly, I'm not sure we can generally say that people can rely on Google. I know that *my* filter bubble is probably tuned heavily towards computer science and Stack Exchange, so *I* can use Google for finding stuff on [cs.SE]. I don't know if that's the case for everybody else, especially newcomers.

Answer (score 17):

### For sites with large review queues, automatically set the review filters based on the user's most "active" tag(s)

- ***I can't be humanly expected to review 1000+ posts on Stack Overflow***

  Yet that is the expectation conveyed to me whenever I glance at the top bar.
- ***I don't grok half the questions because I am not familiar with those technology stacks***

  So how can I be expected to make a call on what is enough information and what is too broad?
- ***Yes, there is a filter that can be manually set***

  But it is not obvious how to set this. And why should I have to set it when my site activity is captured as tag votes, question views, etc.?

---

I don't know what the right definition of "active" should be here. Here are some possible metrics:

- upvotes
- views on questions with those tags
- proportion of questions/answers in that tag compared to total questions/answers
- a combination of the above

Comment: Personally I think the filters should not be automatically set, but that the questions matching the filter should be sorted based on the skills and engagement the review has with each tag.

Comment: Perhaps there should be a filter to give meaningfull numbers in the top bar, but I would indeed agree that for the actual queue sorting would be more appropriate.

Comment: Maybe the review queue should not show any numbers….

Comment: Can we use a bit of machine learning, to build a model of the review tasks that a person is most likely not to skip, and show them these?     (Along with the tasks that are most likely to result in a outcome.)

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254145/213575

Comment: *"So how can I be expected to make a call on what is enough information and what is too broad?"* - you aren't. That's what the **Skip** button is for.

Answer (score 15):

[This suggestion is three years old](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185983/dont-choose-the-best-close-reason-allow-multiple-close-reasons). It currently has a net score of +17, is not tagged with [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)/[status-complete](/questions/tagged/status-complete), and only a single answer at net score +4. The latter even missed the entire point of the feature request, which is

#### Allow a single close-voter to give multiple reasons.

I have hit a dozen questions across several sites in the past week where multiple reasons applied. Some of them are straightforward: it was both *too broad* and *primarily opinion-based*. Others were a bit more complicated: either *reason X* applied, but if it didn't, then *reason Z* would logically have to apply, instead.

This is problematic in more than one way:

- if everybody votes closure for a single reason when two or more apply, and the first reason is inapplicable after editing, we now have a question closed on poor grounds, an asker confused or annoyed, and a dilemma for voters or moderators.
- close-voters have to pick the one reason. As an extreme example, someone may be unable to actually make that choice, and therefore doesn't pick either. I have not experienced the difficulty yet, but it has caused real (physical and mental) anguish.
- borderline cases get left unresolved, because each reason makes it hard to deal with others (it's hard to explain the way it is structured in my mind, but, imagine trying to see one tree in a forest without ever looking at others). Again, no close-vote.

There are several ways to implement this:

- each close-vote is a close-vote. Only the number matters; the reasons are a check box that select the information a close-vote wants to show to the asker.
- the close-vote gets divvied up. Pick two reasons and they each get a half-tick, three get a third, etc. If a reason no longer applies (other responses deal with changing the reason for a close-vote while it is still closed, due to edits) then reasons can be unticked, but the close-vote remains on the counter.
- ...?

Comment: I'd above all love to see _my_ voting reason shown, even if others voted for a different reason. (Especially when 2 or more others voted for "belongs on another site" when I voted "off-topic", "unclear" or "too broad" or "plain crap that should not be moved" if that would exist.)

Comment: Right now, if multiple close reasons are voted on, the final close displays only one reason, but shows all voter names on it, even if that is not the reason they voted on. The close should display all reasons voted on, but not necessary who voted for which particular reason.  Something more along the lines like "Closed X hours ago by Joe, Jane, Mike, etc for the following reason(s): - reason 1 - reason 2 - reason 3, etc"

Comment: @remylebeau all reasons for closure that receive two or more votes are shown. This doesn't often happen because one reason is very obvious and others are not, or because there are two equally applicable reasons and one is easier to click to, but where a question is e.g. vaguely mentioning something completely off-topic, it might get three votes for *unclear* and two votes for *blatantly off-topic*. I believe that suggestion has been made on another answer, it's related but separate from this one.

Answer (score 14):

**Give us notifications for *absolutely everything*, and then make the non-essential notes opt-out.**

Other responses have already pointed out a number of events that we receive zero notice of, despite the importance they have, to our work here.

But it's also been implied that some (especially higher-rep) users would be bombarded, and in any case, the individual might simply not want to hear about that event.

So, there are two requests here:

1. Give us notifications for everything. See previous responses for some examples of what this includes.
2. Let us make them go away, if we want to. I'll expand on this next.

---

That latter request can be fleshed out:

- when a person first receives a new type of notification, add a quick phrase to the notification box *saying that it is* the first such time, and pointing out a check box they can use to "mute" this type of notification. Either grandfather existing notifications or apply this rule "from now on" at implementation.
- add a link in the notification box which directs to a page describing the different notification types, and how to globally mute/unmute them when that is possible. This could even be on the same page. Make it a very obvious symbol and mode indicator - say, a red barred circle versus a green exclamation mark - right next to the name of the notification.
- make the muting question-specifiable. I don't want to hear about new answers on just that question, but I do need to know about other activity - bam, "mute answer notifications on this question" and I'm happy. Not interested in anything except closevotes or deletion - bam, "mute [everything else] on this question" and I can be on my merry, knowing I'll be told if that question might or has been removed.
- Subsequent to both of the above, separate the muting/unmuting for specific questions from the global toggle. I might normally block all the new comment notes, but want to keep track of a particular discussion for a couple of days, or change my standard preferences but keep the special mutes/unmutes applied. Possibly incorporate a "nuke" button as well, that removes all my current special mutes/unmutes.
- This kind of functionality already exists in the ability to block tags on a particular site, or even entire sites from the main page and sidebars. It enables us to get all the information we need at the time we need it, and also to ignore the information we don't need or want, and the change is as simple as a couple of clicks while we happen to be thinking about that thing already.

Comment: One relevant [tag:feature-request]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279312/312026

Comment: This would spam a lot of people unless they take action. The only acceptable way to implement this in my opinion would be with opt-in rather than opt-out.

Answer (score 14):

## Ban "Try this [code block]" answers

I am getting tired of those numerous posts (in my case on Stack Overflow, but I guess there are similar cases on other sites), that say:

> Try this
>
> ```
> [CODE BLOCK]
> ```

I know we can't make rules for each and every low quality post indicator, but in my opinion this one does need attention.

I propose to show a notification to the user that "Try this" answers are discouraged and should be accompanied by some explanation. Maybe we should subtract the code block character count, so "Try this" would fall out the 30 character limit enforcing a little explanation already.

Comment: Given that code does not work in comments, sometime there are few other options then a "Try this [code block]" when you think you may understand the users problem.    Hopefully the user responds and then the answer can be deleted or expanded.

Comment: "Try this" is never helpful. At least explain what has changed and how that fixes the issue at hand. After such answers, the user is still puzzled what he did wrong. He will ask the same question the next time since he didn't learn how to fix it. @IanRingrose

Comment: @IanRingrose: In situations where you need to post code, but aren't giving an answer, per se, you can use the community wiki feature. Just act as if you are posting an answer, and check the the community wiki check box before submitting. Community wikis do not grant rep, so you're not taking anything away from real answers.

Comment: Also include "Like this"...

Comment: @ChrisPratt community wiki isn't a excuse to give a poor answer. Either you properly answer the question or you don't.

Comment: @Braiam I didn't say it was. However, there's many situations where code or long prose may be beneficial to the user, even if it doesn't actually answer the question. That's a perfectly valid use of the community wiki feature.

Comment: @ChrisPratt again, it's not excuse for a poor answer, including "answers" that don't answer *the* question.

Answer (score 13):

### [Support for tables/tabulation in posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138946/137857)

I'm not particularly concerned about how this feature is implemented, but it is cumbersome as a user to have to reach out to a 3rd-party ASCII-table utility (like [this one](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/)) in order to convey one's message more clearly.

Answer (score 11):

### Help users understand that comments are not for answers

Across all sites on the network (though with varying frequency), inevitably, questions end up with "mini-answers" in the comments (even from high-rep users who should know better). Clearly, something isn't working here. Comments are for *comments* on the question (like asking for clarification), not for *answers*.

From my experience, here are the main types of question comments (ignoring spam and rude/offensive comments, as they aren't really relevant here):

1. **Asking for clarification/trying to help improve the question**: This is the main intended use for comments.
2. **References to other questions/answers**: These are very helpful - they populate the "Linked" section on the question with posts that are related (as determined by users, rather than the posts in the "Related" section that are chosen by the software). Often, the question asker or a potential answerer will see information on a linked post that helps them arrive at a solution.
3. **Giving a partial answer**: This is not a valid use of the comment system, nor is it a good answer. Incomplete, unhelpful answers are not welcome as answers or comments.
4. **Giving an answer that the commenter is not certain works**: In my opinion, this is not really different than giving a partial answer: it may or may not be useful to the question asker, and it certainly isn't of the quality that we expect from answers.
5. **Jokes and chatter**: While these sorts of comments can be well-received, they're not really what comments (in their current state) are meant for. In my opinion, chat is a better vehicle for discussion of questions (we have the "migrate to chat" button for a reason).

We need to emphasize that types 1 and 2 are the appropiate uses for comments, and other types should be made in chat (or not at all).

Comment: You may want to elaborate on the three main reasons for this: 1. helping the asker of an unsalvageable question; 2. giving an extremely partial answer; 3. giving a provisional answer the user is unsure of. (The last two partly overlap, and also partly overlap with legitimate troubleshooting advice intended to make the question more detailed.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy I agree with your suggestion. I wanted to add more elaboration, but I hadn't yet figured out how I wanted to elaborate.

Comment: We do enforce the [no-answering-as-comments rule](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1463/9357) on Code Review. A lot of it has to do with site culture and moderator activism. (The only people who can delete comments are the moderators and the poster.)

Comment: @200_success CR is the exception to the rule, then. On many sites across the network, moderators don't remove answers-as-comments, or worse, post their own answers-as-comments.

Comment: Often a "link only answer" solve the problem, but I don't have time to write a full answer.   Therefore I leave the link as a comment.

Comment: I do this a lot on SO, usually when I expect that a new questioner is about to get steamrolled by a hostile hivemind and I won't have time to write a proper answer before the post is closed.  Fix that first.

Comment: I also do this occasionally. I'm not sure how it harms the site.

Comment: @IanRingrose Then just don't answer or comment. It's not a race.

Comment: @KyleStrand You don't see the problem with blatantly disregarding the official policy on what comments are meant to be used for?

Comment: @Mego, it is about **helping** the person, even if you are not going to write an answer that will help google.

Comment: @IanRingrose You can help them (and yourself) more by writing a proper answer. If you don't, either someone else will answer, or you can write a full answer when you have time. Like I said before - it's not a race.

Comment: I tend to do this if I have a suspicion I have an answer, but either lack the time or interest to actually form it into a full answer, and know that posting that as an answer will end up with me pounded with downvotes. So I think @IanRingrose has something of a point. Fix the motivations for people doing this in the first place - or provide some alternative - which is easier said than done. It's telling you would rather have me say nothing than actually address the issue.

Comment: @IanRingrose re: "it is about helping the person" I disagree. SE is about forming constructive and useful Q/A. Helping individual/specific cases is not really the end goal. Digging thru comments to find answers does not help make this a good Q/A site.

Comment: @WilliamKappler I think you are over-inflating the role of the individual here. It doesn't matter *who* answers the question - just as long as it gets answered. If you aren't the one who answers first, it's not a big deal. Move on.

Answer (score 11):

### Open Stack Exchange to the other 80%

Something like 20% of the world population can read simple English. Stack Exchange should expand to the other 80%.

Yes, internationalization is hard. But Stack Exchange has been around for a long time. It's diversified away from being for English-speaking programmers writing about programming, to being for English-speaking programmers writing about diverse topics, and has opened up to English-speaking non-programmers. Now, very slowly, Stack Exchange is opening up to non-English-speaking programmers. Open up to the rest of the world!

6–8 years ago…

> [Our mission is to make the Internet a better place to get expert answers to your questions. Nothing about that mission says the questions have to be in English. It is our long term goal to make the Stack Exchange Network a great, planetary resource for all the world's citizens no matter what language they speak.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52331/is-it-ok-to-have-non-english-question-and-answers-in-area-51/53004#53004)

3–4 years ago…

> [ETA: still 6–8 arbitrary units of time.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82176/localization-the-state-of-the-nation/82229#82229)

A little over a year ago…

> [We're saying not yet.](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20988/internationalization-state-of-the-stack-se-2-0-sites-edition)

And still nothing coming outside of a few programming sites. [And no respect for the existing communities of the sites about languages)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261415/shouldnt-we-merge-russian-stackexchange-com-and-rus-stachexchange-com), which have all (at least the ones about non-extinct, non-artificial) been built by a small set of very persistent native speakers driven by the hope that the site would eventually open up to everyone, and not just the few who also happen to speak English well enough to participate on Stack Exchange.

In concrete terms, I'm only making some very cheap requests:

- Provide a user interface and the official documentation in all the languages of the existing sites (at the visitor's choice, of course). Cost: small, supporting a dozen languages isn't much more expensive than supporting 4.
- On each site, officially allow meta posts and chat in the site's language(s). Cost: 0.
- Allow proposals for non-English sites about topics other than programming on Area 51 (and allow them to go through if they reach the launch stage). “We can't allow T in L yet because we want to have an employee who speaks L” makes sense, “We won't allow T in L because T ≠ programming” doesn't. Cost: 0.

Comment: Main site stack overflow should always remain english only, as well as any but the specifically dedicated SE sites. If you're a programmer and don't speak at least fluent english, you're already doing it wrong.

Comment: @Magisch If you'd like to spew this xenophobic crap, please use the “downvote” button and refrain from commenting. Also remember that Stack Exchange is not only about programming.

Comment: I'm not a native english speaker myself, and that isn't xenophobic. Programming happens in english, and a strong command of the english language is the single most important soft skill for any programmer. What happens when you allow non english posts on for instance TWP or parenting or whatnot is that you mitigate the existing communities' ability to self govern - lots of people on there speak _only_ english. And if you feel that stuff like "parenting in japanese" could gain sufficient traction, I mean, no, probably not.

Comment: I understand this answer to propose that the SE UI should be available in other languages, not that we should post in Babelian ways. (cc @Magisch)

Comment: @Magisch Maybe you are not aware, but most sites on the SE network are not about programming.

Comment: @Raphael Maybe you're not aware, but most of these sites are still filled with programmers and I'd wager around 95% of network activity is on the trilogy sites, which are all for IT professionals or enthusiasts. They actually talked about this, that these other sides are meant to aggregate programmers with for instance also a passion for gardening, cooking, etc. So all in all Stack Exchange is by and large for and populated with programmers.

Comment: I just don't think SE really works for non-english communities. SE communities live by the cross-pollination from the big SE sites, and these are all filled with programmers, english speaking programmers to be precise. The self governance concept further makes it hard to permit expression in any language but the one spoken by all within any one community, since everybody is moderating and the people moderating need to be able to read the content.

Comment: I mean having other language UI wouldn't hurt anyone but it'd also be fairly useless, as the site contributions itself would still be strictly english-only, due to necessity. Does it actually help to have a say german or french ui when the content itself is in english still?

Comment: @Magisch Much of the content on [german.se] is in German. Much of the content on [french.se] is in French. Much of the content of [japanese.se] and all of the content of http://ja.stackoverflow.com/ is in Japanese. etc. There is no necessity that content on Stack Exchange should be in English only, it's just a limitation that was supposed to be lifted at some point.

Comment: Maybe some SE admin can shed some light on @Magisch theses. I for one think it's a narrowing point of view; there's no reason to believe the diverse spread of sites attracted *only* programmer types. As a matter of fact, there are probably very few on sites like [math.SE] and [cs.SE] (even though those all speak English for other reasons). Anyway, it's a self-fulfilling prophecy: as long as the platform is only available in English it will only attract people with command of the English language. Is there a particular reason for this platform-self-limitation?

Comment: @Raphael To give an example, among the 36 users on the top page of [french.se] by reputation, 18 have >2k rep on SO (serious hobbyists or professional programmers), 8 have 200–2000 rep on SO (occasional programmers) and 10 have <200 rep or no account (non-programmers who at most asked about tweaking a script once or something). All can at least understand written English (otherwise, they just wouldn't be there) and most can write English (again, the ones who can't tend not to be interested) but I know at least a couple have trouble with English even if they can cope with the basics.

Comment: Wow, that's probably a higher programmer ratio than on [cs.SE]. :D

Comment: Calling people Xenophobes... The new Godwin's Law.

Comment: I'm confused.  Do you want the current SE sites to start accepting non-English questions and answers?  Each SE site to automatically get other-language versions in each "supported" language?  Just translate the interface, but expect English Q&A?  Something else?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I want what Joel said in 2010: SE to open up to non-English sites (and not just about programming), and to provide a non-English interface to the sites where posts in other languages are already allowed (all the sites about languages other than English and other than [rus.se] are bilingual: English and the topical language). I don't want to have omnilingual sites, I don't think that can work.

Comment: You might want to add that last comment to your answer. As it stands, I can't understand what you're actually suggesting.

Comment: @terdon Correct me if I’m wrong, but I believe this comes down to: “If there's a monolingual non-English *XX*.so site with an **existing user interface** in language *XX*, make its UI optionally available on the corresponding bilingual *XX*.se language site so that the language site can attract more members whose facility with their own language exceeds their facility with English.” So for example make the Spanish UI from es.so an optional UI on es.se, the Portuguese UI from pt.so on pt.se, and so on and so forth for all paired *XX*.so and *XX*.se sites. This seems easy enough, and desirable.

Comment: @tchrist that does seem like a good idea. I just can't tell what Gilles is actually proposing here.

Comment: @terdon Here you go.

Comment: As far as I can tell, your "concrete proposals" section *still* doesn't clearly line up with what @tchrist is suggesting; upon reading it, I got the impression that you *do* want omnilingual sites. Also, re: "allow non-English sites about topics other than programming on Area 51" -- is that really not permitted at the moment?

Comment: @KyleStrand None of my requests even hints at having omnilingual sites, or even mention the language of any existing site in any way, so I wonder where you're getting this. Regarding non-programming non-English sites, [they've been forbidden since june 2015](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/20988/internationalization-state-of-the-stack-se-2-0-sites-edition).

Comment: Your first bullet indicates that the UI and docs should be multilingual. There's nothing about whether *posts* should be multilingual, or whether the docs should be multilingual *on a single site*, but that seems to be the implication since you said that the cost is low. Your second request appears to be saying that "meta posts" and "chat" should be omnilingual on a single site--I'm not sure how else that could be interpreted.

Comment: @KyleStrand My first request is explicitly for *user interface and official documentation*, so I still don't understand where you're getting *content* from. I've edited the second one, I thought it would be obvious that I wasn't requesting for Thai to be allowed on meta.jp.SO, but hopefully the current version should not allow such absurd interpretations.

Comment: Okay, the second request now makes sense, but isn't it already permitted? For instance, it looks like all the [meta posts](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/) and [chatting](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=es.stackoverflow.com) on Spanish SO is indeed in Spanish. (Unfortunately the names of auto-generated chat rooms appear to be in English; fixing *that* sounds like it might be a worthwhile request.)

Comment: @KyleStrand The “Stack Overflow in L” sites have always had meta in L, but with “L Language” there was a rule that meta had to always be in English (largely ignored, admittedly). Chat is still more problematic today: non-English chat is tolerated but is not really moderated properly (the chat moderators are the site moderators across all sites, so when there are issues with non-English rooms, they're usually handled by a moderator who doesn't know the language).

Comment: Okay, I think that resolves my questions, then. +1

Comment: "On each site, officially allow meta posts and chat in the site's language(s)." Do you mean, for example, that German meta/chat would be permitted on German Language but not on, say, Cooking?  How does a site get designated languages other than English, if you mean more than the language sites?

Comment: @KyleStrand re: "*Unfortunately the names of auto-generated chat rooms appear to be in English*"; [es.so] is still in beta and there's content pending translation, including help topics and several parts of the UI. It's a work in progress that will eventually become available in Spanish.

Comment: @MonicaCellio The “X Language” sites (where X ≠ English) are bilingual for content by community choice: you can ask and answer either in English or in X. This wasn't a Stack Exchange policy but AFAIK all sites came to the same conclusion. I expect most sites to be monolingual: only a few topics would warrant multiple languages (beyond sites about languages, perhaps topics like “Indian culture” and “Canadian law”, none of which currently exist).

Comment: Could you please expand this suggestion with examples of things that you want, and examples of things that you **don't** want? I read it twice already but like several commenters just am not clear what exactly you are suggesting. -- Also it seems that a significant part of the answer is focussed on the why, which is fine, but please indicate the what/how more clearly.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin See the part that starts with “In concrete terms…”, which I added after those comments. What kind of things that I don't want do you think I should add? I don't want omnilingual sites, but I really don't see where in my answer people are getting this idea. I don't want a pony either.

Comment: @Gilles I am getting this idea from "Provide a user interface and the official documentation in all the languages of the existing sites ", I guess this could use a reformulation or examples as I would not know what else it could mean. -- Unless you mean that there should be a user interface in language X, even though content in language X is not allowed on the site. -- Or do you perhaps mean that french SE should have a French and English UI, but not a German one? (and in this case, should one be able to ask questions in French?!)

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin “Provide a user interface and official documentation” means just that, it doesn't mean to allow *site content* in all those language. At least [french.se] should have a French UI in addition English UI. I don't see why you'd forbid a German UI on [french.se]: assuming the UI exists anyway (for [german.se]), why wouldn't the UI language be a global preference of the user? And you can ask questions in French on [french.se], this has been possible since day one. [french.se] is bilingual in terms of content (as are all the non-English language sites).

Comment: The idea that a knowledge model wouldn't work for non-English communities, or that a country/language specific parenting site etc. wouldn't _gain traction_ is ridiculous and offensive imho. Such an ethnocentric, top down and self-serving view stifles difference and is inconsiderate, and I especially commend the mission statement from the CEO (_Nothing about that mission says that questions have to be in English_) acknowledging linguistic diversity. Every such new site in a different language, such as the Cooking in French example provided by the CEO, is/would be a step in the right direction.

Comment: _Language is a primary vector for communicating information and knowledge, thus the opportunity to use one’s language on the Internet will determine the extent to which one can participate in emerging knowledge societies._ (UNESCO). Arguably the internet is no longer mainly in [English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Languages_used_on_the_Internet) and growth rate as opposed to raw site count shows strong expansion with many languages in the first decade of the millennium. Further analysis is required. Linguistic diversity is a given. Why some would cast votes against enabling this baffles me.

Comment: And for those not familiar with _Japanese parenting_, might I suggest this [video](http://nettv.gov-online.go.jp/eng/prg/prg2654.html) (around 18:30) showing Her Majesty the Empress of Japan singing a lullaby to some [Canadian children](http://www.sickkids.ca/AboutSickKids/Newsroom/Past-News/2009/japan-emperor-visit.html) in a hospital. That should elevate one's thinking, I would hope. Please note I am not Japanese nor do I speak the language. But very keen on acknowledging beauty and humanity through diversity. Thank you.

Comment: Late, hopeful addition: Perhaps if the French Language Stack Exchange interface were or could be in French, then [a French speaker might have realized s/he could speak French on a forum about French](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/28238/how-to-help-a-friend-to-learn-french). (This is one example of something that happens often.)

Answer (score 11):

**Help prevent new users from asking questions as answers**

The number of times new users think SE is like a forum and post a question as an answer is upsetting.

Can a simple parser look for a '?' in their answer and say something like 'If you have a question, please use the new question link!!!'.

In fact, I'd recommend this just if it's their first answer, regardless of the existence of a '?' in the text...

Comment: This is pretty well covered by [Bhargav Rao's existing answer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285924/159251). Also see [one of Monica Cellio's](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285942/159251) and [HDE's](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285918/159251).

Comment: If that is added it should be site-specific. Consider e.g. Code Review: it should be common for a good answer to include questions to the OP, because a significant part of code review is asking the author to justify decisions whose justification isn't adequately given.

Answer (score 11):

### We need a clear, defined process by which we can request the ability to embed YouTube videos on a SE site

We've been requesting this for eons on Mechanics.SE (questions related to strange sounds, part identification, etc.), written [meta.mechanics.SE](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1449/675) posts about it, discussed it with Jon Ericson in chat and nothing ever seems to happen.

Comment: Not only Youtube embedding but *any* site-specific feature

Comment: But your site is not even big enough to be a rounding error compared to Stackoverflow.

Comment: @IanRingrose it's about quality, not quantity :)

Comment: I can imagine videos being useful on Arqade as well... but I'd prefer not to see Stack Overflow questions containing videos of code.  So this really needs a site-specific system, not just turned on globally.

Comment: FWIW, Arqade already has this, @JeffreyBosboom

Comment: We're a *little bit* reluctant to turn this on willy-nilly, based on years of experience with forums where answers that contain videos often contain zero additional information... and thus are useless if the video is taken down for some reason. That said, I do see the value; if y'all are dedicated to policing "video-only posts", this is trivial to enable.

Comment: @Shog9 That is such a reasonable position. The meta-meta question, though, is: why is there no record of the SE staff response on the feature request? The lack of feedback or transparency means that the feature-request process is broken.

Comment: I guess I overlooked it, @200_success

Comment: @Shog9 your concern is also applicable to link-only answers, and Mechanics does a fairly good job of policing those.

Comment: And @200_success is on the money; the primary concern I wanted to highlight in this post was the perceived absence of process to request this feature.

Answer (score 10):

**Improvements to tags:**

Allow tags to be marked as “obsolete” along with a message explaining why.

- An “obsolete” tag will not be allowed to be used on a new question, or added to the question that does not already have the tag.
- The removal of an obsolete tag from a question would not show the question on the front page.
- The person that asked the question will get an inbox request to remove the tag from their question.
- Maybe marking a tag as “obsolete” with a moderator-only power.
- This would make the process of removing tags less painful.

Allow a tag to require that one of a set of related tag is also used.

- For example, when SQL is used, we could require that a tag is used to say what data vendor is being used.
- A [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) is another example, when it has to know the version of the regular expression engine to write a useful answer.

Comment: Which problem does that solve? We already can delete tags without bumping any questions.

Comment: @Raphael The problem is when it takes some time to retag all the questions, but while doing so the old tag is still being used on new questions.    Common when the old tag is not clear, so the retagging has to choose between a few different options.

Comment: If there's a canonical retag, SE devs can do it for you (without bumps). Or a synonym may do it. In cases as you mention, wouldn't blacklisting work?

Comment: @Raphael, blacklisting seem to never be allowed in real life for some reason.   There are retags on Stackoverlow that takes many weeks due to the number of questions that need cleaning up as part of the process, on other site I expect there is no issue.

Comment: My problem with most tag cleanups is that they tend to be... Really hit & miss as far as finding actual problems. Folks love to fixate on tags *they personally don't see a use for*, which tends to cause a lot of collateral damage; meanwhile, synonyms and merging (which are already accessible to privileged users and moderators respectively) are often neglected. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239189/how-should-we-make-tag-blacklist-requests/239192#239192

Comment: Either suitably-privileged users should be able to deprecate a tag (and have the system enforce this), or we should stop adding "DO NOT USE" to tag excerpts and just let people tag as they will.

Answer (score 10):

Can the tag suggestions get some love? Specifically, when the system suggest tags it should offer JIT help what the tag is about, probably [show the excerpt below the tag.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256114/213575)

Answer (score 9):

## **We need to make the migration feature more robust and intelligent for users and moderators**

I don't think there is a topic more discussed on SE than this topic. A basic search for questions about migration lie in the 4,000 questions asked range. To me this indicates that the current way of handling migrations is insufficient and should be addressed and not simply rationalized away. Due to the length and amount of arguments in the community I will simply list a few posts for example, and then a proposed solution. I am posting this not so much for my idea to be used over others but that we can actually make a step forward in this area. I feel like the justifications to date are "its too much work", and instead we should be making at a minimum smalls feature steps to test if any of the ideas proposed to date would be beneficial to the community at large.

There are currently some open feature discussions on SO and SE on this [Flagging migration should include more options](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251652/flagging-migration-should-include-more-options) and [This question may belong to `<Another site>`, consider migrating](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12570/this-question-may-belong-to-another-site-consider-migrating) and [Propose Close -> Migration](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265535/propose-close-migration-options-based-on-tags), as well as some that were rejected such as [Migrate based on tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68022/migrate-shortlist-based-on-tags) and [More options when flagging for migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration), but I don't think that the answers have been satisfactory given that the question keeps arising.

I think that we could potentially solve this issue by having a few criteria work together in concert. I propose using the current migration stats like SE already does, use the question tags to make more relevant suggestions, use the flaggers criteria such as reputation (in both SE sites) to expand their list options as well as if the flagger has recieved tag badges (arguably subject experts) to make this system more robust and intelligent for the community as a whole.

In many of the posts the argument is that community members of one community will not know the scope of the recieving community; or more generically that experts are few and limited and would not be best able to judge the correct action. I think this is a short sighted argument. This means the only option is to go to a moderator. To me this burdens a moderator both in time and in needing to confirm the destination community. In addition a queue would be adding to the slew of already exisiting cleanup the community endures (although such questions already go to a queue with some other flag applied in some cases such as deletion).

Proposel:

1. We leave the current commonly migrated based list as it is for those in the community below a certain rep level, such as new users.
2. If you have a tag badge (meaning you are an expert in the topic) and/or sufficient rep level in both the current community as well as the (proposed) destination SE community, then your list includes those sites as options for migration in addition to the ones based on migration stats. This would handle the situation of community scope, because the user knows the scope of both sites due to rep level that they have in both communities.
3. Over time we will see stat trends in tag groupings and can make the system wieghted to list the most likely migration at the top of the list based on historical stats. *This is different than todays stats which is an after the fact aggregation.* A great example of this is Android or Wordpress which have full communities on these topics.
4. After 3 or 5 flags applied(?) to a question by the experts defined in #2, the question gets migrated automatically **OR** to prevent all out anarchy, it goes into a queue on the recieving site for that community to make the decision to accept or reject the question. Although I would not want another queue, it would arguably remove this decision from the mods and at least allow **BOTH** communities to benefit in a sense that the FROM community can boot a question and the TO community can benefit and expand its question and knowledge base.

I know this might not cover any technical hurdles with the current system, but once again I think it's important to take one or two of the proposed options and make headway because this is clearly a painful item in the community that isn't going away and just keeps getting rejected based on opinions of difficulty to implement.

Comment: Further reading: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285467/a-proposed-philosophy-of-question-migration

Answer (score 8):

**Order answers by most votes instead of accepted answers**

A good percentage of answers I end up using are not the accepted answer.

But I see a strong correlation between upvotes for an answer and the its usefulness.

Would be great to see the most upvoted ones on top. In most cases, those are the ones that have been used by others and have helped others, so it makes sense to sort answers this way.

Comment: Quite often the accepted answer happened to be the first, or just tells the asker what they wanted to hear instead of facts they needed to, or is simply not as good (I've seen some that fit into two or even all three groups). "Accepted" only means one person in particular thought it was useful, and they already have an upvote to give, too. This is an easy but sensible suggestion.

Comment: Basically, this is [tag:status-bydesign].

Comment: Perhaps. But it's all kinds of wrongness. If the question is here for all of us and those who come afterward, as is often claimed and a fuss made over, the best answer as determined by the community will rise up - it doesn't need acceptance for that. And if the best answer is not the one accepted - because that happens often enough now - then the entire idea of an accepted answer is not worth keeping.

Comment: So I think its a question of "does Stackoverflow want to bubble up useful , but possible less relevant answers. Or does Stackoverflow say, "The guy who asks the question should determine which is the best answer". Also there's a risk of people voting up stuff just to make an answer popular, so not sure how that would play out.

Comment: How is that risk not already present? 319k questions on Math SE do not have an accepted answer, compared to 359k that do. People can upvote in order to move it higher on the page already - and that's actually the entire point of upvoting and answer ordering. If there was suspicion of someone doing it just to have their answer higher up, there's algorithm to catch sockpuppetry and to catch abnormal voting, and moderation to stop people being egotistical halfwits.

Comment: @Jan http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285938/279306 Kinda plays into this one then, doesn't it?

Comment: I often see mediocre first answers gather a few votes and then see a better answer being posted and getting accepted (with fewer votes). Thus I would suggest something like 'order by votes, where the accept mark counts for 3~5 votes'. -- A less intuitive alternative could be to only look at votes after an answer has most recently been accepted.

Answer (score 7):

#### Make close votes on own questions binding, even for under-3k users.

A under-3k user can freely edit his question. He can see close and reopen votes on his question. His delete votes on his own question is binding - the question is deleted right away. So why aren't close votes to his own questions binding, insta-closing? I had this problem when I found out that my question is a dupe, but though I (an under-3k user) voted to close as duplicate, the question did not get closed.

Comment: For dupes specifically, this isn't actually a problem. Just vote to close, reload the page, and click the This Answered My Question button in the dupe banner at the top of the question, and it will (using the existing binding confirmation mechanism) automatically finish closing the question as a duplicate. It's only other close reasons that are limited this way.

Comment: Which [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285951/307988) would solve.

Comment: Aha, *"reload the page"*, @Nathan, I would never have thought about that... But I guess the banner could be shown right after voting.

Answer (score 4):

### A better system for determining policy on a case-by-case basis

The close-vote system works well as a tool for implementing policy, but on many sites it has also been co-opted as a democratic system for *determining* policy. This happens either as a matter of local site policy or as the *de facto* result of having relatively hands-off moderators or a general lack of an active meta community. In either case, the result is that when there is uncertainty about whether a question is on-topic or not the community responds by waiting to see if it gets closed or not, possibly going through several cycles of closing and re-opening the question by different groups of people.

The problem is that this amounts to closing questions if

```
(votes in favour - votes against) % 10 >= 5.
```

There are a number of problems that stem from this.

- In principle, for a very large community where many people participate in the review queues, this amounts to a rather inefficient random number generator.
- In practice, for most communities, most questions don't get through to a single reopen cycle, so this amounts to a very strong "if in doubt, close it" policy.
- If the community has 5 or more active users who dislike a particular sub-topic it becomes impossible to ask questions about that topic, regardless of what the rest of the community thinks or of the question's quality. This is a real problem for the larger science communities, in my opinion.
- As a result of the above points, site policies can become much narrower than they need to be, eventually catering only to a subset of the community they were set up to serve.
- Since policies determined this way are not written down anywhere it's impossible for a new user to know whether their question is on topic or not.

I should stress that these points are *not* about wanting to leave open questions that are low quality or clearly off topic. They are about those few rare gems from new users that are well constructed and would be of value, but whose style or topic is unusual for that particular community, so that there isn't a clearly defined policy for that kind of question.

The root of these problems is that the close vote system has taken on two roles:

(i) quickly closing questions about which there is no real question; and

(ii) deciding whether to close questions about which there *is* a question.

It works well for the former but very sub-optimally for the latter. If these tasks could be more appropriately divided, with a new system taking over task (ii), it might be possible to solve these issues.

Comment: What form would this new system take?  There's no shortage of ideas, but you haven't really offered any solutions here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't know - I would offer a solution if I had a good one, but in the absence of that I thought it would be important to draw attention to the issue and let the gurus at Stack Exchange ponder it.

Comment: Quite honestly, I think the easiest way to solve this would be to remove *voting* to close entirely for all but the most popular questions. For your average... Let's say -∞ to 5 score question... it would remain open as long as there is one more privileged person interested in it than there are folks who dislike it; only once it'd managed to gain some serious traction would folks have to *vote* to close or reopen it. Vote-to-close was an expedient solution for a time when there were no limits on how often you could vote and folks were fixated on popular fluff...

Comment: @Shog9 So what do you propose in the stead of voting to close to prevent answers to bad questions? Atm we're closing too few, not too many questions already.

Comment: Just let everyone with some amount of rep close or reopen at will for new / ignored questions, @magisch. That's how it started; would've worked fine if we hadn't gotten into close wars over popular nuisances.

Comment: @Shog9 And what would "some amount of rep" be to you? 10.000? 20.000? 50.000? It would have to be in that ballbark, and then suddenly you have a lot less people able to close anything. I think it's still a bit naive to only dish privileges out by rep/participation on main. It can be the basis of that, ok. But the more powerful actions should require a track record of being able to use the tools correctly.

Comment: The current threshold is 3k, @magisch... Which was pretty arbitrary, but necessary to bootstrap. We have 8 years of data now... Analyze it and pick a threshold that works. Ideally, adjust based on the tags a question is in.

Answer (score 3):

Raise an automatic flag when a question posted by a user banned at Stack Overflow enters the close queue at another site, so that moderators at that site could quicker close and delete off-topic coding / debugging questions.

Stop wasting community time and efforts on the problems that were already discovered and handled at Stack Overflow.

---

A bit of the history for those interested in details...

Abusing a system by trying to circumvent a block by posting the question to some other site is a long known popular trick. Five years ago, the Stack Exchange team even had to add a special system feature to address this, so that such questions can't migrate to the site where user is blocked.

The approach picked back then was not quite fair: although it protected Stack Overflow from getting back questions from already banned users, this was done at the expense of other sites where users had to waste efforts reviewing and closing inappropriate questions only to find out that migration is blocked.

Back then it hardly was a problem because not many users did that. I myself was a regular at a site that had been getting some of such questions and I remember how these were rather infrequent so it didn't really matter that we spent some effort on handling these.

Things changed after quality project features started rolling out at Stack Overflow. More users started bumping into the blocks, and it became harder for blocked users to retry attempts to ask over there with new accounts, etc. As a result, more of them started trying their luck at other sites and wasting effort of these sites regulars.

Related:

- [Block migration if user is suspended/question-blocked at destination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102293/165773)
- [Stats on how attempts to circumvent Stack Overflow question blocks impact other sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237534/165773) 
  <sup>Stats over there are probably obsolete because these ware taken before quality project took off at Stack Overflow. More recent (and more scary) stats for one of the listed sites can be found [here](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6592/31260).</sup>
- [Perform automatic checks for... question block at SO when post enters close queue, not only at attempt to migrate](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6795/31260)
- [Let's help askers who are trying to circumvent question block at Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7020/31260)
  <sup>Complementary / alternative approach that focuses only on improving new users experience by helping them avoid frustration if they get down and close votes, angry comments, blocked migrations and question block at new site when trying to work around SO ban.</sup>

Comment: There's one other advantage to the system you lament: it knows which site it has to run on. IOW, the system doesn't have to query up to 160 sites to determine if a block applies; it only has to ask one (and it doesn't even have to do *that* until right before the post would be created at the destination).

Comment: @Shog9 I assume that blocks at sites other than SO don't matter (if you can counter this guess with stats I would be more than happy to learn). That is, there is only one site system has to run on, not 160 (and that site is SO). Questions enters close queue => system checks if asker is blocked at Stack Overflow, simple as that

Comment: That check is completely irrelevant on the vast majority of sites, @gnat.

Comment: @Shog9 anything could prevent disabling such a check at sites where it is not relevant? or could there be problem collecting stats to find at which sites it is relevant?

Comment: "I assume that blocks at sites other than SO don't matter" -- why? On [cs.SE], a block on [math.SE] or [cstheory.SE] is *highly* relevant.

Comment: @Raphael "if you can counter this guess with stats I would be more than happy to learn" (to avoid misunderstanding, "you" in this sentence means SE employees because only they have access to details needed for such stats)

Comment: I'm sure myself and bluefeet have both tried to dig up statistics on this in the past, @gnat: even for *related* sites (SO->programmers, SO->MSO), cross-posting is not as common as you would expect; performing a rather expensive cross-site check in response to a *flag* on, say, Mathematics would no doubt catch a few instances of abuse, but... At great cost and for relatively little benefit. Note that it's extremely difficult to determine whether a given user was blocked *at a specific point in time* unless that time happens to coincide with one where they were trying to post.

Comment: @Shog9 why do you focus on cross-posting, here I ask only about question blocks: "Raise automatic flag when a question posted by a user banned at Stack Overflow enters close queue at other site"

Comment: Because I assume cross-posting is all you're really concerned about, @gnat. If you honestly want to penalize folks posting about their turkey on Seasoned Advice because they happen to be blocked from asking about PHP on SO, then... I gotta ask *why?*

Comment: @Shog9 your assumption is wrong because I am concerned about off-topic posts from users blocked at SO. And your example of Seasoned Advice is misleading because it lacks key ingredient (turkey lacks apples). Question must be not just posted but flagged/voted as off-topic: "when a question... enters close queue". Unless some _real_ user have read the question and decided that it is off-topic, system should not do anything. Your idea that it is about penalizing users posting on-topic questions seems to be caused by some misreading of what I wrote

Comment: So you're trying to identify problematic posts that... Someone has already identified as problematic. Eh, @gnat? I gotta be honest; I'd trust the average 15-rep user on most sites more than I'd trust an automated system when it comes to identifying bad posts.

Comment: right @Shog9 - first a user with 15+ rep says "I think this post is bad fit here" and only after that system does additional check

Comment: So what does the additional check accomplish then, @gnat?

Comment: @Shog9 just what is written in my post - notifies moderators at that site to "quicker close and delete off-topic coding / debugging questions"

Comment: Why? These are a minority of questions on every site where they appear; what makes them worth more attention than *every other bad post* on these sites, @gnat?

Comment: @Shog9 I explained why in the post: "Stop wasting community time and efforts on the problems that were already discovered and handled at Stack Overflow"

Comment: ...I know you won't do it - it is easy to tell because every question you ask in comments suggests that you didn't even bother to read the proposal, even though it is two simple sentences in two paragraphs. I don't know why you won't do it and I don't care. Nor am I going to push for it because I am not interested in being a lonely warrior. I only posted it here to have a documented thing that it was brought to the attention of SE team and community at the place I consider most appropriate for that

Comment: To put this in perspective, @gnat: no site on the network gets more questions from users blocked on SO than http://ru.stackoverflow.com... which gets something like 3 per day. That's a hair over 1% of all questions posted there, **and it includes questions that actually do well**. You say you're not interested in being a "lonely warrior", but you've been pushing this line for *years* - based, near as I can tell, mostly on your experience dealing with sites that get a disproportionate amount of traffic from SO vs. from google or other search engines. IOW... you mistake a symptom for a cause.

Comment: So you want us to "stop wasting the time of moderators" by implementing this, presupposing it'll catch some vast amount of badness being shoveled at some site by SO... But realistically, we're talking maybe 2 questions a day. This is only a vast amount of badness on a site that is on death's door, a site that is ripe for a mercy-killing rather than further investment in life-support development. Every time I dig up numbers for this, it's a headache because there are thousands upon thousands of people getting blocked on SO, and you're worried about single-digits. Get your head out of the sand.

Comment: I've been pushing this for two and half years @Shog9 - since Spring 2014 when first wave of cockroaches pushed by quality project from SO started attacking other sites. As of now I've got enough tools and knowledge to handle this flood at the site I care about, that's why I'm done with it. This proposal here is just in case if someone else wants to know what they would need from SE team if they want to to easier handle off-topic debugging questions at their sites

Answer (score 3):

## Highlight the answerer's post in the comments

This has been asked a few times in the past (most recent request [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230649/highlight-answerers-name-in-comments)), but since that was asked in 2014, I feel it's been sufficiently long enough to bring it up again.

People use comments to question or correct an answer, and a person will often comment on their own answer to offer a counterargument. Knowing that someone wrote the answer they commented on is an important bit of context in long comment chains, and I am very surprised to find that it hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: Maybe just put the user name of the person that wrote the answer and the person that wrote the question in bold.

Comment: @IanRingrose Maybe highlight the name of the question-asker and bold the name of the answerer? I honestly don't care how it's done, as long as the answerer is immediately distinguishable from the other commenters.

Answer (score 2):

### Make reviewing edits with Mathjax more managable

Currently, when viewing an edit where Mathjax is edited, the rendered output side-by-side diff breaks the Mathjax rendering. This is particularly annoying when reviewing edits, as the actual result after editing is unavailable.

Of course, it would be best to change the diff view to not break edited Mathjax, but a perhaps easier improvement would be to simply show the rendered output without the diff, as then the Mathjax will be rendered correctly (if the edit placed the Mathjax delimiters correctly. In fact, this is one of the hardest things to check right now!)

This is a pretty old issue and my suggestions are nothing new:

- [MathJax rendering for suggested edit queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200496/mathjax-rendering-for-suggested-edit-queue)
- [Mathjax half-broken in suggested edit diffs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232123/mathjax-half-broken-in-suggested-edit-diffs)

But this might be a simple improvement that would make (community) moderating easier.

Comment: You would probably be better off making this its own Meta question rather than an answer here. [Nothing is being done with these](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285889/lets-plan-the-second-iteration-of-the-stack-exchange-quality-project/306148#comment943807_285889).

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a very elitist* suggestion, but how about an introductory non-zappable video before asking first question:

"How to get the best out of Stackwhatever"

With concise, positive advice, which I'm not going to rehash here, I think it's been done any number of times already here on meta.

<sub>*Because it's rude to point out that the problem is that people don't read any more.</sub>

Comment: video is too high brow, what we really need are [comics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comics#/media/File:Mr._A._Mutt_Starts_in_to_Play_the_Races_1907.jpg)

Comment: If we could get Randall Munroe to create animated shorts that replace current how-tos, that would be ... awesome without precedent.

Comment: Video without text alternative is not good for accessibility.

Comment: @Anders: It could be closed captioned. I do like the idea of a video, because people are more likely to engage with that. However, that's really just symptomatic of the deeper problem. The problem users don't take the time to even write good questions, and they definitely don't take the time to read the help articles or Meta. I'm not sure if enabling that "I just want to get an answer with the least work possible" mentality necessarily fixes anything.

Answer (score 0):

### Ability to retract reopen/delete votes

Close votes can be retracted; let's make it happen for reopen/delete votes as well.

This may resurrect [an old feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193061/168244).

Answer (score -1):

**Allow the user to mark an answer, but sort answers by the number of upvotes**

While not as common as it used to be, I'll occasionally find an old question with a specified answer with a handful of upvotes. The answer after that will have Several dozen to several hundred upvotes, the next one a couple hundred, etc etc. Sometimes the accepted answer should be sorted four or five answers down. Stack Exchange is about community consensus on what is the best approach, but our most valuable resource (the first answer to a question) is picked by one individual.

Yes, the individual should have the ability to select an answer that works for them, and even the only person who should change that answer is the OP, but that doesn't mean it's actually the *right answer to the question*. Why does it make sense to let someone who has asked a question, showing their knowledge is lacking in the subject, control which answer is the first shown to incoming users?

Comment: It's just a sort order, and a trivial concern at that; the answer you're actually looking for (the most highly upvoted one) is *right below the accepted one.*

Comment: The OP is the only person who can accept an answer and although they can revise their decision, they never do. They're often *wrong*.

Comment: @TomWL The checkmark doesn't indicate *correctness.*  It indicates that the user chose that answer to put the checkmark on, and that's all it indicates.  If it's being used correctly, the checkmark indicates the answer that solved the OP's problem.

Comment: [Same suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/286175/307988)

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm fully aware that the second highest answer is the one I'm typically looking for, but SO is more often than not one of the first google hits for _any user_ who may or may not know how SO works. While the checkmark is not indicative of correctness, to a new user, it certainly looks like it is.

Comment: @Sidney: New users have all sorts of misconceptions about SE sites.  This is just one of them.

Answer (score -1):

### More statistics on each question for geeks (like me).

This is the general idea, from that idea to make it real there are many questions.

- What level and up a user can see that statistics?
- What statistics to show?

For example, something like

- Views per month/day
- Votes per day
- Votes that gets compare with the views
- The average score of viewer
- The non-register viewer’s vs the register.
- The users that see, what tags they are best on…

All that on the bottom of the question hidden somewhere in a tab.

### What is the goal behind that?

Apparently on **most question that statistics will mean nothing** but we can see **if some technology is die or continue to interesting the people** on some specific questions by looking if they still view and vote about.

For sure is only very interesting for some question and not for all !

Also can be a "gift" for high score users and motivate to get points to see that stats !

Comment: How will this improve the quality of questions and answers?

Comment: @IanRingrose By understanding how your question, or answer affect if affect the other users. For example, if an answer have all ready 10 views and not any vote, and after a year you have 2 more views and a vote, this is a knowledge that some one is really needed after years, but not at that time, and the opposed. Other, if most of questions have let say 10 views but in this 10 views you see that you have only 1 that have score above 10k, and you do get an answer only from him, this is also a clue. Statistics are very important to help in anything in my opinion.

Comment: The "quality project" is about getting rid of the problem questions etc, most of these are asked by people with low rep that have no interest in how the side works.

Comment: @IanRingrose I am not sure whether I am misunderstanding something significantly because English is only my second language (even though I started learning it at age four) but if I go back to the original question right at the top of this site I seem to arrive at a completely different interpretation of the ‘quality project’: namely that it should *improve our experience,* not improve the quality of questions and answers.

Comment: @Jan Isn't statistics improve our experience ? Maybe I am really geek with that....

Answer (score -2):

I've seen a lot of spam posts lately and earlier this week I just thought a **Flag** feature for users might come in handy on the user's profile.

Comment: You mean you want to be able to flag a userprofile for posting spam, instead of having to go over all their posts?

Comment: @rene We've had profiles created entirely for spammy posts so flagging the profiles instead of flagging all the posts might be faster and easier for the admins to keep track.

Comment: I'm not sure if this would change much for the mod. A custom flag on a post can do the same trick, maybe combined with a spam flag. If you flag the profile you have to be 100% sure all posts are spam. I doubt if you want to automatically remove all posts when 6 such flags come in.

Comment: Some previous posts on Meta.SO asked how to flag a user for having spam in their profile or for having an offensive avatar image.  The response is usually "put a custom flag on your own post/comment and explain it well", but that isn't exactly intuitive.  On the other hand, I can see people flagging users they don't like just because, creating more work for the mods.  I'm not sure if the use cases justify the misuse cases.

Comment: @Jeffrey Bosboom If someone wants to flag users they don't like just because, they can do so on all their posts and even downvote, causing more harm.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom, if you flag a user "just because", presumably that's grounds for a moderator to revoke your flag and/or site-use privileges.

Answer (score -2):

I just remembered another [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) of mine that comes with absolutely minimal (I think) coding requirements for maximum benefit — very small buck but significant bang.

[I keep cancelling my edit rejects!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285300/312026)

The gist is: if you want to do something that has a custom text box, e.g:

- send a custom mod flag
- close a question for a custom reason
- post an answer
- …

The required keyboard shortcut after having written in that custom text box is `tab → enter`. This even works for posting questions: if I forgot to add tags I’ll be right in the tag bar, if I did add them it also automatically posts.

And then there is reject suggested edits, where the workflow is `tab →`**`tab`**`→ enter`. And I swear it catches me every time.

Comment: How this improve the content quality of SE?

Comment: This isn't a problem with Stack Exchange, it's a problem with occasional errors in your personal workflow. Rearranging menus doesn't eliminate the problem which is that you're using shortcuts that are unconscious to create actions which require active conscious decisions.

Comment: @Nij The *conscious* part of the decision is typically writing up the custom reject reason. As soon as I am content with the sentence I want to get it sent away and I shouldn’t need *another* conscious ‘are you really, really, really sure you want to do this?’ It’s like the Linux philosophy of ‘If that person wrote `rm -rf ~` then I’m going to assume it was a conscious action and do so.’

Comment: This will not improve the quality of the content, therefore does not keep to the spec!

Comment: It fulfils the project spec as it will improve my (and probably others’, too) Stack Exchange usage experience.

Answer (score -3):

**A button to quickly/easily select all the code in a code block.**

Especially useful when looking at questions to answer, whereby you want to copy the asker's code paste it into your own environment and try it out. It would save time with those code blocks that are so long that they need to show a vertical scrollbar.

I know this can be solved with user scripts etc. but still, it would be nice to have it built in to SE.

Example feature request on meta:
["Select all" for code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169593/select-all-for-code-blocks)

Comment: Since it's trivial to add this with a user script I don't think SE devs need to spend time on this.

Comment: I'm not sure about other sites, but on SO, we don't want questions with so much code they need to show a vertical scrollbar. That's why we have the [`[mcve]`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) shortcut...

Comment: This feature would be useful in certain scenarios, but I'd prefer a more specific "copy-to-answer" function. A lot of answers involve correcting or calling attention to code in a question. Instantly copying a block of code to an answer would have the benefit of making it easier to answer a question without making it any easier to copy-paste potentially malicious code into a live environment.

Answer (score -3):

**Identify and Provide Guidelines for Responders with Communication Issues**

I really like the counselling that's automatically provided when I ask a question.  Some responders, their information is sound and they mean well but they come off as needlessly rude because of their choice of language.  Clearly they mean well but they could use some counselling on their communication skills.

Could warnings be incorporated into the answer posting process that identify highly emotionally charged words in a responders answer and provide suggested alternatives in the same way that the question posting provides advice when a question appears to be opinion-based?

Comment: There's a hard natural language processing problem there, and even if you solve that, you'll just be nagging people who are already annoyed, which seems more likely to make things worse than better.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom no harder than the current method used on questions.

Answer (score -3):

New users usually start on one site, then find other sites they find interesting through the Hot Network Questions (HNQ). One problem that I have already indicated half a year ago and shouldn't exactly require be hard to fix, is [the inconsistent link CSS these HNQ have across sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278836/hot-network-questions-have-inconsistent-css-for-visited-not-visited-depending-on).

It feels like there are a dozen of different templates for this CSS, and what makes it even more confusing is that they can't agree on what form the contrast difference between `:visited`, `:hover` and plain should take. I've screenshotted 5 different sites, and each of those sites has a different take on HNQ links. One of them says `:visited` should be darker, one of them says it should be lighter, one of them says it should be a little bit darker (but not as much as the first site, because that would make too much sense), one of them says it should be cyan instead of the default red,... Both for new users and users that already have an expansive SE presence, this works confusing.

HNQ is one of the few page elements that can be found on every site, so users have a certain expectation of continuity when going from one site to the next through this method. Many existing users browse this network during their lunch break, at home, or while legitimately waiting for certain long-winded processes to finish. They may not be interested in a specific site and just want to read what interesting questions have been asked on sites they like to read. Many new users may find new communities they are interested in. For both use cases, consistent link CSS helps the user decide which question they want to visit next. It also can lead new users to sites they may enjoy.

I feel like we should at least consolidate the contrast across the different sites, even if we decide to not unify the CSS for the HNQ entirely. It makes no sense that going from Stack Overflow to Super User has a completely mirrored contrast for `:visited` compared to plain links.

Comment: Not sure how would this improve content quality? I know it may be annoying, but SE are looking for proposals geared towards rising the quality.

Comment: I assumed by quality, general site quality was meant, like user experience, but now I understand it is about content quality. My bad, sorry. In honesty, my intent was partially to get an update.

Comment: How will this improve the quality of questions and answers?

Comment: @Braiam I am not sure whether I am misunderstanding something significantly because English is only my second language (even though I started learning it at age four) but if I go back to the original question right at the top of this site I seem to arrive at a completely different interpretation of the ‘quality project’: namely that it should *improve our experience,* not improve the quality of questions and answers.

Comment: @Braiam: Simple, make background-color and color the same *on every site*, that way no one can see the HNQ links or visit them. This will instantly raise quality on most sites, sometimes quite significantly. :P

Answer (score -4):

## Get rid of historical locking

This is probably the most counter-quality feature Stack Exchange has come with. [Like Gilles said:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112910/213575)

> What we're doing here is to frame the garbage.

The historical lock has been used for stuff that isn't "history" at all. Stuff that was deleted by the community and was kept deleted for a long time, sometimes over a year, are undeleted and locked for the dismay of the curators and quality-aware users.

Instead, promote **more aggressive course of actions** like editing, migrating, re-asking, re-scoping, etc. that are more desirable since nobody will have claims that the content should be deleted, and frankly, content that is available on the internet isn't lost even if SE deletes it.

Comment: The entire point of the Historical Lock is that the questions **can't** be edited to fit the SE format or the site's current on-topic structure... that's pretty much what the text says. Where do you suggest they be migrated? Some of the questions are worth keeping around for reference... but the point of the historical lock is to prevent similar questions in the future... a 5 year old site may decide that shopping recommendations are off topic in year 3 but there's no reason to retroactively delete all shopping recommendation questions that existed prior to that decision being implemented...

Comment: @Catija what? You say that something too broad can't be broken down [into more reasonable questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95072/) Or that they can't be [moved to a more appropriated SE?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/84676/2), or that SE doesn't [actually restricts the potential untapped that some topic has?](https://github.com/vhf/free-programming-books/blob/master/README.md) There are plenty examples of alternatives to locking that have been proven to work better in the long run, you just have to keep the ball running.

Comment: @Catija btw, locks don't prevent new questions, [in fact they foment people to ask them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory) and [in some cases the said users feel entitled to complain about the "lock" itself](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280826/792066)

Answer (score -5):

## A queue just for new questions from new users, like Help & Improvement but before the question is shown to the public.

Most new users post bad questions, without intending to. This would truly help the community out.

Comment: @HDE226868 that's *after* questions go live on main, where they can get attacked. **We need to stop the plague before it breaks out.**

Comment: Sorry; I misunderstood.

Comment: [Puzzling.SE](//puzzling.stackexchange.com) has an issue with the quality of asked riddles. Recently they instituted a [Riddle Sandbox](//meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/5276) where riddles could be reviewed before they were posted on the main site. You’re suggesting pretty much the same thing, but more formally, right? Related: [Okay, let’s figure out how to address our quality problem](//meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/5372), [Do we have a quality problem with riddles specifically?](//meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/5451), and [more](//meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=sandbox).

Comment: @PeregrineRook instead of a sandbox, a review queue. Only a few people see it, in the sandbox, it's all-for-all.

Comment: I really hate websites that allow you to post something and then state 'your message has been submitted for review'. In this case I would say the cure is worse than the disease.

Answer (score -5):

#### Make the new user help available in languages other than English

A lot of users whose first language is not English use SO to ask questions. When one of those new users is confronted with a raft of new-user information in English, it's a larger barrier to entry than if it is available in their native language. Whatever we create to assist new users should be available in the languages that the surveys have identified as the most common in our community.

Comment: Disagree. Providing guidance in foreign languages will only serve to encourage folks to post in foreign languages... which is the opposite of improving quality. I understand the motive, but I don't think this is the right implementation.

Comment: @Undo Your concern is easily addressed if it's clear that questions and answers should be in English.

Comment: In which case: if their English is not sufficient to read guidelines, how is it going to be good enough to comprehend the answers to their question, or the advice on improving it?

Comment: It just seems to me that if I was a non-native speaker it would be a lot easier to read introductory material in my own language and make it more likely that I would be able to ask a good question in English.

Answer (score -6):

#### Hide deleted posts by default.

This has two implications, that I can see: First, if [hichris123's suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285898/245368) is implemented, it will prevent spam from even being effective against most users.  Second, it is annoying to read a bunch of really good content, then to be slapped in the face by trash, or perhaps have to scroll past it to get to the bottom of the page to the answer box after reviewing a section of the question.

#### Put the answer box immediately beneath the question.

It would make it a lot easier to recheck something in the question while writing an answer--especially if there are a few answers or a really long answer already.

Comment: IMO this would encourage answerers to post without bothering to read existing answers, which IMO seems like a Bad Idea™ ...also, deleted posts are invisible to < 10K users...

Comment: I don't care who deleted posts are invisible too.  They are visible to me, and I think it is a pain.  I agree with your first point, but it would still be easier to write answers with it under the question.  I'm sure some of these geniuses at SE can figure the UX issue out.

Comment: It’s a priviledge you earned. You’re basically saying *give me the option to remove that priviledge*.

Comment: Hardly.  I just want the trash hidden by default, the way posts that are marked as spam have the content hidden by default.  Of course, if the button was a little smaller than the full length of the post, it would be nice.

Answer (score -6):

### We need a mechanism for asking the questioner a complicated question, one that supports full Markdown and can be unbounded in length.

I saw multiple proposals in here having to do with discouraging answers that are "more properly comments".  This is about one scenario I've found myself in, repeatedly, where it was impossible to ask the question I needed to ask in the form of a comment. A nice, clear example is [Bin data read differently in AIX vs Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38576067/); look particularly at the revision history of my answer, https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38576285/revisions, which started out as a request for the OP to run a test program.  Test programs can't go in the comment box, unless they're shell one-liners, and even then it can get awkward.

Comment: I think a question that requires a long follow-up question is not ready to be on SE. Whiteboard, email or blog-post discussion is needed.

Comment: @Raphael They happen. We have to deal with them.

Comment: Vote to close, and leave a comment linking to a gist with your test program. Or invite the author to chat. But if you need to do this back-and-forth for a question, then you also need to _vote to close_, not _answer_.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I see where you're coming from on that, but I think that in the current state of play, having one's question closed equates to "fuck off and never bother us again" in the eyes of most new posters, and therefore I only do it to questions that are completely unsalvageable.  I think that a mechanism like the one I suggested is a *prerequisite* for question closing not being a slap in the face.

Comment: If the OP is put off by the closure and does not even read the comment inviting them to discussion elsewhere, I don't think I want to interact with that person.

Comment: My initial reaction here was to shudder - "oh great, full program listings in comments". Then I thought... This actually happens, *today* - in chat. Yes, believe it or not, chat is pretty effective for "interactive" Q&A, and supports posting extremely large blocks of code in a single message (they show up collapsed, so not nearly so disruptive as a comment would be). Giving folks a way to start a chat with an asker (without making it seem quite so like dragging them into a dark alley for nefarious purposes) could solve this problem.

Comment: @Shog9 I'd like that a lot. It's unnecessarily hard to *start* (not lead) a conversation on SE.

Comment: I refuse to use chat, because I see the mere _existence_ of chat as a major contributing factor to the misguided and harmful belief that comments should be ephemeral. I'd support a new mechanism for having a synchronous, interactive conversation directly with a questioner - *strictly* one-on-one, to prevent other people jumping in with unhelpful kibitzing - which, after completion, would be permanently recorded with the question.

Comment: Oh, don't worry @zwol - we considered comments ephemeral long before chat existed. Heck, they used to be hard deleted, and for years not even moderators could see deleted comments much less undelete or move them to chat. If anything, chat is pushing the notion that we should keep these little things around...

Comment: @Shog9: I think we need better ways to move conversations into chat.  The current way (waiting for a suggestive link) is fickle, unpredictable and doesn't actually move the comments.  For users at a certain rep level, I would support making that "move conversation to chat" link continuously available, rather than having to wait for it to appear.  High-rep users also need a way to marshal sub 20-rep users into a chat room.

Comment: @Shog9 That's nice and all, but chat conversations don't show up in site searches, aren't visible from a user profile, and most importantly, do not appear next to the question or answer that they should have remained permanently associated with.  Until all of those things are fixed chat will remain a misfeature.  And there's probably a bunch of other problems that I'm not aware of since I never use the thing.

Comment: @zwol oh, [they actually are](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+site%3Achat.stackexchange.com), that's one of the reasons why SF folks moved to a private chat. They are public *and* indexed.

Comment: @Braiam External searchability is a feeble workaround at best.

Comment: @zwol are you aware that some ~95% of all the traffic *ever* see comes from search engines? BTW, chat also has its own search. From my point of view, it seems that you are frankly uninformed about the characteristics of the site and taking an uninformed standpoint about a very important issue. I recommend you to research *more*, much more than what you know now.

Answer (score -6):

I would like to request that when marking a duplicate, if your answer is better than the duplicate, leave yours and punish the lesser quality one instead.  I am asking that duplicates be marked based on quality not timestamp as that should improve the overall quality of SE as an information source.

Comment: What do you mean by "punish"? Downvote? If so, why?

Comment: _"I am asking that duplicates be marked based on quality not timestamp"_ That's already the guidance- Close the worse question/question with worse answers as duplicate of the better. Timestamp is supposed to be irrelevant to which should be closed, unless you feel it's a tie in quality and decide to close the newer one then.

Comment: in my experience, I have created an awesome question far better than the duplicate and it is gang closed within 5 minutes...

Comment: @dalearn, so post on the appropriate site meta, and a moderator can reverse the direction of the "duplicate" marking.

Comment: @dalearn I presume you're talking about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39214972/cant-send-emails-via-php-from-shared-web-hosting) question. Thats not better then the duplicate, thats barely even on topic.

Comment: i was NOT talking about that one...  (I admit that it is a very bad question although I dispute that it is a duplicate because the other question did not fix my problem)  No, I am talking about like 3 or 4 questions that I deleted...

Comment: @dalearn Questions that are closed as duplicates are still visible to others and therefore potentially helpful. Deleted questions are not (except to 10K users). If you think your closed question is better than the original, please **do not** delete it.

Answer (score -10):

I haven't contributed much to SE sites, but as someone who frequently browses them (particularly programming questions on SO and SU), **I often find questions that have been locked even though they contain useful information and are featured prominently in web search results.**

Two particularly common occurrences that confuse me:

- Questions that are "too general"

  I often come to these when I'm looking up a topic that I'm not already familiar with, so I don't know the specific vocabulary to search for. While these don't always answer my question, they usually have enough info to point me in the right direction and allow me to search for my more specific issue.
- Questions that are soliciting opinions, not facts

  Something like a question about code architecture. There's seldom one correct architecture to use; there's a number of different models, each with pros and cons. That's an inherently subjective question, but getting people's opinions helps me form my own, and gives me a starting point to go look for more info.

---

In addition to getting useful information, I could see myself asking a question like that, and then being confused and put off by it being closed.

Comment: The problem with broad questions is that it's quite inconvenient to maintain them in a strict Q&A format.

Comment: The usefulness of these questions is why they are locked, and not deleted. That's *also* why the banner says that they are not to be imitated by new questions.

Comment: Do you have a specific proposal here? You're describing a situation that (I guess?) you personally don't like, but you're not explaining what broad effect you think it has or what should be done. (And I'll also point out that "these broad questions are the best thing and should be encouraged" is an viewpoint that's been well-hashed out: see, e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110350/ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92980/ and check out the "Linked" sidebar on both of those.)

Comment: Also note that the downvotes on this answer have little to nothing to do with its quality - on Meta, upvotes and downvotes indicate agreement and disagreement (like "yeah we should do this" and "I think doing this is a bad idea").

Comment: Heh... maybe we need an "opinions.stackexchange.com" site

Comment: I don't have any particular proposal, I just wanted to share my experience to help inform whatever proposals people do come up with.

@dorukayhan, thanks for the tip, I wouldn't have known that otherwise.

Answer (score -12):

### Let's give newcomers a little slack

<sub>(especially on meta)</sub>

[image] **Because feeling humiliated online is never "fun".**

This is especially true for first-time users on Stack Exchange, and when they post their first contributions. If the question is "bad" because it doesn't meet with standards set out by the site; then, yes, responsible users need to express that by downvoting. Likewise for answers.

But I would suggest that if there are no upvotes, then the number of downvotes be limited to ten, i.e.; -10. This limit would be for newly subscribed users posting their first *ever* answer and/or  first question.

If it is possible to block the number of downvotes to five (-5) without  affecting spam flags and spam downvotes, even better. Any following downvotes would be hidden, unless an upvote is cast.

For example, newcomer UserXYZ posts a question on meta and ten downvotes are cast, one after the other. The display only shows -5, if six upvotes are cast the number on display will now show -4 and any votes cast after that will be counted.

**Why rub salt into a wound when it's bleeding?**

Yes, the user could delete their answer, and recoup the lost reputation points, and a question may be closed, so new answers cannot be added, but that sense of humiliation and impotence will stick. Additionally, if that question has received one or more upvoted answers the hapless user is unable to delete their question.

Besides, after the first ten downvotes, how *constructive* were the next 18 downvotes?

**UPDATE**

Here's a perfect example of a user (a newcomer on meta?) whose proposal, and consequent attempts to delete their request, got repeatedly downvoted, it now stands at **-40**

[A new reputation value based on Open Source Software (OSS) financial support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286482/a-new-reputation-value-based-on-open-source-software-oss-financial-support)

If the number of downvotes had been blocked at, say -10, the user's pride would have been hurt, but he wouldn't have been humiliated. Yes. I know. He defaced his posts, and attempted to delete it several times; but he couldn't because more than one user had posted an answer. Weren't the negative response in the comments (I'm making the assumption that many of the earlier comments were deleted because the exchange begins abruptly) and the downvotes more than enough?

> @_____ not disagreement, but I've lost 40 rep points, and this looks as I did something really bad. that kind of down votes number should get an offensive or racist post. If my post is so offensive to moderators then allow me to delete it

The excessive number of downvotes, the non intervention of any mod whose role should also be one of guidance,  the posting of quasi duplicate answers that means an OP cannot delete their post, the resulting defacements, all of this is deplorable behaviour. So maybe, just maybe, if the number of downvotes had remained fixed at -10 (here on meta) the OP would have had had the time to reflect, and reconsider either editing their request, or deleting it altogether.

What kind of first time experience is this? What kind of impression is this user leaving with?

Comment: Are the votes still counted but just hidden? What happens for example if a post would have got 48 downvotes and 10 upvotes? Since the downvotes are limited to 10, is it now at a net of 0?

Comment: @Cai I don't *know*. I'll leave that up the developers. I'm concerned about people feeling anxious, and stressed when they post their first contributions. It *is* humiliating, especially if they post something in good faith.

Comment: Is -10 less bad than -20? You read users complaining constantly about their -1 question. So does this really fix anything?

Comment: And is it 'okay' to downvote a regular user to -28? Where is the line drawn?

Comment: @PatrickHofman EDIT: This limit would be for NEWCOMERS  -10 puts across the message that the post is bad. I've seen posts with -50 on meta, now if the user has been a member for longer than six weeks, I say "fair game", they should know what they are letting themselves into.

Comment: I understand the reasoning. The only way it would work I think, is if the correct count is unaffected but simply hidden for new users (maybe people with view-vote-counts privilege can see the correct count).

Comment: (meta question: does this really have to do with the SE quality project?)

Comment: Also it's not only new users who complain about downvotes so I'm not sure it's fair to say "fair-game" to anyone who's been registered for longer than x amount of time.

Comment: @PatrickHofman give me a break. Downvote this proposal, if you feel it adds nothing.

Comment: It adds something, but I wonder if this is the right place for that.

Comment: @Cai newcomers, people who post their first question or answer, users who have 1 rep, I'm talking about those. We've all posted poor contributions, and I have deleted answers that earned 3 downvotes. But a person who posts on SO, and hasn't read the guidelines, the reams of pages and bla..bla...bla.. they just want a quick answer. Well -10 says pretty much what you need to know. have you never watched a soccer match when the stronger side is winning 7-0? How did you feel for the losing team?

Comment: Do they call the match off in that situation? Invalidate any further goals? No.

Comment: I'm not saying your idea doesn't have any merit and I completely agree with the sentiment. Maybe it would work, maybe it wouldn't, I honestly don't know. I'm just voicing my problems with the idea.

Comment: In the past 30 days, about 0.09% of all posts on Stack Overflow scored -10 or below; that includes deleted posts like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39887539/who-is-the-richest-dumbest-person-you-know

Comment: @Shog9 and your point being if a newcomer gets -28 votes, he shouldn't feel too bad about it, because his question belongs to the 0.09% ? Sorry for asking, but to clarify, when you say all posts, does that also include sister sites? i read that user's last comment, and I felt truly sorry for him/her.

Comment: Once you get down to -4, questions no longer appear on the homepage; answers start being greyed out at -3, and questions are eligible for immediate deletion after being closed. As such, we see a pretty big spike at -3 - almost 3% of posts in the past 30 days achieved a score of -3 or less (stack overflow only still - % is lower elsewhere). My point is, if you want to have a noticeable effect, -10 is too low; the vast, vast majority of new folks who get downvoted never reach such depths (you'd mostly be benefiting trolls and spammers, who don't really care anyway).

Comment: Now, meta is a bit different: Q&A here holds the potential to influence the experience of *everyone on all sites* - a feature request to change the behavior of the software, or a discussion on policy can end up altering how stuff works for thousands of people years into the future. As such, folks tend to be a lot more... Proactive... about indicating their displeasure when it comes to meta sites.

Comment: *All that said*, there is precedent for simply *hiding negative scores*: we do this during elections, for candidates during the primary phase. You can hit -30, but your displayed score will still display as 0; it will *stay* 0 until your actual score hits at least +1, but the idea is that you're not being discouraged and - perhaps more importantly - folks aren't being encouraged to pile on downvotes before reading what you have to say. Such behavior may be extremely harmful when it comes to answers (if I see a bad answer, I must know that before trying it), but could work for questions.

Comment: @Shog9 know that spam posts only require six flags, which automatically means they get -6  before their posts are deleted. So the limit must be around -10, a round number. It could be -8, maybe  that number would be fine to block further downvotes. I see that on SE meta users don't hesitate to fall on unsuspecting users like a ton of bricks (which you admitted to in your previous comment). What happened to the "let's be nice policy" which I continually read references to? Ack, I've got -3 even on this suggestion. :) :)

Comment: @Shog9 I'm speaking about newcomers, treating them with a bit of healthy respect. Who cares about the election of moderators, anyone who candidates to be a mod, and posts their propaganda speech, should be   able to take criticisms, and downvotes. So the score is never lower than -0. That's not right. They should want to lead by example, if the kitchen's too hot, get out.

Comment: I don't follow your logic, @Mari-LouA: you note that even spam routinely gets deleted before it reaches your proposed threshold, which is true - as I noted earlier, -8 is *exceedingly rare*, and contains in quantity - at least on main sites - some truly awful stuff. So what are we protecting by setting the bar that low? As for downvotes and "nice"... Please see: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/08/stack-exchange-is-not-a-forum-the-role-of-niceness-on-a-qa-site/

Comment: @Shog9  The logic was, maybe it was illogical, is that you can't lower the threshold to, say,  -5 because that would affect spam users. I'm only speaking about first time users who post their first posts. In the vast majority of cases, blocking the number of negative downvotes wouldn't be needed, but it's a safety net. Use that limit only on meta then, for unsuspecting, innocent  users who come asking about where to report their bugs on Samsung, and they're greeted with -16 votes. Great welcome.

Comment: And what I'm getting at is that we could alter how post scores are *displayed* without breaking anything, @Mari-LouA. Spam still disappears with 6 flags, but appears to have a score of 0 right up until deletion; lousy questions drop off the homepage at -4, but still appear to have a score of 0. Heck, we could even do this *only for the authors of the posts themselves*, and get rid of the distraction (and often counter-productive feelings of rage at seeing their work rejected) while still warning other readers that they may wish to look elsewhere... IOW, attack the perception, not the system.

Comment: @Shog9 oh, that's good...

Comment: I'm not familiar with StackOverflow, but on the sites I frequent, the only way a post is likely to hit -10 is if it is either spectacularly wrong (eg. likely to get someone killed), or if it's from the sort of person we *want* to drive off (a spammer, or someone who thinks vicious personal attacks are appropriate conversation).

Comment: Naw, -10 is pretty rare *everywhere but meta*, @Mark. Mari-Lou, if you like the variation I suggested in my last comment, you might consider proposing that separately...

Comment: @Shog9 thanks but I know when I'm beat. Going to delete the suggestion. Although that poor user who only wanted to report about her  Samsung phone was humiliated by a ridiculous number of down votes, who cares. She should've known better, right?

Comment: How can you be beat? The suggestion isn't even sitting at -8 yet. ;-) You've spent half a day defending this idea, and gotten a fair bit of feedback... Well, work with it! That's how things get done.

Comment: @Shog9  I gave it one last shot. One downvote away from -8,  but if it doesn't pull the crowds, it doesn't pull. Softening newcomers' experiences is not a hot topic on SO meta. Thanks anyway for pointing out the flaws, the constructive criticisms, you know.

Comment: It would be weird to confuse the downvoter by not seeing the score change, just to make the bad poster not feel too bad. So, if implemented, then the voter still needs to see _something_ is happening to the score when downvoting, or when removing the downvote. But I guess that's easily implemented client-side. (That said, I feel no pity at all to newcomers who just post crap without first browsing around to get to know the community, while ignoring the hints they get while posting.)

Comment: @Arjan compared to today, what were your very first questions or answers like? Did you do a better job once you got to know the site better?  First impressions are important, the newcomer's bad post  made a bad impression, OK. But what impression did they receive when their poorly researched post got -10, or -5? And quite often the downvotes are not explained. I keep hearing about SO's mean attitude, and spirit, a common complaint on EL&U also. Give users a second chance, and don't drive away newcomers who might have a lot to offer.

Comment: *"Did you do a better job once you got to know the site better?"* Sure, but did I ever get downvoted as I posted crap without looking around? Of course not. And nowadays the communities have so much [hints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFCFW.png) and [limitations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxqoH.png) in place, I feel it's even difficult to post something that attracts many downvotes.

Comment: @Arjan how many users are proficient in English? OK, there are now Russian, Japanese and Spanish sites on SE, so it might be interesting to find out if they have fewer "crappy" first time posters compared to the larger English speaking communities.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts to be nice; that's always good. That said, no new-comer is *required* to use these sites. I feel it's a waste of development time to make things even easier for newcomers who manage to attract a lot of downvotes. For me, the _only_ reason to make it even easier for them is to ensure existing members who're actively helping are not driven away.

Comment: @Arjan  Fewer people will stay to be long term contributors, and eventually those contributors become bored because the quality of the questions will appear to get worse, and worse over time. If you want any Internet platform, network, Q&A community to guarantee quality, and expert help, it has to be smaller. And that is something the developers on SE definitely do not want, it's in their financial interest that the number of registered users keep increasing,  that the user base remains solid, and that newcomers come back.

Comment: (Con't) Well getting -28 on your first post is not the way to win over somebody's loyalty. It's not the way to show a newcomer how to write a better question. It's not the business card you want to be displaying to someone who is visiting the first time. My suggestion is not just being "nice" it should also produce some  pay-off. The suggestion says "give newcomers a little slack" It doesn't say welcome to every crappy question on the Internet. There's a huge difference.

Comment: There's a fundamental problem with this proposal: how would it improve quality?

Comment: @Braiam How about it would improve the newcomer's  experience and suggest that SE is a friendlier, a more helpful place for non-experts?

Comment: @Mari-LouA how about not killing the experts that able to answer the questions in the process?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Quality is the #1 standard on the SE network, and that will hopefully never change. Adding that limitation would certainly not be good for the quality (and the original purpose of votes, reflecting (dis)-agreement).

Comment: @Mari-LouA Your problem is the idea that every newcomer is a desireable user. They're not. Only those who ask good questions are, the others can easily get downvoted and/or question banned quickly, SE will be better off for it.

Comment: **Someone please explain to me the utility of receiving -30 votes, or -20, or even -15**. I mean after -10 votes in a row, why kick someone when he's already down?! Especially a NEWCOMER.

Comment: @Mari-LouA To impress into the newcomer the idea: Get better or get out.

Comment: OK, we'll if you think that attitude is going to improve StackExchange's reputation, you're mistaken. If you keep the community small, and more tight knitted, then you can be unyielding, and exigent. It can become more of an exclusive club, nothing wrong with that. But if you're opening up to a few billion people, this is not the way to increase membership, or give a positive first impression. I've said everything I wanted to say. *Adesso basta!* ;)

Comment: @Mari-LouA No problem with that. The goal is not to increase membership or give a positive first impression for askers, its to build a high quality QA site. These are two different goals.

Comment: Empathy, a seemingly rare commodity nowadays. That and dealing at arm's length with people were instrumental in me deciding to contribute content. Saying that the sole responsibility for Q. rests on the shoulders of newcomers is just lazy imho. Questions should be edited, expectations should be expressed, and experienced users should also ask questions. I'm sure there is a lot of noise on many sites, including on SO and ppl. are fed up, but with all due respect, content is not about servicing bored out ppl. Both people and knowledge should be treated with the care and respect they deserve. Ty.

Comment: This answer has gotten a lot of feedback, which is great. It has also got a lot of downvotes which would be great except that I don't really see people pointing out why this is a "bad" idea. Downvotes past 0 usually don't add anything constructive, so I agree with the request.